# Programmatically darken a Hex colour

Tags: colors, hex

What's the easiest way to programmatically darken a hex colour?

Comment: I found this github gist useful for some kind of working solution to shift a color programmatically - note the `fraction` param there is a percentage. So I use input `0.05` to darken by 5%  - https://gist.github.com/martintreurnicht/f6bbb20a43211bc2060e

Comment: This worked for me - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33072365/how-to-darken-a-given-color-int/33072575#33072575

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you're not bothered about too much control, and just want a generally darker version of a colour, then:

```
col = (col & 0xfefefe) >> 1;
```

Is a nice quick way to halve a colour value (assuming it's packed as a byte per channel, obviously).

In the same way brighter would be:

```
col = (col & 0x7f7f7f) << 1;
```

Comment: Is there a way to make it darken by a quarter instead of half?

Comment: Or what about making it brighter instead of darker?

Comment: brighter would be `(col & 0x7f7f7f) << 1` although for more complex stuff you'd be better breaking out the RGB components and manipulating them separately

Comment: To get something that is only slightly darker, try this: `((col & 0x7E7E7E) >> 1) | (col & 0x808080)`

Comment: Can you give an explanation what is happening here?

Comment: @Sisir: 0xFE is `11111110` in binary. Using that with the `&` operator sets the smallest bit (decimal value 1) of each color byte to zero. The `>>` operator shifts everything down one position, so the zeros are now in the spots worth 255 points, and the rest of each color is in a position worth only half the value it was before.

Comment: Didn't do anything for me. Instead what worked for me is - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33072365/how-to-darken-a-given-color-int/33072575#33072575

Answer (score 30):

**Convert hex color into integer RBG components:**

```
#FF6600 = rbg(255, 102, 0)
```

**If you want to make it darker by 5%, then simply reduce all integer values by 5%:**

```
255 - 5% = 242
102 - 5% = 96
0 - 5% = 0

= rbg(242, 96, 0)
```

**Convert back to hex color**

```
= #F26000
```

Comment: This won't actually work very nicely due to [relative luminance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_luminance) - something which the HSV scale takes into account.  By just reducing all RGB values by the same  amount, the result color will look more greenish and blueish (since those components appear to be more bright than red).

Comment: Windows 10 Creators edition darkens the logon screen image by reducing the rgb numbers by about 45%.

Answer (score 21):

A function implemented in javascript:

```
// credits: richard maloney 2006
function getTintedColor(color, v) {
    if (color.length >6) { color= color.substring(1,color.length)}
    var rgb = parseInt(color, 16); 
    var r = Math.abs(((rgb >> 16) & 0xFF)+v); if (r>255) r=r-(r-255);
    var g = Math.abs(((rgb >> 8) & 0xFF)+v); if (g>255) g=g-(g-255);
    var b = Math.abs((rgb & 0xFF)+v); if (b>255) b=b-(b-255);
    r = Number(r < 0 || isNaN(r)) ? 0 : ((r > 255) ? 255 : r).toString(16); 
    if (r.length == 1) r = '0' + r;
    g = Number(g < 0 || isNaN(g)) ? 0 : ((g > 255) ? 255 : g).toString(16); 
    if (g.length == 1) g = '0' + g;
    b = Number(b < 0 || isNaN(b)) ? 0 : ((b > 255) ? 255 : b).toString(16); 
    if (b.length == 1) b = '0' + b;
    return "#" + r + g + b;
}
```

Example:

```
> getTintedColor("ABCEDEF", 10)
> #c6f7f9
```

Comment: In case someone else wants to use this for Three.js' THREE.Color - just go straight from the first assignments to r, g & b (when you have numbers) and divide each by 255, since the RGB values should be between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 13):

Well, I don't have any pseudocode for you, but a tip. If you want to darken a color and maintain its hue, you should convert that hex to HSB (hue, saturation, brightness) rather than RGB. This way, you can adjust the brightness and it will still look like the same color without hue shifting. You can then convert that HSB back to hex.

Comment: works, but overly complex for a simple task

Comment: I actually prefer this method as I have more control.  Note that in Android it's HSV.  `Color.colorToHSV(col, hsv);`

Comment: Here's javascript code that does this: https://gist.github.com/xaphod/ae965011d4864abc4052ebd08c3b795c

Answer (score 5):

```
given arg darken_factor # a number from 0 to 1, 0=no change, 1=black
for each byte in rgb_value
    byte = byte * (1 - darken_factor)
```

Answer (score 3):

I pieced together a nice two-liner function for this:

[Programmatically Lighten or Darken a hex color (or rgb, and blend colors)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5560248/programmatically-lighten-or-darken-a-hex-color/13542669#13542669)

`shadeColor2(hexcolor,-0.05)` for 5% darker

`shadeColor2(hexcolor,-0.25)` for 25% darker

Use positives for lightening.

Answer (score 2):

- Split the hex color into its RGB components.
- Convert each of these components into an integer value.
- Multiply that integer by a fraction, such as `0.5`, making sure the result is also integer.

  - Alternatively, subtract a set amount from that integer, being sure not to go below 0.
- Convert the result back to hex.
- Concatenate these values in RGB order, and use.

Answer (score 2):

RGB colors (in hexadecimal RGB notation) get darker or lighter by adjusting shade, key, lightness, or brightness. See the playground: [colorizer.org](http://colorizer.org)

---

### Option 1. Translate R, G, B values to darken shade

This one is simple, but easy to mess up. Here is subtracting 16 points off the (0,255) scale from each value:

```
myHex = 0x8c36a9;
darkerHex = myHex - 0x101010;
#  0x7c2699;
```

The hex will underflow if any of the R,G,B values are `0x0f` or lower. Something like this would fix that.

```
myHex = 0x87f609;
darkenBy = 0x10;
floor = 0x0;

darkerHex = (max((myHex >> 16) - darkenBy, floor) << 16) + \
    (max(((myHex & 0xff00) >> 8) - darkenBy, floor) << 8) + \
    max(((myHex & 0xff) - darkenBy), floor);
# 0x77e600

# substitute `ceiling=0xff;` and `min((myHex ...) + lightenBy, ceiling)` for lightening
```

### Option 2. Scale R, G, B values to increase black

In the [CMYK](http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/color/rgb-to-cmyk.htm) model, key (black) is 1 - max of R, G, B values on (0,1) scale.

This one is simple enough that you can get good results without too much code. You're rescaling the distribution of R, G, B values by a single scaling factor.

Express the scaling factor as 2-digit hex (so 50% would be `.5*0x100` or `0x80`, 1/16th is `0x10` and 10% rounds down to `0x19` ).

```
#  Assumes integer division ... looking at you python3 >:(

myHex = 0x8c36a9;
keyFactor = 0x10;                   #  Lighten or darken by 6.25%
R = myHex >> 16;                    #  0x8c
G = (myHex & 0xff00) >> 8;          #  0x36
B = myHex & 0xff;                   #  0xa9

darkerHex = ((R-R*keyFactor/0x100) << 16) +  # Darker R
            ((G-G*keyFactor/0x100) << 8) +   # Darker G
            (B-B*keyFactor/0x100);           # Darker B
#  0x84339f

#  substitute `(X+keyFactor-X*keyFactor/0x100)` for lightening 
#  0x9443af
```

### Option 3. Reduce Lightness or Brightness at constant hue

In the [HSL](http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/color/rgb-to-hsl.htm) representation of RGB, lightness is the midpoint between min and max of R, G, B values. For [HSV](http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/color/rgb-to-hsv.htm), brightness is the max of R, G, B values.

Consider using your language's built-in or external RGB/HEX to HSL/HSV converter. Then adjust your L/V values and convert back to RGB/HSL. You can do the conversion by hand, as in #1 & #2, but the implementation may not save you any time over an existing converter (see links for the maths).

Answer (score 1):

A hex colour such as #FCFCFC consists of three pairs representing RGB. The second part of each pair can be reduced to darken any colour without altering the colour considerably.

eg. to darken #FCFCFC, lower the values of C to give #F0F0F0

Reducing the first part of each pair by a small amount will also darken the colour, but you will start to affect the colour more (eg. turning a green to a blue).

Answer (score 1):

You should consider darken the color in L*a*b* color space. Here's an example in JavaScript using [chroma.js](https://github.com/gka/chroma.js/):

```
chroma.hex("#FCFC00").darker(10).hex()  // "#dde000"
```