# Programmatically Lighten or Darken a hex color (or rgb, and blend colors)

Tags: javascript, colors, hex

Here is a function I was working on to programmatically lighten or darken a hex color by a specific amount. Just pass in a string like `"3F6D2A"` for the color (`col`) and a base10 integer (`amt`) for the amount to lighten or darken. To darken, pass in a negative number (i.e. `-20`).

The reason for me to do this was because of all the solutions I found, thus far, they seemed to over-complicate the issue. And I had a feeling it could be done with just a couple lines of code. Please let me know if you find any problems, or have any adjustments to make that would speed it up.

```js
function LightenDarkenColor(col, amt) {
  col = parseInt(col, 16);
  return (((col & 0x0000FF) + amt) | ((((col >> 8) & 0x00FF) + amt) << 8) | (((col >> 16) + amt) << 16)).toString(16);
}


// TEST
console.log( LightenDarkenColor("3F6D2A",40) );
```

For Development use here is an easier to read version:

```js
function LightenDarkenColor(col, amt) {
  var num = parseInt(col, 16);
  var r = (num >> 16) + amt;
  var b = ((num >> 8) & 0x00FF) + amt;
  var g = (num & 0x0000FF) + amt;
  var newColor = g | (b << 8) | (r << 16);
  return newColor.toString(16);
}


// TEST
console.log(LightenDarkenColor("3F6D2A", -40));
```

And finally a version to handle colors that may (or may not) have the "#" in the beginning. Plus adjusting for improper color values:

```
function LightenDarkenColor(col,amt) {
    var usePound = false;
    if ( col[0] == "#" ) {
        col = col.slice(1);
        usePound = true;
    }

    var num = parseInt(col,16);

    var r = (num >> 16) + amt;

    if ( r > 255 ) r = 255;
    else if  (r < 0) r = 0;

    var b = ((num >> 8) & 0x00FF) + amt;

    if ( b > 255 ) b = 255;
    else if  (b < 0) b = 0;
    
    var g = (num & 0x0000FF) + amt;

    if ( g > 255 ) g = 255;
    else if  ( g < 0 ) g = 0;

    return (usePound?"#":"") + (g | (b << 8) | (r << 16)).toString(16);
}
```

OK, so now it's not just a couple of lines, but it seems far simpler and if you're not using the "#" and don't need to check for colors out of range, it is only a couple of lines.

If not using the "#", you can just add it in code like:

```
var myColor = "3F6D2A";
myColor = LightenDarkenColor(myColor,10);
thePlaceTheColorIsUsed = ("#" + myColor);
```

I guess my main question is, am I correct here? Does this not encompass most (normal) situations? And if so, what is the fastest and smallest way to do this? I want to use in animations and in a small environment, so speed is the first most important factor here, size second, accuracy third, readability? huh? not on the list of requirements (sorry, I know half of you are tearing out your eyes right now!).

Comment: If you don't get expected results when modifying colors, I suggest looking into LAB color space, which is closer to human vision. Many languages have libraries for conversion. In my experience especially shades of orange can be problematic when darkening or lightening.

Comment: Very good point. However, the main purpose of this question was to find, firstly, the fastest runtime and smallest size formula... and secondly, its accuracy. Hence, why I didn't deal with converting to HSL or whatever. Here speed and size are more important. But, as you can see with my version 2 of the formula. Using LERP to shade will result in pleasant oranges through out the shade range. Take a look at the color chart below and let me know if that shade range isn't pretty darn close to actual accurate.

Comment: I got a bit confused with the structure in here, but you're right, the orange levels for shadeColor1 seem to be very good.

Comment: Lol, you mean shadeColor2.  I guess the structure you are talking about is the overall layout of the answer itself?  Any hints to make more clear?

Comment: No, shadeColor2 does not account for the hue shift that orange would normally go through. Here is a screenshot showing how orange behaves in (CIE)LAB http://imgur.com/oHSPWCO. As to the structure, maybe it is just the length of the accepted answer that threw me off.

Comment: Oh, ok, now this is a wrench!  I was lead to believe that this shift in hue was a bad thing, as you see on my color chart below, it goes to pure red with only a 60% darkening, using shadeColor1. [Mark's post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141855/programmatically-lighten-a-color/141943#141943) gave me this idea. I make this [imgur](http://imgur.com/tmEAfau) using Adobe Illustrator's color picker, it doesn't have LAB. But check the oranges in the Red Box I drew. shadeColor2 roughly follows this column.

Comment: As you can see from my [imgur](http://imgur.com/tmEAfau) it creates oranges of the same hue that are just darker.  Which is probably what people are thinking of when they want a darker version of a color, I would assume.  As I slide down on that Illustrator color picker, if i was looking at the HSB colors, it just lowers the B (brightness). Hue never changes on that large square in that color picker, just Saturation and Brightness.  Hue is the skinny column.

Comment: Final thought, check this [MinutePhysics](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LKnqECcg6Gw) video.  It really kindda sounds like a similar problem, maybe not. I'm not sure what the solution is. Because a change in the Hue just seems like a problem, because a darker orange... to most people.. should still be orange... not red... I would assume.

Comment: There is just one issue in the function with # above is that it doesn't create the leading zeroes if the final hex code starts with zeroes. For example, if the hex code is #00a6b7 it will output it as #a6b7, which will not working if using as a css. You can correct that by replacing the return line by this:
  var string = "000000" + (g | (b << 8) | (r << 16)).toString(16);
  return (usePound?"#":"") + string.substr(string.length-6);

Comment: @RafaelLevy - Yes, this issue has been addressed. Please see the Accepted Answer to this question below for a version of the function that fixes many issues that the above function has in the Original Question.

Comment: hsl2rgb simple algorithm https://stackoverflow.com/a/54014428/860099

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski - yes, that does looks simple. Thanks! But the other main problem with HSL is the double conversion. One conversion to HSL just to raise/lower the L, then from HSL back to RGB. Which seems much slower, I would suspect. Especially seeing that if the input color was HEX there would be two more conversions from HEX to RGB and back. But I don't know. This version was to focus on speed and size first, accuracy was second. And the newer versions of this function will closely follow color shading as seen in Adobe products, as seen here (in the red box): http://imgur.com/tmEAfau

Comment: Did you get copy and pasted by Chris Coyier 2 years after your post? Naughty Chris! https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/lighten-darken-color/

Comment: @martinedwards - Yup! Scroll to the bottom of the comments on Coyier's article to read my reply.

Comment: if i want a darker color, how do I adjust it by say 40%, and if I want a lighter color how do I adjust it by 40% in the other direction?

Comment: @chovy - Hey, check the accepted answer below for a good solution and usage examples. But it looks like you want shading.. so, using the below solution, your answer would be something like `pSBC ( -0.4, color );` to darken and then `pSBC ( 0.4, color );` to lighten.

Comment: As a base function, I believe the math is incorrect.  You are adding `amt` when you should be calculating as a percentage the distance between the current color value and either `ff` for white or `00` for black in terms of lightening or darkening.  I've compiled a lot of the answers presented here and created a function that covers the range from -100 (darkens to #000000) to 100 (lightens to ffffff).  There's no need to default a value over 255 down to 255 or a value under 0 to 0 since it covers the case of over/under 100%.

https://gist.github.com/BigRaj/68388188743a62adbe087cc2dfb0ef4c

Comment: @BigRaj - Yes, thank you! And you are correct! But these ideas were already addressed in the accepted answer to this question below, years ago. As well, someone noted that using a Log approach (instead of a straight percentage) produced colors that people expect as well. Both methods were put in to the function below. As well the ability to blend two colors and many other useful features. Check the color chart in the accepted answer to see the difference. You say there is no need to default a value above 255 down to 255, but in your GitHub example that is exactly what your last line includes.

Comment: @PimpTrizkit good catch, I updated the code on the last line to remove the checks, as the values for RGB will never be out of the range of 0 -> 255.  Log blending is definitely the best approach, but with how long this whole thread is, and the amount of incorrect examples upvoted it's easy for incorrect math to get lost in the shuffle.  I only noticed it when I was building an interpolator between 2 colors.  #000-#fff is much easier math than #ff0000 -> #008000 by percentage of change.

Comment: @BigRaj - There is one other thing. Years ago, it was mentioned that adding a percentage, like in your example, will create a shift in hue, you have to do the math for a straight percentage a little differently to avoid that. Have you tried the accepted answer below? `pSBC` is great function and SUPER fast and has many features. And doesn't shift hue, and uses both linear and log blending, and error checking, and the input takes both RGB and HEX while outputting either... It is quite refined. I could go on, but the full list of features is listed right below.

Comment: @BigRaj - .... at least if I understand your code correctly. But, I didn't test `pSBC` and `ColorBrightness` (yours) together to see if they get the same exact numbers. You can reference the numbers on the color chart (below) for that. The top number is the "from" color and the bottom is the "to" color, and each box has a number from 0 to 1.0 representing the percentage passed in and, below that, it's RGB result.

Answer (score 1060, accepted):

*Well, this answer has become its own beast. Many new versions, it was getting stupid long. Many thanks to all of the great many contributors to this answer. But, in order to keep it simple for the masses. I archived all the versions/history of this answer's evolution to my [github](https://github.com/PimpTrizkit/PJs/wiki/12.-Shade,-Blend-and-Convert-a-Web-Color-(pSBC.js)#stackoverflow-archive-begin). And started it over clean on StackOverflow here with the newest version. A special thanks goes out to [Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/740553/mike-pomax-kamermans) for this version. He gave me the new math.*

---

This function (`pSBC`) will take a HEX or RGB web color. `pSBC` can shade it darker or lighter, or blend it with a second color, and can also pass it right thru but convert from Hex to RGB (Hex2RGB) or RGB to Hex (RGB2Hex). All without you even knowing what color format you are using.

This runs really fast, probably the fastest, especially considering its many features. It was a long time in the making. See the whole story on my [github](https://github.com/PimpTrizkit/PJs/wiki/12.-Shade,-Blend-and-Convert-a-Web-Color-(pSBC.js)#stackoverflow-archive-begin).  If you want the absolutely smallest and fastest possible way to shade or blend, see the Micro Functions below and use one of the 2-liner speed demons. They are great for intense animations, but this version here is fast enough for most animations.

This function uses Log Blending or Linear Blending. However, it does NOT convert to HSL to properly lighten or darken a color. Therefore, **results from this function might differ** from those much larger and much slower functions that use HSL (like TinyColor? which is actually quite large, in comparison).

> [jsFiddle with pSBC](https://jsfiddle.net/PimpTrizkit/a7ac0qvp/)
>
> [github > pSBC Wiki](https://github.com/PimpTrizkit/PJs/wiki/12.-Shade,-Blend-and-Convert-a-Web-Color-(pSBC.js))

Features:

- Auto-detects and accepts standard Hex colors in the form of strings. For example: `"#AA6622"` or `"#bb551144"`.
- Auto-detects and accepts standard RGB colors in the form of strings. For example: `"rgb(123,45,76)"` or `"rgba(45,15,74,0.45)"`.
- Shades colors to white or black by percentage.
- Blends colors together by percentage.
- Does Hex2RGB and RGB2Hex conversion at the same time, or solo.
- Accepts 3 digit (or 4 digit w/ alpha) HEX color codes, in the form #RGB (or #RGBA). It will expand them. For Example: `"#C41"` becomes `"#CC4411"`.
- Accepts and (Linear) blends alpha channels. If either the `c0` (from) color or the `c1` (to) color has an alpha channel, then the returned color will have an alpha channel. If both colors have an alpha channel, then the returned color will be a linear blend of the two alpha channels using the percentage given (just as if it were a normal color channel). If only one of the two colors has an alpha channel, this alpha will just be passed thru to the returned color. This allows one to blend/shade a transparent color while maintaining the transparency level. Or, if the transparency levels should blend as well, make sure both colors have alphas. When shading, it will pass the alpha channel straight thru. If you want basic shading that also shades the alpha channel, then use `rgb(0,0,0,1)` or `rgb(255,255,255,1)` as your `c1` (to) color (or their hex equivalents). For RGB colors, the returned color's alpha channel will be rounded to 3 decimal places.
- RGB2Hex and Hex2RGB conversions are implicit when using blending. Regardless of the `c0` (from) color; the returned color will always be in the color format of the `c1` (to) color, if one exists. If there is no `c1` (to) color, then pass `'c'` in as the `c1` color and it will shade and convert whatever the `c0` color is. If conversion only is desired, then pass `0` in as the percentage (`p`) as well. If the `c1` color is omitted or a non-`string` is passed in, it will not convert.
- A secondary function is added to the global as well. `pSBCr` can be passed a Hex or RGB color and it returns an object containing this color information. Its in the form: {r: XXX, g: XXX, b: XXX, a: X.XXX}. Where `.r`, `.g`, and `.b` have range 0 to 255. And when there is no alpha: `.a` is -1. Otherwise: `.a` has range 0.000 to 1.000.
- For RGB output, it outputs `rgba()` over `rgb()` when a color with an alpha channel was passed into `c0` (from) and/or `c1` (to).
- Minor Error Checking has been added. It's not perfect. It can still crash or create jibberish. But it will catch some stuff. Basically, if the structure is wrong in some ways or if the percentage is not a number or out of scope, it will return `null`. An example: `pSBC(0.5,"salt") == null`, where as it thinks `#salt` is a valid color. Delete the four lines which end with `return null;` to remove this feature and make it faster and smaller.
- Uses Log Blending. Pass `true` in for `l` (the 4th parameter) to use Linear Blending.

#### Code:

```js
// Version 4.0
const pSBC=(p,c0,c1,l)=>{
    let r,g,b,P,f,t,h,i=parseInt,m=Math.round,a=typeof(c1)=="string";
    if(typeof(p)!="number"||p<-1||p>1||typeof(c0)!="string"||(c0[0]!='r'&&c0[0]!='#')||(c1&&!a))return null;
    if(!this.pSBCr)this.pSBCr=(d)=>{
        let n=d.length,x={};
        if(n>9){
            [r,g,b,a]=d=d.split(","),n=d.length;
            if(n<3||n>4)return null;
            x.r=i(r[3]=="a"?r.slice(5):r.slice(4)),x.g=i(g),x.b=i(b),x.a=a?parseFloat(a):-1
        }else{
            if(n==8||n==6||n<4)return null;
            if(n<6)d="#"+d[1]+d[1]+d[2]+d[2]+d[3]+d[3]+(n>4?d[4]+d[4]:"");
            d=i(d.slice(1),16);
            if(n==9||n==5)x.r=d>>24&255,x.g=d>>16&255,x.b=d>>8&255,x.a=m((d&255)/0.255)/1000;
            else x.r=d>>16,x.g=d>>8&255,x.b=d&255,x.a=-1
        }return x};
    h=c0.length>9,h=a?c1.length>9?true:c1=="c"?!h:false:h,f=this.pSBCr(c0),P=p<0,t=c1&&c1!="c"?this.pSBCr(c1):P?{r:0,g:0,b:0,a:-1}:{r:255,g:255,b:255,a:-1},p=P?p*-1:p,P=1-p;
    if(!f||!t)return null;
    if(l)r=m(P*f.r+p*t.r),g=m(P*f.g+p*t.g),b=m(P*f.b+p*t.b);
    else r=m((P*f.r**2+p*t.r**2)**0.5),g=m((P*f.g**2+p*t.g**2)**0.5),b=m((P*f.b**2+p*t.b**2)**0.5);
    a=f.a,t=t.a,f=a>=0||t>=0,a=f?a<0?t:t<0?a:a*P+t*p:0;
    if(h)return"rgb"+(f?"a(":"(")+r+","+g+","+b+(f?","+m(a*1000)/1000:"")+")";
    else return"#"+(4294967296+r*16777216+g*65536+b*256+(f?m(a*255):0)).toString(16).slice(1,f?undefined:-2)
}
```

#### Usage:

```js
// Setup:

let color1 = "rgb(20,60,200)";
let color2 = "rgba(20,60,200,0.67423)";
let color3 = "#67DAF0";
let color4 = "#5567DAF0";
let color5 = "#F3A";
let color6 = "#F3A9";
let color7 = "rgb(200,60,20)";
let color8 = "rgba(200,60,20,0.98631)";

// Tests:

/*** Log Blending ***/
// Shade (Lighten or Darken)
pSBC ( 0.42, color1 ); // rgb(20,60,200) + [42% Lighter] => rgb(166,171,225)
pSBC ( -0.4, color5 ); // #F3A + [40% Darker] => #c62884
pSBC ( 0.42, color8 ); // rgba(200,60,20,0.98631) + [42% Lighter] => rgba(225,171,166,0.98631)

// Shade with Conversion (use "c" as your "to" color)
pSBC ( 0.42, color2, "c" ); // rgba(20,60,200,0.67423) + [42% Lighter] + [Convert] => #a6abe1ac

// RGB2Hex & Hex2RGB Conversion Only (set percentage to zero)
pSBC ( 0, color6, "c" ); // #F3A9 + [Convert] => rgba(255,51,170,0.6)

// Blending
pSBC ( -0.5, color2, color8 ); // rgba(20,60,200,0.67423) + rgba(200,60,20,0.98631) + [50% Blend] => rgba(142,60,142,0.83)
pSBC ( 0.7, color2, color7 ); // rgba(20,60,200,0.67423) + rgb(200,60,20) + [70% Blend] => rgba(168,60,111,0.67423)
pSBC ( 0.25, color3, color7 ); // #67DAF0 + rgb(200,60,20) + [25% Blend] => rgb(134,191,208)
pSBC ( 0.75, color7, color3 ); // rgb(200,60,20) + #67DAF0 + [75% Blend] => #86bfd0

/*** Linear Blending ***/
// Shade (Lighten or Darken)
pSBC ( 0.42, color1, false, true ); // rgb(20,60,200) + [42% Lighter] => rgb(119,142,223)
pSBC ( -0.4, color5, false, true ); // #F3A + [40% Darker] => #991f66
pSBC ( 0.42, color8, false, true ); // rgba(200,60,20,0.98631) + [42% Lighter] => rgba(223,142,119,0.98631)

// Shade with Conversion (use "c" as your "to" color)
pSBC ( 0.42, color2, "c", true ); // rgba(20,60,200,0.67423) + [42% Lighter] + [Convert] => #778edfac

// RGB2Hex & Hex2RGB Conversion Only (set percentage to zero)
pSBC ( 0, color6, "c", true ); // #F3A9 + [Convert] => rgba(255,51,170,0.6)

// Blending
pSBC ( -0.5, color2, color8, true ); // rgba(20,60,200,0.67423) + rgba(200,60,20,0.98631) + [50% Blend] => rgba(110,60,110,0.83)
pSBC ( 0.7, color2, color7, true ); // rgba(20,60,200,0.67423) + rgb(200,60,20) + [70% Blend] => rgba(146,60,74,0.67423)
pSBC ( 0.25, color3, color7, true ); // #67DAF0 + rgb(200,60,20) + [25% Blend] => rgb(127,179,185)
pSBC ( 0.75, color7, color3, true ); // rgb(200,60,20) + #67DAF0 + [75% Blend] => #7fb3b9

/*** Other Stuff ***/
// Error Checking
pSBC ( 0.42, "#FFBAA" ); // #FFBAA + [42% Lighter] => null  (Invalid Input Color)
pSBC ( 42, color1, color5 ); // rgb(20,60,200) + #F3A + [4200% Blend] => null  (Invalid Percentage Range)
pSBC ( 0.42, {} ); // [object Object] + [42% Lighter] => null  (Strings Only for Color)
pSBC ( "42", color1 ); // rgb(20,60,200) + ["42"] => null  (Numbers Only for Percentage)
pSBC ( 0.42, "salt" ); // salt + [42% Lighter] => null  (A Little Salt is No Good...)

// Error Check Fails (Some Errors are not Caught)
pSBC ( 0.42, "#salt" ); // #salt + [42% Lighter] => #a5a5a500  (...and a Pound of Salt is Jibberish)

// Ripping
pSBCr ( color4 ); // #5567DAF0 + [Rip] => [object Object] => {'r':85,'g':103,'b':218,'a':0.941}
```

---

The picture below will help show the difference in the two blending methods:

[image]

---

### Micro Functions

If you really want speed and size, you will have to use RGB not HEX. RGB is more straightforward and simple, HEX writes too slow and comes in too many flavors for a simple two-liner (IE. it could be a 3, 4, 6, or 8 digit HEX code). You will also need to sacrifice some features, no error checking, no HEX2RGB nor RGB2HEX. As well, you will need to choose a specific function (based on its function name below) for the color blending math, and if you want shading or blending. These functions do support alpha channels. And when both input colors have alphas it will Linear Blend them. If only one of the two colors has an alpha, it will pass it straight thru to the resulting color. Below are two liner functions that are incredibly fast and small:

```js
const RGB_Linear_Blend=(p,c0,c1)=>{
    var i=parseInt,r=Math.round,P=1-p,[a,b,c,d]=c0.split(","),[e,f,g,h]=c1.split(","),x=d||h,j=x?","+(!d?h:!h?d:r((parseFloat(d)*P+parseFloat(h)*p)*1000)/1000+")"):")";
    return"rgb"+(x?"a(":"(")+r(i(a[3]=="a"?a.slice(5):a.slice(4))*P+i(e[3]=="a"?e.slice(5):e.slice(4))*p)+","+r(i(b)*P+i(f)*p)+","+r(i(c)*P+i(g)*p)+j;
}

const RGB_Linear_Shade=(p,c)=>{
    var i=parseInt,r=Math.round,[a,b,c,d]=c.split(","),P=p<0,t=P?0:255*p,P=P?1+p:1-p;
    return"rgb"+(d?"a(":"(")+r(i(a[3]=="a"?a.slice(5):a.slice(4))*P+t)+","+r(i(b)*P+t)+","+r(i(c)*P+t)+(d?","+d:")");
}

const RGB_Log_Blend=(p,c0,c1)=>{
    var i=parseInt,r=Math.round,P=1-p,[a,b,c,d]=c0.split(","),[e,f,g,h]=c1.split(","),x=d||h,j=x?","+(!d?h:!h?d:r((parseFloat(d)*P+parseFloat(h)*p)*1000)/1000+")"):")";
    return"rgb"+(x?"a(":"(")+r((P*i(a[3]=="a"?a.slice(5):a.slice(4))**2+p*i(e[3]=="a"?e.slice(5):e.slice(4))**2)**0.5)+","+r((P*i(b)**2+p*i(f)**2)**0.5)+","+r((P*i(c)**2+p*i(g)**2)**0.5)+j;
}

const RGB_Log_Shade=(p,c)=>{
    var i=parseInt,r=Math.round,[a,b,c,d]=c.split(","),P=p<0,t=P?0:p*255**2,P=P?1+p:1-p;
    return"rgb"+(d?"a(":"(")+r((P*i(a[3]=="a"?a.slice(5):a.slice(4))**2+t)**0.5)+","+r((P*i(b)**2+t)**0.5)+","+r((P*i(c)**2+t)**0.5)+(d?","+d:")");
}
```

---

Want more info? Read the full writeup on [github](https://github.com/PimpTrizkit/PJs/wiki/12.-Shade,-Blend-and-Convert-a-Web-Color-(pSBC.js)).

PT

(P.s. If anyone has the math for another blending method, please share.)

Comment: shadeColor('#000000',100) = #ffffff, shadeColor('#000000',1) = #030303... it looks like you're just multiplying "percent" times 2.55 and adding it to the color which doesn't make sense to me. Also G and B seem to be backwards in both forms.

Comment: Yes, that is what I was trying to describe in my text above. Here, `percent` is the percentage of white you want to add. If you add 255, you will add full white. If `percent` is 100, thats full white (`2.55*100`). This will add white to any color. In order to add white to a color, you need to add even amounts of all colors. Therefore, `shadeColor("#000000",1) = "#030303"` ... in english is: "Shade black 1% of the way to white.". Which makes it slightly less black. It "Lightened" it.

Comment: A PHP version for those who need it: https://gist.github.com/chaoszcat/5325115#file-gistfile1-php

Comment: Nice! Good to see its getting around.  Also, interesting to note... the double ternary statement seems to also work in PHP as well.

Comment: I used [TinyColor](https://github.com/bgrins/TinyColor)  -- `tinycolor.darken(color,amount);`

Comment: TinyColor is cool. No doubt about that. Tons of features, more accurate, uses HSL, list goes on, etc... Its however, not that tiny nor fast (comparatively).

Comment: Great post ... :) ... just created Swift extension of it: https://gist.github.com/matejukmar/1da47f7a950d1ba68a95

Comment: Here is the PHP version for the updated shadeColor2 version:

`function shadeColor2($color, $percent) {
  
  $color = str_replace("#", "", $color);
  
  $t=$percent<0?0:255;
  $p=$percent<0?$percent*-1:$percent;
  
  $RGB = str_split($color, 2);
  $R=hexdec($RGB[0]);
  $G=hexdec($RGB[1]);
  $B=hexdec($RGB[2]);
  
  return '#'.substr(dechex(0x1000000+(round(($t-$R)*$p)+$R)*0x10000+(round(($t-$G)*$p)+$G)*0x100+(round(($t-$B)*$p)+$B)),1);
 }`

Comment: I'd like to understand why `shadeColor2(shadeColor2(color, percent), -percent/(percent + 1)) !== color`. Shouldn't the color stay the same if I lighten it by given percent and then darken it by reverse percent?

Comment: Think of it this way. If I took the number `100` and lowered it by 10% it would be `90`. Then, If I raised `90` by 10% it would be `99`.   And In reverse... If I had `100` and raised it by 10% I would have `110` and then if I lowered it by 10%... I would have `99`. I think this trick is used in the financial system to make (steal) money.

Comment: This is why I don't lighten by 10 % and darken by 10 %, but instead use the reverse percentage, which is ~9.09 % for 10 % (e.g., start with `100`, increase it by 10 % to `110`, and then decrease it by 9.09 % back to `100`). However, even with this adjustment, the result is not the original color.

Comment: Sorry, I apparently missed that point. There are maybe two reasons. The first and obvious is that I use Math.Round and you don't get to use decimal numbers for accurate coloring (colors dont have decimals in hex).
For example, if the Red channel is  `8`, add `10%` you get `8.8` which rounds to `9`. Then take `9.09%` away from `9` and you get `8.1819`. Which rounds to `8` so that's a bad example. But it still illustrates that you are taking `9.09%` of `9` and not `8.8`. So there might be some numbers in there that don't round back out exactly the same as my example here.

Comment: Secondly,  Its taking a percentage of the distance to white (or black) not a percentage of the `color`. For instance, lets run the math on the Red color channel. With a color of `#08a35c`.  (Red = 0x08 or 8 (in decimal)) ==> (255-8 = 247) ==> (247*0.10 = 24.7) ==> (Math.round(24.7) = 25) ==> (25+8 = 33) ==> Red = 33 (without rounding it would be 32.7)
Then lets reverse it: (Red = 33) ==> (0-33 = -33) ==> (-33 * 0.0909 = -2.9997) ==> (Math.round(-2.9997) = -3) ==> (-3 + 33 = 30) ==> Red = 30

Comment: As you can see, the percentage is not be taken from the same number. When lightening a color, the `10%` is applied to the distance from current red to white (255-8), so its `10%` of `247`. When darkening a color, the `9.09%` is applied to the distance from red to black (0-33), so its `9.09%` of `-33`.   This is where I would assume your seeing the difference. Unfortunately, shading a color up 10% is not as simple as moving an integer up 10%.

Comment: Final thoughts, I am not using HSL here for true coloring. Using HSL is much slower and many many lines long. I don't know how the HSL math works. But you might be able to give 10% and take the reverse to revert back to the exact color using HSL. Try TinyColor as mentioned in a comment above. It does not seem that reverse percentages are usable with my algorithm, seeing that it doesn't apply it to the same number.

Comment: No problem. Yes, we were aware that this RGB only method of color shading is not 100% accurate. On my color chart above, you can still notice a change in the hue on darkening shadeColor2 at 90%. Wait, you may have just given me an epiphany.

Comment: the RGB version return something weird when I put rgb(0, 186, 241) as color : `var color = "rgb(0, 186, 241)"; shadeRGBColor(color, -20);` will return rgb(00,-3720186,-4820241)

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Because the usage has changed from the first `shadeColor` version above compared to all the rest.  Only the first version's usage takes percentages as `-20`.  As mentioned above, and shown in the usages examples above you need to use `-0.2` for negative 20% when using `shadeRGBColor` or any of the other versions except the first.

Comment: Great answer, unfortunately doesn't support rgba with transparency ie `rgba(15,15,15,0.5)` and also doesn't support 3 digit codes ie `#ccc` @jindrichm perhaps you could just save the original color, convert it 10% lighter, then just use the stored value?

Comment: Java/Android version in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32942503/1048340

Comment: For anyone like me who just want's to use the first (simple) example, add the following to the beginning of the `shadeColor1()` to convert any 3 digit hex codes to 6, so that it processes correctly.

`if (color.length < 7){ color = '#' + color[1] + color[1] + color[2] + color[2] + color[3] + color[3]; }`

Comment: Yup!  Thats also why I marked the `//ErrorCheck` lines with comments in v3. If you delete them... its then essentially the same thing... but with conversions.

Comment: Please note...  `shadeColor1` is deprecated. Use `shadeColor2` or `shadeRGBColor` for the two-liner.

Comment: Great, detailed answer. If you care to shorten the error checking some, then you can do this: `if (isNaN(p) || p<-1 || p>1 || typeof from!=='string' || (from[0]!=='r' && from[0]!=='#') || (to && typeof to!=='string')) return null;`

Comment: Other micro-ops you can do: (1) `RGB[3] = parseFloat(d[3]) || -1;`, (2) replace the switch block with `if (l===1) return null;`, (3) since we know the data type, use `===` and `!==` instead of `==` and `!=`, respectively (as I have done), (4) in some cases defining too many local variables is more expensive than it's worth, so I would just use `parseInt()` as is instead of assigning it to a variable.

Comment: Correction: `shadeBlendConvert(0.3,"#FFBAA");` returns "#57fcc4", not `null`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment and help! Unfortunately, I will be disagreeing with most of what you said here.
ErrorCheck) `isNaN` has weird behavior. Actually, it doesn't check if `p` is a `number` but rather if its `NaN`, which is, inversely, not exactly the same thing. Check this:[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN). It even mentions to use my method for "is not `number`".

Comment: (1) This is technically shorter, yes. not by much. `parseFloat` will return `NaN` not `false` or `null` or `0`; so using it as a `false` is odd at best. This is the case where you would use `isNaN` as suggested to detect this `NaN` as a boolean. But that would add yet another function call. And yours is slower for when there is not an alpha channel. As it has to run `parseFloat` before the condition check to determine that its bad.  The code v3, will skip the `parseFloat` all together if there is no alpha channel. And if there is, it runs the same speed as yours. One condition and one function

Comment: (2) Sorry again, this change is why your `"#FFBAA"` ErrorCheck is not working in your third comment. The existing `switch` statement is needed. `l` is the length. And this in the `else` block which means we are doing hex. So any length `l` above 9 will goto RGB. Which means this "hex" string will have 9 or fewer characters. Well a 9 character hex color is legal, such as `#5567DAF0` with the alpha channel. But 8 characters is not. Your suggestion only checks if this "hex" string is length 1. It misses all the other invalid hex string sizes, like 8, 6, 3, and 2.

Comment: (3) This idea I have gone back and forth on. You mention: since we know the data type to use the `===` and `!==` instead. But those comparators check for data types. As if, we cared. I would think just the opposite here. Because we *do know* that they are the same data type then we don't need to also check it, we can just assume they are always going to be equal, no need for the extra processing and code length. Please stop me if I'm talking out my ass here.

Comment: (4) IMHO, your best point. Yes, the renaming of `parseInt` is not necessary and does slow it down by just a touch. But there are a grand total of 6 local variables declared in that block (not counting the function's parameters but counting this `parseInt` renaming). The `p` and `to` and `h` local variables are recycled, so im not sure their multiple declarations count. This would make it 6 additional local vars. Im not sure thats "too many" but it is something. I did this to compress the code size a touch.

Comment: (2) <Continued> But your insight is correct, point taken. However, this would be the shorter non-`switch` version: 
`if(l==8||l==6||l<4)return null;`.
 I will edit.  I used the `switch` because I was hoping it was faster *under the hood* for multi comparisons on the same primitive. But this version only has 3 comparisons. So I'm sure that makes up for it. And saves 27 bytes on the download.

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed and nice answer! Which code snippet should I use if I just want to darken/lighten an rgb color?

Comment: Any of the ones after the first one. It just depends on which functionality you want. If you dont need ErrorCheck nor 3 Digit Hex decoding. Then just use the one near the top (after the color chart), Version 2 RGB, I will rename and edit to make more clear.

Comment: JVM? I hope you realise you are writing JavaScript not Java.

Comment: Yes, of course. OK JVM, wasn't the right word. Im not sure what they call it.. a plug in? an extension? the JS engine?  I thought it was still called a VM of some sort. I guess not.

Comment: missing rgba possibility https://jsfiddle.net/p3wqy9pb/, there are color editors that use rgba instead  rgb

Comment: Works great! But what did you intend by reassigning `h`? The first assignment is lost, right? `var i=...,h=from.length>9,h=typeof(to)==...`

Comment: This is pretty freakin' awesome! I do have one small problem with it, however: The PHP version seems to have an issue that baffles me. When calling the `shadeColor2` function, I get the message: `Notice: Undefined variable: G‌​ in /Users/apache/Sites/acs2017/_/functions.php on line 35`. I've checked and `$G` is, most certainly, defined! So what gives?

Comment: @Benn - I see your point. The problem probably lies in that the function name is "rgba" and, while it works fine, this solution only looks for "rgb". Version 3 does do alpha colors both rgb and hex, just not labeled "rgba". I will have to fix.

Comment: @automorphic - Well, check out more of the line (with spacing): `h = from.length > 9,   h = typeof(to)=="string"?to.length>9?true:to=="c"?!h:false:h,`
The next reassignment of `h` uses the previous value of `h`, in a truly confusing tri-ternary statement.. This was a quick variable recycling.

Comment: @PimpTrizkit I see - you're playing with us! Operator precedence obfuscation ;-) Doesn't that last part `!h:false:h` just reduce to `h`?  Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: @automorphic - Nope, I was not playing with you guys. Sure its kind of obfuscation, but only by chance. That line is just very tight, my goal here was to also make it as physically small as possible. There are three ternary statements in one.. each ternary has one `?` and one `:`.  So there are three of each stringed together. Look at it this way: `typeof(to)=="string" ? (to.length>9? true : (to=="c"? !h : false)) : h` .Parenthesis help for readability only, and the funny thing is that if `typeof(to)!="string"` then `h` will be `h`, and if it is a string...well thats a more confusing question.

Comment: @automorphic - But to point out the function here. I'm using `h` to preload a condition of whether or not to use rgb as the resulting answer (or hex). But this condition is not a straightforward true/false. Its like four of them. The least significant is the first one `h = from.length>9` where we check if the `from` color is rgb(true) or hex (false). Its stored in `h` for now, it might be needed in a bit. Then we check if the `to` color is given to us...

Comment: <cont.> If `to` is not given, then the `h` is fine by itself. If the `to` is given to us then we check if it is also rgb, if so, then we set `h` to `true` so that the result will be rgb.  But if the given `to` color is not rgb it could be either hex or the `c` for conversion. So we check for that. If its not the `c` for conversion then we can set `h` to false for hex. And if it is the `c` for conversion we set `h` to its inverse.

Comment: @Sturm - Thanks! I think so too! Sorry for your issue with the PHP version. But, as you can see in the credits, I didn't write it. So I can't help you as of yet...  I think it might be time I tackle that...
But for general troubleshooting steps: Are you getting that error on the assignment line or the `return` line? I assume its on the `return` line... Try tearing that statement into multiples where the two uses of `G` are in separate statements (lines). As in, build it as a separate string var, in pieces, then just `return` it. Maybe that will shed some light.

Comment: I wish there were more answers like this on SO. Keep up the good work!

Comment: @PimpTrizkit Thanks a lot for this ! I think the version 3 universal have two missing `this.`for the sbcRip function. 

Fix : 
`
f = this.sbcRip(from),
t = this.sbcRip(to)
`

Comment: @Wifsimster - Thank you! I'm not sure why you would need the `this`. It works fine for me and others.

Comment: To all using Version 3. There are bugs. Read the Edit note. Please update to the new Version 3.1

Comment: Well, @PimpTrizkit, I found a need for the PHP version of `shadeColor2` again. I ran into that same issue with the linter thinking that `$G` is undefined. Turns out that the version you copy-pasted from @KevinM's comment has a tiny flaw: The bit `+$G` on the `return` line is actually using a different encoding or something like that. I simply deleted it, and re-typed it out—no problem! Now the linter passes and I'm sure it will execute without error. I hope this helps someone else! (Also, you might want to edit your answer so other copy-pasters don't run into this same issue.)

Comment: Tiny color does a good job of retaining the color -- sometimes, as with this example, the color is lost when it darkens -- it turns to black fast.  TinyColor goes light and dark similar to MS Paint.  Awesome.  https://github.com/bgrins/TinyColor

Comment: @GeorgeBeier - Thanks for your comment! Although, I'm not totally sure what your saying about my function here. As it seems you reference TinyColor twice, and not my function at all. Anyhow, TinyColor is not tiny (over 35KB) and it is much much slower. And if you would kindly check this graphic: https://imgur.com/a/ZJTAc4F you will see that my function (which uses Linear Blending) does 100% exactly match MS Paint. So, I'm not sure what the issue is that you are talking about. Unless you are talking about a previous version of my function. Use version 3.1 instead.

Comment: @PimpTrizkit do give https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LKnqECcg6Gw a quick view though, it's pretty good at covering why you need log (even if sometimes a particular interpolation "feels" nicer). It's simply what is necessary to correctly blend colors. As someone who worked with that a lot, your linear blends look incredibly wrong =) They're aesthetically pleasing as palettes, and good "pick 4 random and art is going to happen", but they look super incorrect as blend gradients.

Comment: Well when I use TinyColor and darken #FFDC92 by 20%, I get #FFBB2C.  Using your fiddle posted above, with 20% to black I get  #ccb075.    The original color is orange(ish) with 100% red.  TinyColor holds on to the red value long as it darkens, and the orange color is retained.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans - Alrighty, I posted a new version. It handles the Log math you presented (and its much faster too, but for different reasons). I kept the Linear math as well, there is now a toggle. I guess the reason for this is that after looking at several examples of the difference between Log and Linear. There are times I would still want Linear. It was kind of funny that you linked to me the exact same MinutePhysics video that I linked to someone else in a comment to the OP.  I feel it is a bit like the difference between mixing paint or mixing light.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans - When looking at the LAB color space which can be viewed as a three dimensional object. The Log blending follows the curvature of the exterior shell of that three dimensional space. Which brings red thru yellow to get to green. But I often viewed blending as cutting a straight line thru the three dimensional object (like digging a hole to china, not flying an airplane to china). In which case it would stay away from yellow. Similar to how mixing red and green paint would act.  Anyhow, for those reasons is why I kept both methods. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: very nice: letting people pick which looks best is definitely the way to go =)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans - Ya, 'which looks best' is usually the right answer when designing graphics, imho. Another note: I kept a Linear Blend for alphas for when both colors have an alpha channel. I'm not sure if this messes it up, but it seemed that alphas were independent of the rest of the color and needed a smooth even spaced transition. Thoughts?

Comment: yeah, good call: the alpha channel is typically independent of the color information, so keep that linear makes sense.

Comment: `'pSBCr' is not defined                                                 no-undef`

Comment: @5ervant - hmm, I don't get this error. `pSBCr` is defined in the function as you can see. Starting with the line `if(!this.pSBCr)this.pSBCr=(d)=>{`. This is a standalone function, I didn't test its usage when used as an object or as a member function or some other situation where the `this` keyword gets reassigned. Try adding `this.` to the beginning of the two `pSBCr` calls. These calls are on the line starting with `h=c0.length>9`. And please let me know if that works. Thank you for your time and comment.

Comment: @PimpTrizkit I forgot that there are also other errors: `Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions` on `[r,g,b,a]=d=d.split(","),n=d.length;`, `x.r=i(r[3]=="a"?r.slice(5):r.slice(4)),x.g=i(g),x.b=i(b),x.a=a?parseFloat(a):-1`, `if(n==9||n==5)x.r=d>>24&255,x.g=d>>16&255,x.b=d>>8&255,x.a=m((d&255)/0.255)/1000;` and more. `no-undef` is gone with `this.pSBCr`. I'm coding with Node.js.

Comment: @5ervant - I'm glad you fixed that part. I'm not sure what environment you are working in. This all works just fine with my updated Chrome (not using any other API/libraries). The `[r,g,b,a]=` notation is new for ECMA6 (http://es6-features.org/#ArrayMatching). Are you maybe using ECMA5 instead? Try breaking up that line you quoted into separate statements and lines to see exactly where it is crashing.

Comment: Before you get lost in the weeds, jump over to @PimpTrizkit jsfiddle and you can knock out your color shades and blends in no time.  Thanks!

Comment: I made an edit today. How embarrassing! I had a typeo in `RGB_Linear_Blend` and `RGB_Log_Blend`. They now work correctly.

Comment: About `pSBCr`... to be honest, I didn't know the demand for use of that function separately was going to exist. I was just trying to make the solution contained into one function to fit my situation. I will admit, it was an oversight.... or under-sight. But, it's not hard to cut and paste `pSBCr` and put it outside `pSBC`. Moving on, when I put "#ABCDEF" into `pSBCr` I get the object (not a number) == `{'r':171,'g':205,'b':239,'a':-1}`. Since this object is not a valid color anyhow (not a string), I decided to use `-1` to designate that no alpha channel was passed in at all. Sorry.

Comment: For anyone who is looking for JS equivalent for the SASS functions, use TinyColor. Its darken/lighten functions are exactly same as SASS darken/lighten functions.

Comment: I had issues with undefined `pSBCr` due to the context of `this` (I was calling it from within another object). I fixed it by adding a `let pSBCr = null;` at the start of the function, then replaced all `this.pSBCr` with `pSBCr`. Just out of interest, is there a benefit to using this.pSBCr instead?

Comment: @Djave - Well, `pSBC` was designed to work as a single stand-alone function, easy copy-pastable... and `pSBCr` was designed to be a global function as well... so instead of having two globals to copy-paste, I put the declaration `pSBCr` inside of `pSBC`... now we can call `pSBCr` directly (after a primer call to `pSBC`)... Moving on, now when calling `pSBCr` inside of `pSBC` (depending on where you put this function) you may need to call it using `this.pSBCr` instead of `pSBCr` (or vice versa, according to you). To be honest, I never thought `pSBCr` would be so popular.

Comment: I may have to do this differently. I never intended on `pSBC` being defined anywhere else besides the top global. But now, there are several comments about `pSBCr` and the `this` and using it either inside of `pSBC` or outside. What you did is just remove `pSBCr` from the global (or rather in your case from the parent object) and just make it a local variable inside of the `pSBC` function. Which, I think, makes it redefine `pSBCr` every time you run it, which is non-optimal. Plus, now you can't access `pSBCr` outside of `pSBC`.

Comment: @Anyone-else-who-cares : Also, yet another reason I decided to define `pSBCr` inside of `pSBC` was to recycle/reuse the the variables from `pSBC` so that more declarations and namespace can be avoided. I was going for super fast and tight function, at the time. If I wanted painfully slow and extremely bulky I would have used TinyColor, haha.. Anyhow, `r` `g` `b` `a` `i` `m`  were all recycled. I like recycling variables, it is terrible to read and share, unfortunately.

Comment: I've rewritten into TS here. I hope you like it. I also detected some unneeded checks and logic into your code and I removed them. https://stackoverflow.com/a/73660199/4537906

Answer (score 247):

I made a solution that works very nice for me:

```
function shadeColor(color, percent) {

    var R = parseInt(color.substring(1,3),16);
    var G = parseInt(color.substring(3,5),16);
    var B = parseInt(color.substring(5,7),16);

    R = parseInt(R * (100 + percent) / 100);
    G = parseInt(G * (100 + percent) / 100);
    B = parseInt(B * (100 + percent) / 100);

    R = (R<255)?R:255;  
    G = (G<255)?G:255;  
    B = (B<255)?B:255;  

    R = Math.round(R)
    G = Math.round(G)
    B = Math.round(B)

    var RR = ((R.toString(16).length==1)?"0"+R.toString(16):R.toString(16));
    var GG = ((G.toString(16).length==1)?"0"+G.toString(16):G.toString(16));
    var BB = ((B.toString(16).length==1)?"0"+B.toString(16):B.toString(16));

    return "#"+RR+GG+BB;
}
```

Example Lighten:

```
shadeColor("#63C6FF",40);
```

Example Darken:

```
shadeColor("#63C6FF",-40);
```

Comment: Nice, I like the percentage! +1  Tho, I would might do `R = ((R<255)?R:255).toString(16);` then `R = R.length==1 ? "0"+R : R` for speed. And im not sure the point of the toUpperCase?

Comment: It's unnecessary. I only add that for pretty print while test. I will edit that.

Comment: Very nice. However, should 100% lighter not become fully white and 100% dark always black, no matter what color? it seems -100 does make any color black, but 100 (positive) does not make it fully white.

Comment: doesnt work with solid colors like #ff0000, #00ff00, #0000ff

Comment: To make it work with black color I just did this hack 

`var R = parseInt(color.substring(1, 3), 16)
  var G = parseInt(color.substring(3, 5), 16)
  var B = parseInt(color.substring(5, 7), 16)
  if (R == 0)
    R = 32;
  if (G == 0)
    G = 32;
  if (B == 0)
    B = 32;`

Comment: Instead of `((R.toString(16).length==1)?"0"+R.toString(16):R.toString(16));` you can just use `R.toString(16).padStart(2, "0")`

Comment: es6 version: const shadeColor = (h, p) =>
  '#' +
  [1, 3, 5]
    .map(s => parseInt(h.substr(s, 2), 16))
    .map(c => parseInt((c * (100 + p)) / 100))
    .map(c => (c < 255 ? c : 255))
    .map(c => c.toString(16).padStart(2, '0'))
    .join('');

Comment: This is my favorite answer and it works in Safari too.  Safari fails with answers that use the '=>' operator.  Since most browsers return the css color in 'rgb(x,y,z)' format, I added an 'if' so it can take rgb values too...  **if (color.toLowerCase().indexOf('rgb')>-1){ var R = parseInt(color.substring(4).split(',')[0]); var G = parseInt(color.split(',')[1]); var B = parseInt(color.split(',')[2]) }else{...}**

Comment: unit tested this

 R = Math.round(R / 10) * 10

should be

 R = Math.round(R)

Answer (score 111):

Here is a super simple one liner based on Eric's answer

```
function adjust(color, amount) {
    return '#' + color.replace(/^#/, '').replace(/../g, color => ('0'+Math.min(255, Math.max(0, parseInt(color, 16) + amount)).toString(16)).substr(-2));
}
```

Examples:

```
adjust('#ffffff', -20) => "#ebebeb"
adjust('000000', 20) => "#141414"
```

Comment: "super simple" .

Comment: What is the amount? Could help to clarify if it's px, percent, etc.

Comment: You can make it a little bit shorter by using `\w\w` (which doesn't match `#`) in that regexp instead of removing and re-adding the `#`. I also don't quite follow why you're adding the `0` and then removing it? Is this some JS thing I'm not following (you're already using `toString()`, so you don't need to cast it?) At any rate, I ended up with the following, which seems to behave the same: `var adj = (c, a) => c.replace(/\w\w/g, m => Math.min(255, Math.max(0, parseInt(m, 16) + a)).toString(16))`

Comment: Added a demonstrator for this... https://jsfiddle.net/Abeeee/xeos0p42/20/

Comment: @MartinTournoij : The `'0'+` and `substr(-2)` are there for those numbers between 0 and 15, which will be only one digit in hexadecimal and thus give a malformed hexadecimal color string. He add the '0' in front and keep the last two digits so that 9 becomes '09', not just '9'. Good first point though! 

Answer (score 55):

I am adding my 2 cents here, a satisfyingly small combination of different answers:

```js
const colorShade = (col, amt) => {
  col = col.replace(/^#/, '')
  if (col.length === 3) col = col[0] + col[0] + col[1] + col[1] + col[2] + col[2]

  let [r, g, b] = col.match(/.{2}/g);
  ([r, g, b] = [parseInt(r, 16) + amt, parseInt(g, 16) + amt, parseInt(b, 16) + amt])

  r = Math.max(Math.min(255, r), 0).toString(16)
  g = Math.max(Math.min(255, g), 0).toString(16)
  b = Math.max(Math.min(255, b), 0).toString(16)

  const rr = (r.length < 2 ? '0' : '') + r
  const gg = (g.length < 2 ? '0' : '') + g
  const bb = (b.length < 2 ? '0' : '') + b

  return `#${rr}${gg}${bb}`
}
```

accepts a color starting with `#` or not, with 6 characters or 3 characters.

example of use: `colorShade('#54b946', -40)`

Here is the output of 4 colors with 3 shades lighter and 3 shades darker for each of them (amount is a multiple of 40 here).

[image]

Answer (score 11):

This is what I used based on your function. I prefer to use steps over percentage because it's more intuitive for me.

For example, 20% of a 200 blue value is much different than 20% of a 40 blue value.

Anyways, here's my modification, thanks for your original function.

```
function adjustBrightness(col, amt) {

    var usePound = false;

    if (col[0] == "#") {
        col = col.slice(1);
        usePound = true;
    }

    var R = parseInt(col.substring(0,2),16);
    var G = parseInt(col.substring(2,4),16);
    var B = parseInt(col.substring(4,6),16);

    // to make the colour less bright than the input
    // change the following three "+" symbols to "-"
    R = R + amt;
    G = G + amt;
    B = B + amt;

    if (R > 255) R = 255;
    else if (R < 0) R = 0;

    if (G > 255) G = 255;
    else if (G < 0) G = 0;

    if (B > 255) B = 255;
    else if (B < 0) B = 0;

    var RR = ((R.toString(16).length==1)?"0"+R.toString(16):R.toString(16));
    var GG = ((G.toString(16).length==1)?"0"+G.toString(16):G.toString(16));
    var BB = ((B.toString(16).length==1)?"0"+B.toString(16):B.toString(16));

    return (usePound?"#":"") + RR + GG + BB;

}
```

Comment: Found this much more useful than the top answer because the top answer was making my colours very intense instead of just darker. Cheers Eric

Comment: By far the best answer, kudos!

Answer (score 9):

Based on the, David Sherret and Pablo, answer above converted the solution to safer version for Typescript

```
/**
 * @param color Hex value format: #ffffff or ffffff
 * @param decimal lighten or darken decimal value, example 0.5 to lighten by 50% or 1.5 to darken by 50%.
 */
static shadeColor(color: string, decimal: number): string {
    const base = color.startsWith('#') ? 1 : 0;

    let r = parseInt(color.substring(base, 3), 16);
    let g = parseInt(color.substring(base + 2, 5), 16);
    let b = parseInt(color.substring(base + 4, 7), 16);

    r = Math.round(r / decimal);
    g = Math.round(g / decimal);
    b = Math.round(b / decimal);

    r = (r < 255)? r : 255;
    g = (g < 255)? g : 255;
    b = (b < 255)? b : 255;

    const rr = ((r.toString(16).length === 1)? `0${r.toString(16)}` : r.toString(16));
    const gg = ((g.toString(16).length === 1)? `0${g.toString(16)}` : g.toString(16));
    const bb = ((b.toString(16).length === 1)? `0${b.toString(16)}` : b.toString(16));

    return `#${rr}${gg}${bb}`;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I tried your function and there was a little bug: If some final 'r' value is 1 digit only, the result comes up like: 'a0a0a' when the right value is '0a0a0a', for example.
I just quick-fixed it by adding this instead of your return:

```
var rStr = (r.toString(16).length < 2)?'0'+r.toString(16):r.toString(16);
var gStr = (g.toString(16).length < 2)?'0'+g.toString(16):g.toString(16);
var bStr = (b.toString(16).length < 2)?'0'+b.toString(16):b.toString(16);

return (usePound?"#":"") + rStr + gStr + bStr;
```

Maybe it's not so nice but it do the work. Great function, BTW. Just what I needed. :)

Comment: Thanks for the debug and compliment!  Too bad its not an answer to whether or not there is a faster way, which is my main question. Like possibly one using all hex and no base conversions.  Tho, I guess you did tell me if i had correct code (+1). Unfortunately, the fix added considerably more overhead (now your calling toString 6 times), and slightly less KISS. Maybe it would be faster to check if the base10 number is 15 or less, before the base16 conversion. But, I like!

Answer (score 5):

have you thought about an rgb > hsl conversion? then just move the Luminosity up and down? thats the way I would go.

A quick look for some algorithms got me the following sites.

PHP:
http://serennu.com/colour/rgbtohsl.php

<strike>Javascript:
http://mjijackson.com/2008/02/rgb-to-hsl-and-rgb-to-hsv-color-model-conversion-algorithms-in-javascript</strike>

**EDIT** the above link is no longer valid. You can view git hub for the [page source](https://github.com/mjijackson/mjijackson.github.com/blob/master/2008/02/rgb-to-hsl-and-rgb-to-hsv-color-model-conversion-algorithms-in-javascript.txt) or the [gist](https://gist.github.com/mjijackson/5311256)

Alternatively another StackOverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353211/hsl-to-rgb-color-conversion) might be a good place to look.

---

Even though this is not the right choice for the OP the following is an approximation of the code I was originally suggesting. (Assuming you have rgb/hsl conversion functions)

```
var SHADE_SHIFT_AMOUNT = 0.1; 

function lightenShade(colorValue)
{
    if(colorValue && colorValue.length >= 6)
    {
        var redValue = parseInt(colorValue.slice(-6,-4), 16);
        var greenValue = parseInt(colorValue.slice(-4,-2), 16);
        var blueValue = parseInt(colorValue.slice(-2), 16);

        var hsl = rgbToHsl(redValue, greenValue, blueValue);
        hsl[2]= Math.min(hsl[2] + SHADE_SHIFT_AMOUNT, 1);
        var rgb = hslToRgb(hsl[0], hsl[1], hsl[2]);
        return "#" + rgb[0].toString(16) + rgb[1].toString(16) + rgb[2].toString(16);
    }
    return null;
}

function darkenShade(colorValue)
{
    if(colorValue && colorValue.length >= 6)
    {
        var redValue = parseInt(colorValue.slice(-6,-4), 16);
        var greenValue = parseInt(colorValue.slice(-4,-2), 16);
        var blueValue = parseInt(colorValue.slice(-2), 16);

        var hsl = rgbToHsl(redValue, greenValue, blueValue);
        hsl[2]= Math.max(hsl[2] - SHADE_SHIFT_AMOUNT, 0);
        var rgb = hslToRgb(hsl[0], hsl[1], hsl[2]);
        return "#" + rgb[0].toString(16) + rgb[1].toString(16) + rgb[2].toString(16);
    }
    return null;
}
```

This assumes:

1. You have functions `hslToRgb` and `rgbToHsl`.
2. The parameter `colorValue` is a string in the form **#RRGGBB**

Although if we are discussing css there is a syntax for specifying [hsl/hsla](http://caniuse.com/css3-colors) for IE9/Chrome/Firefox.

Comment: Interesting, but then wouldn't I have to convert from hex string to rgb to hsl? Seems like its more complicated. Maybe I'm missing something. But, I am looking for a KISS way to do it, as well as fast as possible (execution time). I feel ideally, if i could do it all in hex that would be the fastest. But, the solution I've developed here involves going to rgb to be able to add an incremental amount.

Comment: Yes i assume it would be slower, more complicated and if you don't use rgb to hsl conversion anywhere else then it probably wouldn't be the most simplistic solution. It would, however, be more accurate than adding to rgb values although I'm not much of a colour person myself. It all depends on how accurate you want to be I guess.

Comment: Whats the loss of accuracy you mention? I assume you mean all [web] colors are not reachable with rgb or something?

Comment: As I said I don't know that much about colour: [wiki Color Theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_theory)

Comment: @Pimp Trizkit: It's less accurate because (and this is just my theory... I'm not a color expert) you're shifting each channel the same amount, no matter how much of that color there was to begin with. I *think* that would result in decreasing the saturation because you're bringing the channels closer to each other (by percentage). Of course, if you overflow/underflow that's unavoidable anyway.

Comment: @matt - Good Point. And Im sure thats true! seems logical. But I think the real question of accuracy was based on using RGB vs HSL (not the function above).  Now, im looking for a way to do the function above but without having to convert to decimal. Straight in hex.

Comment: @pimp I don't think you can get it much better than you have. You are converting string to int do a calculation then convert back to string again. Thats fairly simple, can't think of a significantly faster way and unless you are using it a million times in a row it won't matter a great deal. How often do you use it? also you are just looking for feedback try on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @James - Well, I use it in mouse event calls (move). So I'm trying to keep it as fast as possible. I just thought there might be a pure hex way to do it. I guess I need to research how JavaScript does hex numbers. Still learning here.... lol

Comment: @Pimp http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/The_Complete_Javascript_Number_Reference#quickIDX2 i beleive Javascript handles all numbers as decimals.

Comment: link rot: second link broken

Comment: In addition to being incomplete (if the answer requires two conversion functions then include them) this does not properly accommodate for the times when r, g, or b will be single digit and therefore will return malformed hex codes often.

Comment: @JimboJonny duplicating the other question (which is focused on rgb to hsl) would only confuse readers. This question is about lightening or darkening a colour.  You are correct that it would only return single digits for hex values.

Comment: I personally disagree. This question is about lightening and darkening...but your solution for lightening and darkening includes rgb / hsl conversion and therefore the answer should include that conversion as well. You've already had one link go bad. It is not confusing to make your code actually work on its own without adding code from another question...in fact it's probably less confusing.

Comment: @JimboJonny There are at least 3 other better answers and two of them will cover most people. If the reader is looking for a hsl/rgb conversion they will find the other question first. I would delete this answer if it wasn't referenced in the OP's answer.

Comment: The reader doesn't need to be looking for a hsl/rgb conversion. This answer is what requires it, and this answer is on the subject of this question. There's no need to sit around rationalizing why we shouldn't bother to make the code in this answer actually work when you yourself state you shouldn't delete the answer. If it's important enough to not delete then it's important enough to fix. Edit is in the queue.

Comment: @JimboJonny If you think my answer is not useful the correct response is to downvote.

Comment: ...I've never heard anyone imply that fixing a nonworking/incomplete answer via editing it to be complete and working is a poor way to handle it. In fact that's completely nonsensical.

Answer (score 5):

I wanted to change a color to a **specific** brightness level - no matter what brightness the color was before - here's a simple JS function that seems to work well, although I'm sure it could be shorter

```
function setLightPercentage(col: any, p: number) {
    const R = parseInt(col.substring(1, 3), 16);
    const G = parseInt(col.substring(3, 5), 16);
    const B = parseInt(col.substring(5, 7), 16);
    const curr_total_dark = (255 * 3) - (R + G + B);

    // calculate how much of the current darkness comes from the different channels
    const RR = ((255 - R) / curr_total_dark);
    const GR = ((255 - G) / curr_total_dark);
    const BR = ((255 - B) / curr_total_dark);

    // calculate how much darkness there should be in the new color
    const new_total_dark = ((255 - 255 * (p / 100)) * 3);

    // make the new channels contain the same % of available dark as the old ones did
    const NR = 255 - Math.round(RR * new_total_dark);
    const NG = 255 - Math.round(GR * new_total_dark);
    const NB = 255 - Math.round(BR * new_total_dark);

    const RO = ((NR.toString(16).length === 1) ? "0" + NR.toString(16) : NR.toString(16));
    const GO = ((NG.toString(16).length === 1) ? "0" + NG.toString(16) : NG.toString(16));
    const BO = ((NB.toString(16).length === 1) ? "0" + NB.toString(16) : NB.toString(16));

    return "#" + RO + GO + BO;}
```

Comment: Coolio! I assume that `p` has range `0-100`? I don't even know how to correctly define brightness in RGB, thats an HSL thing. For instance, is `#FF00FF` brighter than `#FF0000`? If so, that would imply that magenta is twice as bright as red. Therefore, the pure red test is used. Pass in pure red `#FF0000`, set to 50% brightness, and here we get `#FF4040`, is that right? I would of guessed to make red 50% brightness, we would be getting darker, seeing that its already fully bright.. as in `#800000` or 150% brightness would be `#FF8080`. Is pink a brighter red? or is red already fully bright?

Comment: You're right - I should have mentioned that p must be in the range 1-100!

Comment: #FF00FF has 255 as value in the red channel, 0 in the green channel and 255 in the blue channel. The higher the combined values in the channels are, the higher the brightness of the color.

The number p states that we want the new color to be 50% as bright as the original color can be. I'm not 100% that #FF4040 is the correct answer to "50% as bright as possible Red".  Producing darker shades (with, in this case, lower value in the red channel) would require modification

Comment: Yes, I was just pointing out the ambiguity in talking about brightness in RGB. If converted to HSL, the `L` channel is literally brightness. My [personal mental] issue here is that, to me, `#FF0000` is fully bright. And `#FF4040` is Lighter but not brighter.... to me lighter means closer to white, like pink is. And brightness is how much its got, and its got full red, so red, is full bright. Therefore, `#FF0000` can't be made brighter.. but rather.. lighter...  maybe I'm just a freak, lol!! I really don't know color theory, sooo, I'm really just talking out my a...

Comment: But I know that when I change the brightness on my monitor, the Reds don't turn pink... to me.  So this is probably where I started my logic.

Answer (score 5):

Your approach is ok :) I simplify your shortest version a little (for saturation control look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54014428/860099))

```
(col,amt)=> (+('0x'+col)+amt*0x010101).toString(16).padStart(6,0)
```

```js
// Similar to OP shortest version, we not have here # and colors range checking

var LightenDarkenColor = 
     (col,amt) => (+('0x'+col)+amt*0x010101).toString(16).padStart(6,0);    




// ------
// TEST
// ------

function update() {
  let c= col.value.padEnd(6,'0').slice(0,6);
  let color = '#'+LightenDarkenColor(c, +amt.value);
  oldColor.innerHTML = 'Old: #'+c;
  oldColor.style = `background: #${c}`;
  newColor.innerHTML = 'New: '+color
  newColor.style = `background: ${color}`;

  
}

update();
```

```css
.box{ width: 100px; height: 100px; margin: 10px; display: inline-block}
```

```html
<input id="col" value="3F6D2A" oninput="update()">
<input id="amt" value="30" oninput="update()"><br>
<div id="oldColor" class="box"></div>
<div id="newColor" class="box"></div>
```

And version with # and color ranges checking

```js
// # and colors range checking

var LightenDarkenColor = 
     (col,amt) => '#'+col.slice(1).match(/../g)
                         .map(x=>(x=+`0x${x}`+amt,x<0?0:(x>255?255:x))
                         .toString(16).padStart(2,0)).join``;




// ------
// TEST
// ------

function update() {
  let c= col.value.padEnd(6,'0').slice(0,7);
  let color = LightenDarkenColor(c, +amt.value);
  oldColor.innerHTML = 'Old: '+c;
  oldColor.style = `background: ${c}`;
  newColor.innerHTML = 'New: '+color
  newColor.style = `background: ${color}`;
}

update();
```

```css
.box{ width: 100px; height: 100px; margin: 10px; display: inline-block}
```

```html
<input id="col" value="#3F6D2A" oninput="update()">
<input id="amt" value="40" oninput="update()"><br>
<div id="oldColor" class="box"></div>
<div id="newColor" class="box"></div>
```

Comment: I really liked the idea of this short and powerful function, but it does not seem to work for all the colors. :/ For instance: #54b946 apply -30, -60, -90, -120, it returns a purple instead of lighter green.

Comment: @antoni I update answer and make more interaction to snippets (but not change main procedure code). In bottom snippet I check your color - and it seems that eveything works ok. If not - can you provide hex number with exact result you expect for #54b946 and -120 ?

Comment: That was my bad @kamil, thanks for your function. Smart and concise. +1 Your tester helped me see the mistake was elsewhere in my code.

Comment: Great answer, simple and very useful!

Answer (score 4):

C# Version...
note that I am getting color strings in this format #FF12AE34, and need to cut out the #FF.

```
    private string GetSmartShadeColorByBase(string s, float percent)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
            return "";
        var r = s.Substring(3, 2);
        int rInt = int.Parse(r, NumberStyles.HexNumber);
        var g = s.Substring(5, 2);
        int gInt = int.Parse(g, NumberStyles.HexNumber);
        var b = s.Substring(7, 2);
        int bInt = int.Parse(b, NumberStyles.HexNumber);

        var t = percent < 0 ? 0 : 255;
        var p = percent < 0 ? percent*-1 : percent;

        int newR = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round((t - rInt) * p) + rInt);
        var newG = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round((t - gInt) * p) + gInt);
        var newB = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round((t - bInt) * p) + bInt);

        return String.Format("#{0:X2}{1:X2}{2:X2}", newR, newG, newB);
    }
```

Comment: Never used C# before, but it looks like the last three variable declarations are wierd. An `int` and two `vars` for the same type of data.

Comment: The var keyword in C# means let the compiler infer the type at compile time. So in the example above int and var define a variable the same type - int. This is useful if you have a long type name, or if you want to reference an anonymous type. It's weird because user1618171 has mixed two variable declaration styles - probably a typo.

Answer (score 3):

I just used the hex number preceded by '#'.

```
var x = 0xf0f0f0;
x=x+0xf00; //set this value as you wish programatically
document.getElementById("heading").style = 'background-color: #'+x.toString(16);
```

higher the number ..lighter the color

Answer (score 2):

I needed it in C#, it may help .net developers

```
public static string LightenDarkenColor(string color, int amount)
    {
        int colorHex = int.Parse(color, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
        string output = (((colorHex & 0x0000FF) + amount) | ((((colorHex >> 0x8) & 0x00FF) + amount) << 0x8) | (((colorHex >> 0xF) + amount) << 0xF)).ToString("x6");
        return output;
    }
```

Comment: You converted the "non working" function that doesn't deal with leading zeros, and can go above FF in the sums, = modify the color component above...

Comment: When I tried the function it didn't work because of non hex values (16 = 0xF) and (8 = 0x8) and gives a color in 8 positions, but now it works very well

Comment: did you try increasing from FF? (say from 0xFFFFFF + 0x000004) : your code rolls over that max value (say to 0x1000003), instead of not increasing, and especially setting the 2 upper color components to 00 which is the biggest change they could do...

Comment: you are right, thank you for the remark, except an input of limits arround fff and 000 it will work fine.

Answer (score 2):

My version written in typescript:

```
function changeColorLightness(color: number, lightness: number): number {
    return (Math.max(0, Math.min(((color & 0xFF0000) / 0x10000) + lightness, 0xFF)) * 0x10000) +
        (Math.max(0, Math.min(((color & 0x00FF00) / 0x100) + lightness, 0xFF)) * 0x100) +
        (Math.max(0, Math.min(((color & 0x0000FF)) + lightness, 0xFF)));
}
```

**explanation:**

```
export function changeColorLightness(color: number, lightness: number): number {
    const r = (color & 0xFF0000) / 0x10**4;
    const g = (color & 0x00FF00) / 0x10**2;
    const b = (color & 0x0000FF);

    const changedR = Math.max(0, Math.min(r + lightness, 0xFF));
    const changedG = Math.max(0, Math.min(g + lightness, 0xFF));
    const changedB = Math.max(0, Math.min(b + lightness, 0xFF));

    return (changedR * 0x10**4) + (changedG * 0x10**2) + changedB;
}
```

**usage:**

```
changeColorLightness(0x00FF00, 0x50);
changeColorLightness(parseInt("#00FF00".replace('#',''), 16), 0x50);
changeColorLightness(0x00FF00, 127.5);
```

Answer (score 1):

The following method will allow you to lighten or darken the exposure value of a Hexadecimal (Hex) color string:

```
private static string GetHexFromRGB(byte r, byte g, byte b, double exposure)
{
    exposure = Math.Max(Math.Min(exposure, 1.0), -1.0);
    if (exposure >= 0)
    {
        return "#"
            + ((byte)(r + ((byte.MaxValue - r) * exposure))).ToString("X2")
            + ((byte)(g + ((byte.MaxValue - g) * exposure))).ToString("X2")
            + ((byte)(b + ((byte.MaxValue - b) * exposure))).ToString("X2");
    }
    else
    {
        return "#"
            + ((byte)(r + (r * exposure))).ToString("X2")
            + ((byte)(g + (g * exposure))).ToString("X2")
            + ((byte)(b + (b * exposure))).ToString("X2");
    }

}
```

For the last parameter value in GetHexFromRGB(), Pass in a double value somewhere between -1 and 1 (-1 is black, 0 is unchanged, 1 is white):

```
// split color (#e04006) into three strings
var r = Convert.ToByte("e0", 16);
var g = Convert.ToByte("40", 16);
var b = Convert.ToByte("06", 16);

GetHexFromRGB(r, g, b, 0.25);  // Lighten by 25%;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is lack of support for colors starting from 00 ie "#000623" but here is the fix

```
function lightenDarkenColor(colorCode, amount) {
 let usePound = false;

 if (colorCode[0] == "#") {
     colorCode = colorCode.slice(1);
     usePound = true;
 }
 const num = parseInt(colorCode, 16);
 let r = (num >> 16) + amount;

 if (r > 255) {
     r = 255;
 } else if (r < 0) {
     r = 0;
 }

 let b = ((num >> 8) & 0x00FF) + amount;

 if (b > 255) {
     b = 255;
 } else if (b < 0) {
     b = 0;
 }

 let g = (num & 0x0000FF) + amount;

 if (g > 255) {
     g = 255;
 } else if (g < 0) {
     g = 0;
 }
 let color = (g | (b << 8) | (r << 16)).toString(16);
 while (color.length < 6){
   color = 0 + color;
 }
 return (usePound ? '#' : '') + color;  
}
```

Comment: This fix should be added here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/lighten-darken-color/

Answer (score 1):

I've rewritten this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/13542669/4537906 into a pair of readable functions in TypeScript.

The reason is that in modern JavaScript we don't need to care about saving characters any more. That is done by the compilers. IMO we should aim for a readable and understandable code.

This is my approach:

### tint.ts

```
type ColorObject = Record<"r" | "g" | "b" | "a", number>;
const singleColorSpace = 16 * 16; // 256
const blueSpace = singleColorSpace;
const greenSpace = blueSpace * singleColorSpace; // 65536
const redSpace = greenSpace * singleColorSpace; // 16777216
/* eslint-disable regex/invalid */
// adapted to TS from https://github.com/PimpTrizkit/PJs/wiki/12.-Shade,-Blend-and-Convert-a-Web-Color-(pSBC.js)
export const toColorObject = (rgbOrHex: string): ColorObject => {
    const { length } = rgbOrHex;
    const outputColor = {} as ColorObject;
    if (length > 9) {
        const rgbaColor = rgbOrHex.split(",");
        const [rgbaAndRed, green, blue, alpha] = rgbaColor;

        if (rgbaAndRed.slice(0, 3) !== "rgb") {
            throw new Error("Invalid color format");
        }
        const red = rgbaAndRed[3] === "a" ? rgbaAndRed.slice(5) : rgbaAndRed.slice(4);

        const rgbaLength = rgbaColor.length;
        if (rgbaLength < 3 || rgbaLength > 4) {
            return null;
        }
        outputColor.r = parseInt(red, 10);
        outputColor.g = parseInt(green, 10);
        outputColor.b = parseInt(blue, 10);
        outputColor.a = alpha ? parseFloat(alpha) : -1;
    } else {
        if (length === 8 || length === 6 || length < 4) {
            throw new Error("Invalid hex color format");
        }
        let HexColor = rgbOrHex;
        if (length < 6) {
            HexColor = `#${rgbOrHex[1]}${rgbOrHex[1]}${rgbOrHex[2]}${rgbOrHex[2]}${rgbOrHex[3]}${rgbOrHex[3]}${
                length > 4 ? rgbOrHex[4] + rgbOrHex[4] : ""
            }`;
        }
        if (length === 9 || length === 5) {
            const hexRed = parseInt(HexColor.slice(1, 3), 16);
            outputColor.r = hexRed;

            const hexGreen = parseInt(HexColor.slice(3, 5), 16);
            outputColor.g = hexGreen;

            const hexBlue = parseInt(HexColor.slice(5, 7), 16);
            outputColor.b = hexBlue;

            const hexAlpha = parseInt(HexColor.slice(7, 9), 16);
            outputColor.a = Math.round((hexAlpha / 255) * 100) / 100;
        } else {
            const hexRed = parseInt(HexColor.slice(1, 3), 16);
            outputColor.r = hexRed;

            const hexGreen = parseInt(HexColor.slice(3, 5), 16);
            outputColor.g = hexGreen;

            const hexBlue = parseInt(HexColor.slice(5, 7), 16);
            outputColor.b = hexBlue;

            outputColor.a = -1;
        }
    }
    return outputColor;
};

const black: ColorObject = { r: 0, g: 0, b: 0, a: -1 };
const white: ColorObject = { r: 255, g: 255, b: 255, a: -1 };
export const tint = (
    ratio: number,
    inputColor: string,
    { toColor, useLinear, reformat }: { toColor?: string; useLinear?: boolean; reformat?: boolean } = {}
) => {
    const { round } = Math;
    const clampedRatio = Math.min(Math.max(ratio, -1), 1);
    if (ratio < -1 || ratio > 1) {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
        console.info(`Ratio should be between -1 and 1 and it is ${ratio}. It will be clamped to ${clampedRatio}`);
    }
    let baseColor = inputColor;
    if (inputColor[0] !== "r" && inputColor[0] !== "#") {
        baseColor = "#000";
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
        console.info(
            `Invalid input color format. "${inputColor}" should be rgb(a) or hex. It will fallback to "${baseColor}"`
        );
    }
    let isRGBformat = baseColor.length > 9 || baseColor.includes("rgb(");
    isRGBformat = reformat ? !isRGBformat : isRGBformat;

    if (toColor) {
        const isToColorRgbFormat = (toColor && toColor?.length > 9) || toColor?.includes("rgb(");
        isRGBformat = reformat ? !isToColorRgbFormat : isToColorRgbFormat;
    }
    const formattedBaseColor = toColorObject(baseColor);
    const isNegativeRatio = clampedRatio < 0;
    const toColorDefault = isNegativeRatio ? black : white;
    const formattedToColor = toColor && !reformat ? toColorObject(toColor) : toColorDefault;
    const toColorRatio = Math.abs(clampedRatio);
    const baseRatio = 1 - toColorRatio;

    const outputColor = {} as ColorObject;
    if (useLinear) {
        outputColor.r = round(baseRatio * formattedBaseColor.r + toColorRatio * formattedToColor.r);
        outputColor.g = round(baseRatio * formattedBaseColor.g + toColorRatio * formattedToColor.g);
        outputColor.b = round(baseRatio * formattedBaseColor.b + toColorRatio * formattedToColor.b);
    } else {
        outputColor.r = round((baseRatio * formattedBaseColor.r ** 2 + toColorRatio * formattedToColor.r ** 2) ** 0.5);
        outputColor.g = round((baseRatio * formattedBaseColor.g ** 2 + toColorRatio * formattedToColor.g ** 2) ** 0.5);
        outputColor.b = round((baseRatio * formattedBaseColor.b ** 2 + toColorRatio * formattedToColor.b ** 2) ** 0.5);
    }

    const blendedAlpha = formattedBaseColor.a * baseRatio + formattedToColor.a * toColorRatio;

    outputColor.a = formattedToColor.a < 0 ? formattedBaseColor.a : blendedAlpha;

    const hasAlpha = formattedBaseColor.a >= 0 || formattedToColor.a >= 0;
    if (isRGBformat) {
        return `rgb${hasAlpha ? "a" : ""}(${outputColor.r},${outputColor.g},${outputColor.b}${
            hasAlpha ? `,${round(outputColor.a * 1000) / 1000}` : ""
        })`;
    }
    return `#${(
        outputColor.r * redSpace +
        outputColor.g * greenSpace +
        outputColor.b * blueSpace +
        (hasAlpha ? round(outputColor.a * 255) : 0)
    )
        .toString(16)
        // If no Alpha, we remove the last 2 hex digits
        .slice(0, hasAlpha ? undefined : -2)}`;
};
```

And also a collection of jest tests

### tint.test.ts

```
import { tint, toColorObject } from "./tint";

const rgbBlue = "rgb(20,60,200)";
const rgbaBlue = "rgba(20,60,200,0.67423)";
const hex6Cyan = "#67DAF0";
const hex3Pink = "#F3A";
const hex4Pink = "#F3A9";
const rbgBrown = "rgb(200,60,20)";
const rgbaBrown = "rgba(200,60,20,0.98631)";

describe("tint", () => {
    describe("Logarithmic blending", () => {
        describe("Shades", () => {
            it("lightens rgb color", () => {
                expect(tint(0.42, rgbBlue)).toEqual("rgb(166,171,225)");
            });
            it("darkens hex color", () => {
                expect(tint(-0.4, hex3Pink)).toEqual("#c62884");
            });
            it("lightens rgba color", () => {
                expect(tint(0.42, rgbaBrown)).toEqual("rgba(225,171,166,0.986)");
            });
            it("returns black with ratio -1", () => {
                expect(tint(-1, rgbBlue)).toEqual("rgb(0,0,0)");
            });
        });
        describe("converts color notation", () => {
            it("converts from rgba to hexa", () => {
                // expect(tint(0.42, color2, "c")).toEqual("#a6abe1ac");
                expect(tint(0.42, rgbaBlue, { reformat: true })).toEqual("#a6abe1ac");
            });
            it("converts from hexa to rgba", () => {
                // expect(tint(0, color6, "c", true)).toEqual("rgba(255,51,170,0.6)");
                expect(tint(0, hex4Pink, { reformat: true })).toEqual("rgba(255,51,170,0.6)");
            });
            it("converts and returns white with ratio 1", () => {
                expect(tint(1, hex3Pink, { reformat: true })).toEqual("rgb(255,255,255)");
            });
        });
        describe("Blends two colors", () => {
            it("blends rgba with rgba", () => {
                expect(tint(-0.5, rgbaBlue, { toColor: rgbaBrown })).toEqual("rgba(142,60,142,0.83)");
            });
            it("blends rgba with rgb", () => {
                expect(tint(0.7, rgbaBlue, { toColor: rbgBrown })).toEqual("rgba(168,60,111,0.674)");
            });
            it("blends hex with rgb", () => {
                expect(tint(0.25, hex6Cyan, { toColor: rbgBrown })).toEqual("rgb(134,191,208)");
            });
            it("blends rgb with hex", () => {
                expect(tint(0.75, rbgBrown, { toColor: hex6Cyan })).toEqual("#86bfd0");
            });
        });
    });
    describe("Linear Blending", () => {
        describe("Shades", () => {
            it("lightens rgb color", () => {
                expect(tint(0.42, rgbBlue, { useLinear: true })).toEqual("rgb(119,142,223)");
            });
            it("darkens hex color", () => {
                expect(tint(-0.4, hex3Pink, { useLinear: true })).toEqual("#991f66");
            });
            it("lightens rgba color", () => {
                expect(tint(0.42, rgbaBrown, { useLinear: true })).toEqual("rgba(223,142,119,0.986)");
            });
            it("returns black with ratio -1", () => {
                expect(tint(-1, rgbBlue, { useLinear: true })).toEqual("rgb(0,0,0)");
            });
        });
        describe("converts color notation", () => {
            it("converts from rgba to hexa", () => {
                expect(tint(0.42, rgbaBlue, { reformat: true, useLinear: true })).toEqual("#778edfac");
            });
            it("converts from hexa to rgba", () => {
                expect(tint(0, hex4Pink, { reformat: true, useLinear: true })).toEqual("rgba(255,51,170,0.6)");
            });
            it("converts and returns white with ratio 1", () => {
                expect(tint(1, hex3Pink, { useLinear: true, reformat: true })).toEqual("rgb(255,255,255)");
            });
        });
        describe("Blends two colors", () => {
            it("blends rgba with rgba", () => {
                expect(tint(-0.5, rgbaBlue, { toColor: rgbaBrown, useLinear: true })).toEqual("rgba(110,60,110,0.83)");
            });
            it("blends rgba with rgb", () => {
                expect(tint(0.7, rgbaBlue, { toColor: rbgBrown, useLinear: true })).toEqual("rgba(146,60,74,0.674)");
            });
            it("blends hex with rgb", () => {
                expect(tint(0.25, hex6Cyan, { toColor: rbgBrown, useLinear: true })).toEqual("rgb(127,179,185)");
            });
            it("blends rgb with hex", () => {
                expect(tint(0.75, rbgBrown, { toColor: hex6Cyan, useLinear: true })).toEqual("#7fb3b9");
            });
        });
    });
    describe("Error handling", () => {
        describe("When invalid hex color provided", () => {
            it.each([1, 2, 5])("throws error if hex color has %s characters", (n) => {
                const correlativeNumbers = Array.from(Array(n).keys()).join("");
                expect(() => tint(0, `#${correlativeNumbers}`)).toThrow("Invalid hex color format");
            });
        });

        describe("When ratio is not between -1 and 1", () => {
            it("clamps ratio to -1", () => {
                expect(tint(-43, rgbBlue)).toEqual("rgb(0,0,0)");
            });
            it("clamps ratio to 1", () => {
                expect(tint(42, rgbBlue)).toEqual("rgb(255,255,255)");
            });
        });
    });
});

describe("toColorObject function", () => {
    it("should return a color object from hex", () => {
        expect(toColorObject("#fff")).toEqual({
            r: 255,
            g: 255,
            b: 255,
            a: -1,
        });
    });
    it("should return a color object from hex with alpha", () => {
        expect(toColorObject("#fff6")).toEqual({
            r: 255,
            g: 255,
            b: 255,
            a: 0.4,
        });
    });
    it("should return a color object from rgb", () => {
        expect(toColorObject("rgb(255,255,255)")).toEqual({
            r: 255,
            g: 255,
            b: 255,
            a: -1,
        });
    });
    it("should return a color object from rgba", () => {
        expect(toColorObject("rgba(255,255,255,1)")).toEqual({
            r: 255,
            g: 255,
            b: 255,
            a: 1,
        });
    });
    describe("Error handling", () => {
        it("should throw error if invalid color provided", () => {
            expect(() => toColorObject("foo")).toThrow("Invalid hex color format");
        });
        it("should throw error if invalid color provided", () => {
            expect(() => toColorObject("invalid color")).toThrow("Invalid color format");
        });
    });
});
```

I hope you enjoy it. It's very simple but it works pretty fine

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, JS is a scripting language.. not a compiled one, right?. Also, isn't that "compiler" actually on the user end? Therefore, those "extra characters" are indeed sent across the line, increasing the size of the download. Also, looking at your answer, it appears quite a bit larger and much slower than needed.  My OP was really based originally on trying to get as much speed as possible (for animations) for the small particular environment I was using when I started this question. Therefore, this stackoverflow question was supposed to be speed minded first, size second.

Comment: I have not used TypeScript. Does it do a (pre) 'compile" on the script *before* it gets published on the webserver for end user downloading?

Comment: TypeScript is a superset of JavaScript. Nowadays it can't be executed directly in any browser. It needs to be compiled to JS anyway. In that step, there is plenty of tools that can compress and uglify code. We don't need to do that manually. Once it's compiled to the "dist" version, it can be minified, comments removed... etc. IMHO it makes no sense to write "compressed code" any more. Moreover, gzip also compresses code when travelling the network

Comment: @PimpTrizkit checkout this great tool https://esbuild.github.io/getting-started/#bundling-for-the-browser. It can be minified in one step: `./node_modules/.bin/esbuild tint.ts --bundle --minify --outfile=tint.js`

Answer (score 0):

I made a port of the excellent xcolor library to remove its jQuery dependency. There are a ton of functions in there including lightening and darkening colors.

Really, converting hex to RGB is a completely separate function from lightening or darkening colors. Keep things DRY please. In any case, once you have an RGB color, you can just add the difference between the light level you want and the light level you have to each of the RGB values:

```
var lightness = function(level) {
    if(level === undefined) {
        return Math.max(this.g,this.r,this.b)
    } else {
        var roundedLevel = Math.round(level) // fractions won't work here
        var levelChange = roundedLevel - this.lightness()

        var r = Math.max(0,this.r+levelChange)
        var g = Math.max(0,this.g+levelChange)
        var b = Math.max(0,this.b+levelChange)

        if(r > 0xff) r = 0xff
        if(g > 0xff) g = 0xff
        if(b > 0xff) b = 0xff

        return xolor({r: r, g: g, b: b})
    }
}

var lighter = function(amount) {
    return this.lightness(this.lightness()+amount)
}
```

See https://github.com/fresheneesz/xolor for more of the source.

Comment: I haven't yet analyzed the code as it pertains to my OP (speed/size/accuracy). But at first read there are some comments to be made:1) I agree that converting hex to RGB can be seen as a completely separate function.. IF my problem was intended to be solved with a dry function, which was not a requirement. The intention here was to have an answer (see my Version 2) that was super fast and super tiny (2 lines!) and one that lightened and darkened a hex color... specifically... as a stand-alone self-contained function. So that, in its final usage, it will be a simple single function call.<cont.>

Comment: 2) And the case with Version 3, by popular demand, is the intention to have a completely stand-alone self-contained universal function, as fast and as small as possible, that can blindly take a hex or RGB color and in all their variations. Hence, a conversion of hex to RGB is needed.
<cont.>

Comment: 3) Upon simple analysis of the code. It does appear that it would run much slower and it is obviously much larger than my Version 2 (which is the real answer to my OP; version 3 was for the masses). To be fair, I should compare this code with my RGB Version 2 which does not do a conversion and seems to answer your point about dryness. And truthfully speaking, your port is not much more simple to understand than my 2 liner for hex. So, while its dryer, its not actually that much, if any, simpler.  (the dryness didn't help much for understand-ability) <cont.>

Comment: 4) My RGB Version 2 is a no conversion 2 line function if you want that. My particular solution for my original OP wanted hex. That's why there are two different types of Version 2.  But you mention the point about dryness and hex conversions so we are now really focusing on version 3.  Version 3 came much later; only after Version 2 was popular. <cont.>

Comment: 5) While I will agree that dryness generally helps for universality. And in most cases, for understand-ability. Unfortunately its at a cost in this example. These costs are that its much larger and seemingly much slower and seemingly uses more memory both on the stack (with its recursive-like nature) and in global (2 functions; as compared to v2).

Comment: 6) Since the solution to universality can be easily impeded internally. My intention was to remove those costs and cover the universality internally. Which decreased the overall code length and processing time of the whole operation while still basically covering all the bases. Allowing for simple one function call usage for either hex or RGB, blindly.

Comment: @PimpTrizkit I disagree that `lightness` would run slower than `shadeRGBcolor`, and its not significantly longer either. Your `shadeRGBcolor` function is nearly unreadable and is only "shorter" because you've removed almost any whitespace that would make it marginally readable and all your variable names are cryptic single characters. It sounds like we had different goals in writing this stuff. I rely on uglify to make my code small. I honestly have no idea why you think my code here is "recursive-like" or that this would use a significant amount of memory.

Answer (score 0):

I've long wanted to be able to produce tints/shades of colours, here is my JavaScript solution:

```
const varyHue = function (hueIn, pcIn) {
    const truncate = function (valIn) {
        if (valIn > 255) {
            valIn = 255;
        } else if (valIn < 0)  {
            valIn = 0;
        }
        return valIn;
    };

    let red   = parseInt(hueIn.substring(0, 2), 16);
    let green = parseInt(hueIn.substring(2, 4), 16);
    let blue  = parseInt(hueIn.substring(4, 6), 16);
    let pc    = parseInt(pcIn, 10);    //shade positive, tint negative
    let max   = 0;
    let dif   = 0;

    max = red;

    if (pc < 0) {    //tint: make lighter
        if (green < max) {
            max = green;
        }

        if (blue < max) {
            max = blue;
        }

        dif = parseInt(((Math.abs(pc) / 100) * (255 - max)), 10);

        return leftPad(((truncate(red + dif)).toString(16)), '0', 2)  + leftPad(((truncate(green + dif)).toString(16)), '0', 2) + leftPad(((truncate(blue + dif)).toString(16)), '0', 2);
    } else {    //shade: make darker
        if (green > max) {
            max = green;
        }

        if (blue > max) {
            max = blue;
        }

        dif = parseInt(((pc / 100) * max), 10);

        return leftPad(((truncate(red - dif)).toString(16)), '0', 2)  + leftPad(((truncate(green - dif)).toString(16)), '0', 2) + leftPad(((truncate(blue - dif)).toString(16)), '0', 2);
    }
};
```

Comment: Some usage examples would help. And maybe some explanation as to why this version over the others. This version seems to run considerably slower. And its much longer. And it doesn't seem to shade accurately. It looks like your using LERP, or something similar..which is good. Unfortunately, its only from one channel, then that same value is used across all channels. This is not right, in order to get higher accuracy, you should LERP each channel individually. As my answer to this question does. Plus its smaller and faster and checks for errors and handles rgb, and does conversions,I could go on

Comment: A usage example:

    varyHue("6e124c", 77) 

where the first argument is the colour in hex and the second the percentage change. A positive percentage change shades (darkens) whilst a negative value tints (lightens) the result. 

I wrote the routine as my first attempt just a few hours before I came upon this page and posted it simply as a matter of interest. I was not aware that I had to better your effort or that I required your approval before doing so. Its entirely my own work without reference to anybody else. 

I've not heard of LERP I'll check it out, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Hehe, well, of course you don't have to do anything! And we all thank you for your efforts! My first main concerns were the ones listed first. Trying to help you with your answer so that it might get votes. (show usages, and explanation of how it works, etc)  The other stuff is obviously a quick analysis to help further *everyone's* knowledge. Sorry, if it seemed a bit aggressive. But another suggestion is to make it accept the `#` of hex colors. Sorry if it seemed like.. "approval"... I saw it as peer review. If you don't want someone to analysis your code, or offer feedback, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

thank all for all good answer and edits, they help me to I develop this helpful solution, as I think.

```js
/**
 * @param color Hex value format: #ffffff or ffffff or fff or ffffff00 with opacity or rgb rgba formats
 * @param decimal lighten or darken decimal value, example -0.5 to darken by 50% or 0.5 to lighten by 50%.
 */
function shadeColor(color, decimal){
    if(typeof color!=="string" || !color)return color;
    if(typeof decimal !== "number" || !decimal)return color;
    var r,g,b;
    var _format="";
    color=color.trim();
    if(/^rgba?\((\s*[0-9]{1,3}\s*)(,\s*[0-9]{1,3}\s*){2}(,\s*[0-9](\.[0-9]+)?\s*)?\)$/i.test(color)){
        color=color.replace(/[a-z)(\s]+/ig,'').split(/,/)
            .map(function (c,i) { return ((i===3)?c:parseInt(c)); });
        _format="rgb";
        if(color.length===4) {
            _format += "a(VAL," + color[3]+")";
            color.pop();
        }else _format+="(VAL)";
    }else if(/^#?([a-f0-9]{3}|[a-f0-9]{6}|[a-f0-9]{8})$/i.test(color)){
        var group=color.length>5?2:1;
        color=color.replace("#","")
            .split(new RegExp("([a-f0-9]{"+group.toString()+"})",'i'))
            .filter(function(c){return c.length===group;})
            .map(function (c,i) { if(group===1)c+=c;return ((i===3)?c:parseInt(c,16)); });
        _format="#VAL";
        if(color.length===4) {
            _format += color[3];
            color.pop();
        }
    }else return color;
    if(decimal<=1 && decimal>=-1)decimal*=100;
    color=color.reduce(function (_c,c) {
        c=Math.round(c * (100 + decimal) / 100);
        c= (c < 255)? c : 255;
        if(/^#/.test(_format)){
            c=c.toString(16);
            if(c.length === 1)c="0"+c;
            return _c+c;
        }
        if(_c==="")return c;
        return _c+","+c;
    },"");
    return _format.replace("VAL",color);
}
```

You Can Use to dark or light, example:

```js
//lighten
shadeColor("#abcdef",0.5);
shadeColor("#abcdef",0.3);
shadeColor("#abcdef",50);
shadeColor("#abcdef",30);

//it's work with all color format supported in css3 and transparent future

//for example transparnet
shadeColor("#abc8",0.5);
shadeColor("#abcdefff",0.5);
shadeColor("#abcf",35);

//for example rgb and rgba
shadeColor("rgb(128,33,244)",0.5);
shadeColor("rgba(128,33,244,0.3)",0.5);

//darken like above except the decimal with negative number (less than 0)
shadeColor("#abcdef",-0.5);
shadeColor("#abcdef",-50);
shadeColor("rgb(128,33,244)",-35);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple version using `tinycolor2` library.

```html
<script type='module'>
import Color from "https://esm.sh/tinycolor2";

const usingHsl = ({ value, modify }) => {

console.log('base color:', value);
  let { h, s, l } = Color(value).toHsl();

  const baseLightness = parseFloat(parseFloat(l).toFixed(2));
  const percentage = parseFloat(modify?.value);
  let newL = 0;
  if (modify?.type === "lighten") {
    newL = Math.min(baseLightness + (1 - baseLightness) * percentage, 100);
  }
  if (modify?.type === "darken") {
    newL = Math.max(baseLightness - baseLightness * percentage, 0);
  }

  return Color({
    h,
    s,
    l: parseFloat(parseFloat(newL).toFixed(2)),
  }).toHexString();

};



const darkened = usingHsl({
    value: 'red', //can be hex, rgb or any valid color value
    modify: {
        value: 0.2, // value should be between 0-1
        type: 'darken' // or lighten
    },
 })

console.log('darkened', darkened);
const lightened = usingHsl({
    value: 'red', //can be hex, rgb or any valid color value
    modify: {
        value: 0.2, // value should be between 0-1
        type: 'lighten' // or lighten
    },
 })

console.log('lightened', lightened)
</script>
```

Example, here is the Calculation
For lighten
baseLightness = 0.4
Lighten by 0.2

then new lightened values will be:
`0.4 + (1 - 0.4) * 0.2` => if this value is greater than 1, then we take 1 as new lightness - which is white

For darken,
baseLightness = 0.4
darken by 0.2
`0.4 - (0.4 * 0.2)` => if this value is less than 0, then we take 0 as new lightness - which is black

Answer (score 0):

I started using [Soldeplata Saketos' proposal for TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73660199/953937), but I ran into some error cases, for example, when lowering the ink (darken) to -0.9, it generated hexadecimal codes of only 5 characters.

I have a comparison between some results obtained with pSBC.js, with Soldeplata's solution (thanks for that) and another with some small modifications.

I show some differences:

| Colour | Change | PSBC | Soldeplata | New Proposal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| #C86A6E | -10 | #ce8184 | #ce8184 | #ce8184 |
| #292B3F | +50 | #1d1e2d | #1d1e2d | #1d1e2d |
| #292B3F | +90 | #0d0e14 | **#d0e1 4** | #0d0e14 |

Here is updated version, repeat... based on Soldepalta Saketos original code:

```
interface ConfigTheme {
        primaryColor: string;
        textColor: string;
        contrastColor: string;
        bodyBackgroundColor: string;
        linksColor: string;
        headerBackgroundColor: string;
        headerIconColor: string;
        headerTextColor: string;
        titlesColor: string;
        sectionBackgroundColor: string;
    }


    type ColorObject = Record<"r" | "g" | "b" | "a", number>;
    
    const toColorObject = (rgbOrHex: string): ColorObject => {
        const { length } = rgbOrHex;
        const outputColor = {} as ColorObject;
        if (length > 9) {
            const rgbaColor = rgbOrHex.split(",");
            const [rgbaAndRed, green, blue, alpha] = rgbaColor;

            if (rgbaAndRed.slice(0, 3) !== "rgb") {
                throw new Error("Invalid color format");
            }
            const red = rgbaAndRed[3] === "a" ? rgbaAndRed.slice(5) : rgbaAndRed.slice(4);

            outputColor.r = parseInt(red, 10);
            outputColor.g = parseInt(green, 10);
            outputColor.b = parseInt(blue, 10);
            outputColor.a = alpha ? parseFloat(alpha) : -1;
        } else {
            if (length === 8 || length === 6 || length < 4) {
                throw new Error("Invalid hex color format");
            }
            let HexColor = rgbOrHex;
            if (length < 6) {
                HexColor = `#${rgbOrHex[1]}${rgbOrHex[1]}${rgbOrHex[2]}${rgbOrHex[2]}${rgbOrHex[3]}${rgbOrHex[3]}${
                    length > 4 ? rgbOrHex[4] + rgbOrHex[4] : ""
                }`;
            }
            if (length === 9 || length === 5) {
                const hexRed = parseInt(HexColor.slice(1, 3), 16);
                outputColor.r = hexRed;

                const hexGreen = parseInt(HexColor.slice(3, 5), 16);
                outputColor.g = hexGreen;

                const hexBlue = parseInt(HexColor.slice(5, 7), 16);
                outputColor.b = hexBlue;

                const hexAlpha = parseInt(HexColor.slice(7, 9), 16);
                outputColor.a = Math.round((hexAlpha / 255) * 100) / 100;
            } else {
                const hexRed = parseInt(HexColor.slice(1, 3), 16);
                outputColor.r = hexRed;

                const hexGreen = parseInt(HexColor.slice(3, 5), 16);
                outputColor.g = hexGreen;

                const hexBlue = parseInt(HexColor.slice(5, 7), 16);
                outputColor.b = hexBlue;

                outputColor.a = -1;
            }
        }
        return outputColor;
    };

    const black: ColorObject = { r: 0, g: 0, b: 0, a: -1 };
    const white: ColorObject = { r: 255, g: 255, b: 255, a: -1 };
    const toHex = (value: number): string => {
        const hex = Math.max(0, Math.min(255, Math.round(value))).toString(16);
        return hex.length < 2 ? '0' + hex : hex;
    }

    const tint = (
        ratio: number,
        inputColor: string,
        { toColor, useLinear, reformat }: { toColor?: string; useLinear?: boolean; reformat?: boolean } = {}
    ) => {
        const { round } = Math;
        const clampedRatio = Math.min(Math.max(ratio, -1), 1);
        let baseColor = inputColor;
        if (inputColor[0] !== "r" && inputColor[0] !== "#") {
            baseColor = "#000";
        }
        let isRGBformat = baseColor.length > 9 || baseColor.includes("rgb(");
        isRGBformat = reformat ? !isRGBformat : isRGBformat;

        if (toColor) {
            const isToColorRgbFormat = (toColor && toColor?.length > 9) || toColor?.includes("rgb(");
            isRGBformat = reformat ? !isToColorRgbFormat : isToColorRgbFormat;
        }
        const formattedBaseColor = toColorObject(baseColor);
        const isNegativeRatio = clampedRatio < 0;
        const toColorDefault = isNegativeRatio ? black : white;
        const formattedToColor = toColor && !reformat ? toColorObject(toColor) : toColorDefault;
        const toColorRatio = Math.abs(clampedRatio);
        const baseRatio = 1 - toColorRatio;

        const outputColor = {} as ColorObject;
        if (useLinear) {
            outputColor.r = round(baseRatio * formattedBaseColor.r + toColorRatio * formattedToColor.r);
            outputColor.g = round(baseRatio * formattedBaseColor.g + toColorRatio * formattedToColor.g);
            outputColor.b = round(baseRatio * formattedBaseColor.b + toColorRatio * formattedToColor.b);
        } else {
            outputColor.r = round((baseRatio * formattedBaseColor.r ** 2 + toColorRatio * formattedToColor.r ** 2) ** 0.5);
            outputColor.g = round((baseRatio * formattedBaseColor.g ** 2 + toColorRatio * formattedToColor.g ** 2) ** 0.5);
            outputColor.b = round((baseRatio * formattedBaseColor.b ** 2 + toColorRatio * formattedToColor.b ** 2) ** 0.5);
        }

        const blendedAlpha = formattedBaseColor.a * baseRatio + formattedToColor.a * toColorRatio;
        outputColor.a = formattedToColor.a < 0 ? formattedBaseColor.a : blendedAlpha;

        const hasAlpha = formattedBaseColor.a >= 0 || formattedToColor.a >= 0;
        if (isRGBformat) {
            return `rgb${hasAlpha ? "a" : ""}(${outputColor.r},${outputColor.g},${outputColor.b}${
                hasAlpha ? `,${round(outputColor.a * 1000) / 1000}` : ""
            })`;
        }

        return `#${toHex(outputColor.r)}${toHex(outputColor.g)}${toHex(outputColor.b)}`;
    };
```

the usage is simple, example:

```
const color1 = '#C86A6E';
const color2 = '#292B3F';

const newColor1 = tint(-0.3, color1); // #a7595c
const newColor2 = tint(+0.10, color2); // #27293c
```

I hope this can help someone who, like me, is struggling with color modifications with JavaScript.

Answer (score -1):

How to simple shade color in PHP?

```
<?php
function shadeColor ($color='#cccccc', $percent=-25) {

  $color = Str_Replace("#",Null,$color);

  $r = Hexdec(Substr($color,0,2));
  $g = Hexdec(Substr($color,2,2));
  $b = Hexdec(Substr($color,4,2));

  $r = (Int)($r*(100+$percent)/100);
  $g = (Int)($g*(100+$percent)/100);
  $b = (Int)($b*(100+$percent)/100);

  $r = Trim(Dechex(($r<255)?$r:255));  
  $g = Trim(Dechex(($g<255)?$g:255));  
  $b = Trim(Dechex(($b<255)?$b:255));

  $r = ((Strlen($r)==1)?"0{$r}":$r);
  $g = ((Strlen($g)==1)?"0{$g}":$g);
  $b = ((Strlen($b)==1)?"0{$b}":$b);

  return (String)("#{$r}{$g}{$b}");
}

echo shadeColor(); // #999999
```

Comment: This is a php version of Pablo's answer. Unfortunately, its longer and slower than the final solution and it does not lighten colors accurately. It does darken them accurately tho. Test with pure red (#FF0000), a lighten of 25% should be (#FF4040). Check out the end of my answer for Kevin M's PHP version of the final solution v2.