# Calculate color HEX having 2 colors and percent/position

Tags: javascript, jquery, colors, gradient

Is it possible to calculate a color in a middle of a gradient?

```
var color1 = 'FF0000';
var color2 = '00FF00';

// 50% between the two colors, should return '808000'
var middle = gradient(color1, color2, 0.5);
```

I only have two hex strings, and I want one in return.

Comment: It's a simple linear algebra problem (and you already know that since you've got the answer for your example colors).  What have you coded up so far?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programmatically Lighten or Darken a hex color (or rgb, and blend colors)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5560248/programmatically-lighten-or-darken-a-hex-color-or-rgb-and-blend-colors)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

This should work:

It basically involves converting them to decimal, finding the halves, converting the results back to hex and then concatenating them.

```
var color1 = 'FF0000';
var color2 = '00FF00';
var ratio = 0.5;
var hex = function(x) {
    x = x.toString(16);
    return (x.length == 1) ? '0' + x : x;
};

var r = Math.ceil(parseInt(color1.substring(0,2), 16) * ratio + parseInt(color2.substring(0,2), 16) * (1-ratio));
var g = Math.ceil(parseInt(color1.substring(2,4), 16) * ratio + parseInt(color2.substring(2,4), 16) * (1-ratio));
var b = Math.ceil(parseInt(color1.substring(4,6), 16) * ratio + parseInt(color2.substring(4,6), 16) * (1-ratio));

var middle = hex(r) + hex(g) + hex(b);
```

Comment: note the third argument -> `0.5` which is the ratio of `color1` and `color2`

Comment: Well this is indeed close, but if ratio is 0 then the color is black, whereas it should be color1. Moreover, the r.toString etc. wont pad with zeros, will they?

Comment: var r1 = parseInt(color1.substring(0,1), 16),
    r2 = parseInt(color2.substring(0,1), 16);

  var r = Math.ceil(r1 + (r2-r1)*ratio); ??

Comment: Even if its not padded with zeros, it wont be a problem, for example if you are using it as a color. #888 and #080808 are exactly the same.

Comment: `#abc` is `#aabbcc`; next, `#8FFFF` is not valid I guess (which is the case if not all of r,g,b are either 1 or 2 digits)

Comment: The substring is wrong, the parameters are : (0, 2) - (2, 4) - (4, 6)

Comment: the hex function return should be : return (x.length == 1) ? x + x : x;

Comment: color1 and color2 are reversed.

Comment: Since this uses Math.ceil certain ratios can break it: `var color1 = 'FFFFFF'; var color2 = 'FF0000'; var ratio = 0.2666666666666669;` results in middle being '1004545' because it tries to convert 256 to hex

Answer (score 7):

An ES6 version with comprehensions:

```js
function interpolateColor(c0, c1, f){
    c0 = c0.match(/.{1,2}/g).map((oct)=>parseInt(oct, 16) * (1-f))
    c1 = c1.match(/.{1,2}/g).map((oct)=>parseInt(oct, 16) * f)
    let ci = [0,1,2].map(i => Math.min(Math.round(c0[i]+c1[i]), 255))
    return ci.reduce((a,v) => ((a << 8) + v), 0).toString(16).padStart(6, "0")
}
```

As in the accepted answer, `c0`,`c1` are color codes (without the leading `#`) and `f` is "progress" between the two values.  (At `f=0` this ends up returning `c0`, at `f=1` this returns `c1`).

- The first two lines convert the color codes into arrays of scaled integers
- The third line:

  - "zips" the two integer arrays
  - sums the corresponding values
  - rounds the sum and clamps it to 0-255
- The fourth line:

  - converts the integer array into a single integer (reduce and bitshifting)
  - converts the integer into its hexadecimal string form
  - ensures the resulting string is 6 characters long and returns it

Answer (score 4):

I found out that in the Javascript substring method the to parameter index is not included in the returned string. That means:

```
var string = "test";
//index:      0123
alert(string.substring(1,3));

//will alert es and NOT est
```

So it should be:

```
parseInt(color1.substring(0,2), 16);
parseInt(color1.substring(2,4), 16);
```

and

```
parseInt(color1.substring(4,6), 16);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this ready function (ES6):

```
const calculateMiddleColor = ({
  color1 = 'FF0000',
  color2 = '00FF00',
  ratio,
}) => {
  const hex = (color) => {
    const colorString = color.toString(16);
    return colorString.length === 1 ? `0${colorString}` : colorString;
  };

  const r = Math.ceil(
    parseInt(color2.substring(0, 2), 16) * ratio
      + parseInt(color1.substring(0, 2), 16) * (1 - ratio),
  );
  const g = Math.ceil(
    parseInt(color2.substring(2, 4), 16) * ratio
      + parseInt(color1.substring(2, 4), 16) * (1 - ratio),
  );
  const b = Math.ceil(
    parseInt(color2.substring(4, 6), 16) * ratio
      + parseInt(color1.substring(4, 6), 16) * (1 - ratio),
  );

  return hex(r) + hex(g) + hex(b);
};
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
console.log(calculateMiddleColor({ ratio: 0 / 5 })); // ff0000
console.log(calculateMiddleColor({ ratio: 5 / 5 })); // 00ff00
console.log(calculateMiddleColor({ ratio: 2.5 / 5 })); // 808000
console.log(calculateMiddleColor({ ratio: 4.2 / 5 })); // 29d700
```