# CSS percentage of transition (for progress bar)

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions

I'm trying to make a "progress bar" with animation that changes the background colour of the bar.

The bar should start with red at 0% and as it progresses across the element it changes to green at 100%. I've got this working for 100% (and no, the colour is not great, but that's a future problem)...

```js
setTimeout(function(){
  var bar = document.getElementById("bar");
  bar.style.width = "100%";
  bar.classList.add("show");
},10);
```

```css
#progress {
  border:1px solid #888;
  background-color:#eee;
  height:
  width:100%;
}
#bar {
  height:30px;
  background-color:red;
  width:0;
  transition: all ease 1s;
}
#bar.show {
  background-color:lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div id="progress"><div id="bar"></div></div>
```

The problem is that (for example) at 50% I cannot get the bar to "stop" at the 50% transition state between the red and the green.

**Is there a way to either calculate the colour as it would be at 50% or get CSS to stop the transition at a particular point?**

You can see what happens if I have a 50% value... where it still goes all the way to green but stops at the 50% width, but what I want it to do is stop at the 50% transition colour (i.e. going from red to mid-way between red and green)...

```js
setTimeout(function(){
  var bar = document.getElementById("bar");
  bar.style.width = "50%";
  bar.classList.add("show");
},10);
```

```css
#progress {
  border:1px solid #888;
  background-color:#eee;
  height:
  width:100%;
}
#bar {
  height:30px;
  background-color:red;
  width:0;
  transition: all ease 1s;
}
#bar.show {
  background-color:lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div id="progress"><div id="bar"></div></div>
```

**Additional Info** (as requested by `0stone0`) the percentage value will not be known at the time the page is loaded, but will be provided via an AJAX call.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get color value from gradient by percentage with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30143082/how-to-get-color-value-from-gradient-by-percentage-with-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Stopping' a gradient transition could be quite difficult.

Please consider an alternative approach, one where you manually calculate the desired final color. Use this color value as the target for the `transition`. This way there's no need to 'stop' the transition, since the final colour is already proportional to the percentage.

I've used [this function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16360533/calculate-color-hex-having-2-colors-and-percent-position) to calculate the gradient between green and red, based on the percentage.

To ensure the bar is always clickable, we've moved the `onClick` to the `.progress` div so we can render the `.bar` at 0 width.

(Updated answer, based on comments)

```js
function load(progress, perc) {
  var bar = progress.getElementsByClassName("bar")[0];
  bar.style.width = perc.toString() + "%";
  bar.style.backgroundColor = getGradient(perc / 100);
}

function getGradient(ratio) {
  var color1 = '90ee90'; // lightgreen
  var color2 = 'FF0000'; // red
  var hex = function(x) {
    x = x.toString(16);
    return (x.length == 1) ? '0' + x : x;
  };

  var r = Math.ceil(parseInt(color1.substring(0,2), 16) * ratio + parseInt(color2.substring(0,2), 16) * (1-ratio));
  var g = Math.ceil(parseInt(color1.substring(2,4), 16) * ratio + parseInt(color2.substring(2,4), 16) * (1-ratio));
  var b = Math.ceil(parseInt(color1.substring(4,6), 16) * ratio + parseInt(color2.substring(4,6), 16) * (1-ratio));
  return '#' + hex(r) + hex(g) + hex(b);
}
```

```css
.progress {
  border:1px solid #888;
  background-color:#eee;
  height:30px;
  width:100%;
}
.bar {
  height:30px;
  background-color:red;
  width:0;
  transition: all ease 1s;
}
```

```html
Click to run...<br/>
<div class="progress" onclick='load(this, 25)'><div class="bar">25%</div></div>
<div class="progress" onclick='load(this, 50)'><div class="bar">50%</div></div>
<div class="progress" onclick='load(this, 75)'><div class="bar">75%</div></div>
<div class="progress" onclick='load(this, 100)'><div class="bar">100%</div></div>
```

(Original answer)

```js
function load(bar, until) {
  var p = 0;
  setInterval(function() {
  
    // Clear on complete
    if (p > until) {
      clearInterval(this);
      return;
    }
    
    // Update Bar
    bar.innerHTML = p;
    bar.style.background = getGradient((p/1)/100);
    bar.style.width = p + "%";
    
    // Bump percentage 
    p++;
  }, 100);
}

function getGradient(ratio) {
    var color1 = '90ee90'; // lightgreen
    var color2 = 'FF0000'; // red
    var hex = function(x) {
        x = x.toString(16);
        return (x.length == 1) ? '0' + x : x;
    };

    var r = Math.ceil(parseInt(color1.substring(0,2), 16) * ratio + parseInt(color2.substring(0,2), 16) * (1-ratio));
    var g = Math.ceil(parseInt(color1.substring(2,4), 16) * ratio + parseInt(color2.substring(2,4), 16) * (1-ratio));
    var b = Math.ceil(parseInt(color1.substring(4,6), 16) * ratio + parseInt(color2.substring(4,6), 16) * (1-ratio));
    return '#' + hex(r) + hex(g) + hex(b);
}
```

```css
.progress {
  border:1px solid #888;
  background-color:#eee;
  height: 50px;
  width:100%;
}
.bar {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress"><div onClick='load(this, 100)' class="bar"></div></div>
<div class="progress"><div onClick='load(this, 50)'  class="bar"></div></div>
```

Comment: I like the idea... but instead of setting the colour directly, it would make more sense to work it out once, and set it as the final colour of the transition. I will have a play

Comment: Won't you end up with the same issue? How would you stop suck a transition? Ow, you could calculate the 'duration' based on current and previous percentages, so you wont have to 'stop' the transition.

Comment: If I can use the function to get the RGB for a particular percentage, then I can set the background-color to be that... then when I add the class the transition will move TO that colour. I'm not that bothered about duration, but if necessary I could also set that in the code

Comment: Could you maybe add some more info about the percentage? How is it calculated? API, or just hardcoded? If you know max percentage beforehand, it shouldn;t be that hard. However, when you're not sure how on how much percentage the bar will stop, how would you calcualate the 'final' color?

Comment: The percentage will be provided via AJAX after the page has loaded

Comment: Ahhh, maybe you could add that to the OP? Opens up a lot more solutions.

Comment: @freefaller Won't calling `getGradient(percentage/100)` on your ajax's callback solve your problem ? I mean you only need to know the color value at that percentage right ? Then you might use it as you want ? Because a running transition introduces **time** and can only be handled by `polling` or a nice event driven solution (if there was).

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I meant ("If I can use the function to get the RGB for a particular percentage, then I can set the background-color to be that"), and I'm trying it now... keep getting distracted by colleagues!

Comment: Yep, it works without the need for any interval processing.. so the key thing was the `getGradient` code.  Based on that I can set the `width` and `background-colour` to the correct colour for the percentage.  If you can amend your question (or I can if you're willing to let me) then we're good :-)

Comment: Glad you got it working! You've got a working snippet to add to my answer? Otherwise I'll try to create one to improve my answer. But, of course, you can always improve it ;)

Comment: I've added my version as a hidden script... please feel free to edit as you wish (minor amendments for the click, as the bar is 0% to start with, so you can't click on it, that's why I moved it to the progress instead)

Comment: Hehe, I had the same problem in my snippet, same solution. Ill update my answer in a sec to remove my snippet, and update yours. Thx

Comment: Excellent - thanks for your time... it's very much appreciated... now I just need to find colours that don't look like slurry when you're at the 33% step ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this by getting the computed styles and setting those to your `bar` element (on click of a button) or when we reach the `percentage` width of `progress` element by using polling via `setInterval` like so :-

```js
var bar = document.getElementById("bar");
    setTimeout(function(){
      bar.style.width = "100%";
      bar.classList.add("show");
    },10);


function stopProgressAt(percentage){
let interval = setInterval(()=>{
 const progress = document.getElementById("progress");
 const width = getComputedStyle(bar).getPropertyValue('width');
if((parseInt(width) * 100)/(Math.floor(progress.offsetWidth)) >= percentage ){
pauseTransition();
setTimeout(()=>clearInterval(interval),0);
}
},0)
}


function pauseTransition(){
     const bgColor = getComputedStyle(bar).getPropertyValue('background-color');
    const width = getComputedStyle(bar).getPropertyValue('width');
     bar.style.width=width;
     bar.style.backgroundColor=bgColor;
    ;}
    
 stopProgressAt(66);
```

```css
#progress {
      border:1px solid #888;
      background-color:#eee;
      height:
      width:100%;
    }
    #bar {
      height:30px;
      background-color:red;
      width:0;
      transition: all ease 1s;
    }
    #bar.show {
      background-color:lightgreen;
    }
```

```html
<div id="progress"><div id="bar"></div></div>
    <button onclick="pauseTransition()">Pause</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Can you show me how that work work with a specific percentage value... say 66%.  This is not something that people will manually stop, it's something that will be displayed based on a predetermined percentage value

Comment: @freefaller Updated answer by trying a polling mechanism via `setInterval` and `percentage` variable.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, but that looks incredibly hacky... it also results (on my Firefox) with the bar reaching the middle (even though I suggested 66% as an example) and then retracting a few pixels

Comment: @freefaller You're right, it is hacky. Maybe `animation` keyframes and `pause-state` can be handy for you. But it's working fine for me in **firefox** though. But yes on viewport resize, you won't see the desired behaviour. Would need additional `resize` event handler for the bar to be consistent with the progress width.

Comment: You can set `percentage` variable to 66 to get what you want in-case you missed it.

Comment: Ahh I can the depleting bar behaviour. Happens with short transition durations. Alright that's not good.

Comment: @freefaller Did some changes to not have that depleting bar behaviour. Do you still observe them ?

Comment: Yes, looks better - but I'm still not happy with it as a solution. I really do appreciate the effort though

Comment: @freefaller That's okay. Really doing this for my curiosity. Will see if I can come up with something better.

Answer (score 1):

use an opaque overlay, like this:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  const hue = 120;
  const size = 0.7;
  const H = hue * size;
  const L = (size < .5 ? 1 - size : size) * 50;
  const hsl = `hsl(${H}, 100%, ${L}%)`;
  const progress = document.getElementById('progress');
  progress.style.setProperty('--size', size);
  progress.style.setProperty('--hsl', hsl);
}, 500);
```

```css
#progress {
  --size: 0;
  --hsl: hsl(0, 100%, 50%);
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  background-color: var(--hsl);
  transition: background-color 1s;
}
#bar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: white;
  transition: margin-left 1s;
  margin-left: calc(var(--size) * 100%);
}
```

```html
<div id="progress"><div id="bar"></div></div>
```