# Lighten hex code in javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, hex

I want to have the user be able to enter a random hex color and my javascript code would print out a lighter version of that color (some sort of algorithm so to speak)

A quick example of how I want the colors to change.

What the user inputs: #2AC0A3

What it spits out: #C6EEE6

Thanks so much to anyone who can help!

Comment: This will go a lot better if you can give a more complete definition of "lighter" than just one example.

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5560248/programmatically-lighten-or-darken-a-hex-color

Answer (score 18):

An easy way to lighten up a color is linear interpolation with white. In the same way, a color can be darkened by interpolating with black.

Here's a function that takes a color string and changes the brightness indicated by `light`:

```
function hex2(c) {
    c = Math.round(c);
    if (c < 0) c = 0;
    if (c > 255) c = 255;

    var s = c.toString(16);
    if (s.length < 2) s = "0" + s;

    return s;
}

function color(r, g, b) {
    return "#" + hex2(r) + hex2(g) + hex2(b);
}

function shade(col, light) {

    // TODO: Assert that col is good and that -1 < light < 1

    var r = parseInt(col.substr(1, 2), 16);
    var g = parseInt(col.substr(3, 2), 16);
    var b = parseInt(col.substr(5, 2), 16);

    if (light < 0) {
        r = (1 + light) * r;
        g = (1 + light) * g;
        b = (1 + light) * b;
    } else {
        r = (1 - light) * r + light * 255;
        g = (1 - light) * g + light * 255;
        b = (1 - light) * b + light * 255;
    }

    return color(r, g, b);
}
```

When `light` is negative, the color is darkened; -1 always yields black. When `light` is positive, the color is lightened, 1always yields white. Finally, 0 always yields the original color:

```
alert(shade("#2ac0a3", 0.731));
```

Comment: Thanks, this is super helpful.Don't know why it hasn't got more upvotes yet

Comment: This seems to be pretty great! I refactored the algo a little bit and copied in helpers from my hex project (https://github.com/rpearce/hex) into a zero-dependency gist anyone can use: https://gist.github.com/rpearce/7806764b7ba2694ba27a849e3178db9e