# Getting exact color code from LinearGradient in android SeekBar

Tags: android, linear-gradients, android-seekbar

I have a requirement in my project to create SeekBar filled with different shades of color. For that purpose, I am using LinearGradient by assigning start and end color value and it is also works like charm. But I have no idea how to get the exact color code from the seekbar when the position changes.

I am also posting some piece of code for your reference:

```
public class SeekbarActivity extends Activity {

    private SeekBar volumeControl = null;
    private View view;
    private ShapeDrawable shape;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_seekbar);

        volumeControl = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.volume_bar);

        view = (View) findViewById(R.id.seek_view);

        LinearGradient test = new LinearGradient(0.f, 0.f, 300.f, 0.0f,
                Color.BLACK, Color.RED, TileMode.CLAMP);

        shape = new ShapeDrawable(new RectShape());
        shape.getPaint().setShader(test);

        volumeControl.setProgressDrawable((Drawable) shape);

        volumeControl.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                    boolean fromUser) {

            }

            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });

    }

}
```

**Output image**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no default options available to get the color shades using seekbar, but some calculations with the color code will give you the result. This is how I have done to get color shades using a seekbar

```
seek.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            int a = Color.alpha(selectedColor);
            int r = Color.red(selectedColor);
            int g = Color.green(selectedColor);
            int b = Color.blue(selectedColor);
            int rr = (progress*r)/100;
            int gg = (progress*g)/100;
            int bb = (progress*b)/100;
            colorView.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(a, rr, gg, bb));

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is first determine your end color (the hex code). In your example this is red so I am going to assume it's #FF0000. Now the difference between black (#000000) and red (#FF0000) = #FF, which in decimal values is 255.

You can handle the value of the seekbar as a value between 0 and 255. If you convert the chosen value to HEX and replace the first two characters with the red HEX, then you'll get a darker shade of red.

An example:

Your seekbar value is 216.

The hex value of 216 is D8

Since RED is represented by the first two characters in a hex code for color, the hex code #D80000 represents the shade of red that you want.

Comment: Thanks @Tim for your solution. What if suppose my Color hex color code is #3F51B5 (indigo) instead of Red??. I guess then it would be tedious for me to calculate

Comment: @Chandru Yes. Since a darker shade of indigo is a totally different color code (because you are not just reducing one base color). The method I proposed can only be used for red, green or blue. You could pre determine your shades and color codes, and base the chosen color code on the value of the seekbar manually. This would be tedious though.

Comment: hmmm yeah. I will be choosing color from color picker dialog and then will dynamically load the colors in seekbar

Comment: @Chandru I think this will definitely help you further: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5560248/programmatically-lighten-or-darken-a-hex-color-or-rgb-and-blend-colors .. It's definitely an interesting question! Albeit a difficult one.

Answer (score 0):

If your starting colour as white or any other colour and end colour is different, you can use following

```
private static int findColor(int selectedColor, float ratio) {
    final float inverseRation = 1f - ratio;
    float r = (Color.red(selectedColor) * ratio) + (Color.red(Color.WHITE) * inverseRation);
    float g = (Color.green(selectedColor) * ratio) + (Color.green(Color.WHITE) * inverseRation);
    float b = (Color.blue(selectedColor) * ratio) + (Color.blue(Color.WHITE) * inverseRation);
    return Color.rgb((int) r, (int) g, (int) b);
}
```

Call this as function

```
 float ratio = (float) progress / 100;
 selected_color = findColor(color, ratio);
```

Where selected colour is final colour (Currently for this case RED) and

> Color.White

is starting colour in this case (Black) and progress is 0 to 100.