# Using JQuery to write a value into SASS's "lighten" method

Tags: jquery, html, css, sass

I intend to have several rows of rectangles stacking on top of each other vertically down the page, and I want each rectangle (a div, actually) to get progressively lighter as they go down the page.

Here's the codepen.io link:
http://codepen.io/Chiz/pen/gpNRMj

Altenatively, here's my HTML:

```
<div></div>
```

And my CSS (using SASS):

```
div
{
  width:100%;
  height:70px;
  background-color:lighten(blue,0%);
  border:1px solid white;
  margin:-1px 0;
}
```

And my jQuery:

```
var l;
var ccolor;

for(var i = 0; i <=10; i++)
{
    l = $("<div></div>");
    ccolor = i * 7;
    $(l).css("background-color", "lighten(ccolor");
    $("html").append(l);
}
```

I think the problem is in that "lighten(ccolor")" part, because the ccolor variable is being written as a text, I think, instead of an actual variable.
That's why instead of the divs getting lighter as they come down the page, the divs are all one same color.

How do I fix this? Tks!

Comment: I believe SASS is precompiled. (i.e. on the server). The JavaScript (run in the client browser) will execute on the front end and will add the property `background-color: lighten(ccolor` to the `<div>` tag. The value is invalid so the property will simply be ignored. I don't think you can do what you're trying to do on the client...

Comment: You should create 10 classes in your sass file, and then just assign a class name to each div.

Answer (score 0):

To address the variable issue. It should be written as this:

```
var l;
var ccolor;

for(var i = 0; i <=10; i++)
{
    l = $("<div></div>");
    ccolor = i * 7;
    $(l).css("background-color", "lighten(" + ccolor + ")");
    $("html").append(l);
}
```

**However**, [War10ck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1680836/war10ck)'s comment is correct. You would actually need a JS function to calculate the new color since the SASS is compiled on the server. I would suggest looking at this question - [Programmatically Lighten or Darken a hex color (or rgb, and blend colors)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5560248/programmatically-lighten-or-darken-a-hex-color-or-rgb-and-blend-colors)