# How to randomly receive a Material Design Color?

Tags: java, android, colors, hex, android-color

Google has their [Color - Guidelines](http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html), so how to randomly receive a color? Is there a way to specify a number from the table and receive a random color out of all colors of the table?

**For example `getMatColor(100);`:**

[image]

**EDIT - Result:**
(Icon colors)

[image]

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Better late than never.

My new response if the real purpose is to get a random material color for a *type* of color.

**Add the array.xml file** (from @8m47x)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <array name="mdcolor_50">
        <item name="red_50" type="color">#fde0dc</item>
        <item name="pink_50" type="color">#fce4ec</item>
        <item name="purple_50" type="color">#f3e5f5</item>
        <item name="deep_purple_50" type="color">#ede7f6</item>
        <item name="indigo_50" type="color">#e8eaf6</item>
        <item name="blue_50" type="color">#e7e9fd</item>
        <item name="light_blue_50" type="color">#e1f5fe</item>
        <item name="cyan_50" type="color">#e0f7fa</item>
        <item name="teal_50" type="color">#e0f2f1</item>
        <item name="green_50" type="color">#d0f8ce</item>
        <item name="light_green_50" type="color">#f1f8e9</item>
        <item name="lime_50" type="color">#f9fbe7</item>
        <item name="yellow_50" type="color">#fffde7</item>
        <item name="amber_50" type="color">#fff8e1</item>
        <item name="orange_50" type="color">#fff3e0</item>
        <item name="deep_orange_50" type="color">#fbe9e7</item>
        <item name="brown_50" type="color">#efebe9</item>
        <item name="grey_50" type="color">#fafafa</item>
        <item name="blue_grey_50" type="color">#eceff1</item>
    </array>
    <array name="mdcolor_100">
        <item name="red_100" type="color">#f9bdbb</item>
        <item name="pink_100" type="color">#f8bbd0</item>
        <item name="purple_100" type="color">#e1bee7</item>
        <item name="deep_purple_100" type="color">#d1c4e9</item>
        <item name="indigo_100" type="color">#c5cae9</item>
        <item name="blue_100" type="color">#d0d9ff</item>
        <item name="light_blue_100" type="color">#b3e5fc</item>
        <item name="cyan_100" type="color">#b2ebf2</item>
        <item name="teal_100" type="color">#b2dfdb</item>
        <item name="green_100" type="color">#a3e9a4</item>
        <item name="light_green_100" type="color">#dcedc8</item>
        <item name="lime_100" type="color">#f0f4c3</item>
        <item name="yellow_100" type="color">#fff9c4</item>
        <item name="amber_100" type="color">#ffecb3</item>
        <item name="orange_100" type="color">#ffe0b2</item>
        <item name="deep_orange_100" type="color">#ffccbc</item>
        <item name="brown_100" type="color">#d7ccc8</item>
        <item name="grey_100" type="color">#f5f5f5</item>
        <item name="blue_grey_100" type="color">#cfd8dc</item>
    </array>
    <array name="mdcolor_200">
        <item name="red_200" type="color">#f69988</item>
        <item name="pink_200" type="color">#f48fb1</item>
        <item name="purple_200" type="color">#ce93d8</item>
        <item name="deep_purple_200" type="color">#b39ddb</item>
        <item name="indigo_200" type="color">#9fa8da</item>
        <item name="blue_200" type="color">#afbfff</item>
        <item name="light_blue_200" type="color">#81d4fa</item>
        <item name="cyan_200" type="color">#80deea</item>
        <item name="teal_200" type="color">#80cbc4</item>
        <item name="green_200" type="color">#72d572</item>
        <item name="light_green_200" type="color">#c5e1a5</item>
        <item name="lime_200" type="color">#e6ee9c</item>
        <item name="yellow_200" type="color">#fff59d</item>
        <item name="orange_200" type="color">#ffcc80</item>
        <item name="deep_orange_200" type="color">#ffab91</item>
        <item name="brown_200" type="color">#bcaaa4</item>
        <item name="grey_200" type="color">#eeeeee</item>
        <item name="blue_grey_200" type="color">#b0bec5</item>
    </array>
    <array name="mdcolor_300">
        <item name="red_300" type="color">#f36c60</item>
        <item name="pink_300" type="color">#f06292</item>
        <item name="purple_300" type="color">#ba68c8</item>
        <item name="deep_purple_300" type="color">#9575cd</item>
        <item name="indigo_300" type="color">#7986cb</item>
        <item name="blue_300" type="color">#91a7ff</item>
        <item name="light_blue_300" type="color">#4fc3f7</item>
        <item name="cyan_300" type="color">#4dd0e1</item>
        <item name="teal_300" type="color">#4db6ac</item>
        <item name="green_300" type="color">#42bd41</item>
        <item name="light_green_300" type="color">#aed581</item>
        <item name="lime_300" type="color">#dce775</item>
        <item name="yellow_300" type="color">#fff176</item>
        <item name="orange_300" type="color">#ffb74d</item>
        <item name="deep_orange_300" type="color">#ff8a65</item>
        <item name="brown_300" type="color">#a1887f</item>
        <item name="grey_300" type="color">#e0e0e0</item>
        <item name="blue_grey_300" type="color">#90a4ae</item>
    </array>
    <array name="mdcolor_400">
        <item name="red_400" type="color">#e84e40</item>
        <item name="pink_400" type="color">#ec407a</item>
        <item name="purple_400" type="color">#ab47bc</item>
        <item name="deep_purple_400" type="color">#7e57c2</item>
        <item name="indigo_400" type="color">#5c6bc0</item>
        <item name="blue_400" type="color">#738ffe</item>
        <item name="light_blue_400" type="color">#29b6f6</item>
        <item name="cyan_400" type="color">#26c6da</item>
        <item name="teal_400" type="color">#26a69a</item>
        <item name="green_400" type="color">#2baf2b</item>
        <item name="light_green_400" type="color">#9ccc65</item>
        <item name="lime_400" type="color">#d4e157</item>
        <item name="yellow_400" type="color">#ffee58</item>
        <item name="orange_400" type="color">#ffa726</item>
        <item name="deep_orange_400" type="color">#ff7043</item>
        <item name="brown_400" type="color">#8d6e63</item>
        <item name="grey_400" type="color">#bdbdbd</item>
        <item name="blue_grey_400" type="color">#78909c</item>
    </array>
    <array name="mdcolor_500">
        <item name="red_500" type="color">#e51c23</item>
        <item name="pink_500" type="color">#e91e63</item>
        <item name="purple_500" type="color">#9c27b0</item>
        <item name="deep_purple_500" type="color">#673ab7</item>
        <item name="indigo_500" type="color">#3f51b5</item>
        <item name="blue_500" type="color">#5677fc</item>
        <item name="light_blue_500" type="color">#03a9f4</item>
        <item name="cyan_500" type="color">#00bcd4</item>
        <item name="teal_500" type="color">#009688</item>
        <item name="green_500" type="color">#259b24</item>
        <item name="light_green_500" type="color">#8bc34a</item>
        <item name="lime_500" type="color">#cddc39</item>
        <item name="yellow_500" type="color">#ffeb3b</item>
        <item name="orange_500" type="color">#ff9800</item>
        <item name="deep_orange_500" type="color">#ff5722</item>
        <item name="brown_500" type="color">#795548</item>
        <item name="grey_500" type="color">#9e9e9e</item>
        <item name="blue_grey_500" type="color">#607d8b</item>
    </array>
    <array name="mdcolor_600">
        <item name="red_600" type="color">#dd191d</item>
        <item name="pink_600" type="color">#d81b60</item>
        <item name="purple_600" type="color">#8e24aa</item>
        <item name="deep_purple_600" type="color">#5e35b1</item>
        <item name="indigo_600" type="color">#3949ab</item>
        <item name="blue_600" type="color">#4e6cef</item>
        <item name="light_blue_600" type="color">#039be5</item>
        <item name="cyan_600" type="color">#00acc1</item>
        <item name="teal_600" type="color">#00897b</item>
        <item name="green_600" type="color">#0a8f08</item>
        <item name="light_green_600" type="color">#7cb342</item>
        <item name="lime_600" type="color">#c0ca33</item>
        <item name="yellow_600" type="color">#fdd835</item>
        <item name="orange_600" type="color">#fb8c00</item>
        <item name="deep_orange_600" type="color">#f4511e</item>
        <item name="brown_600" type="color">#6d4c41</item>
        <item name="grey_600" type="color">#757575</item>
        <item name="blue_grey_600" type="color">#546e7a</item>
    </array>
    <array name="mdcolor_700">
        <item name="red_700" type="color">#d01716</item>
        <item name="pink_700" type="color">#c2185b</item>
        <item name="purple_700" type="color">#7b1fa2</item>
        <item name="deep_purple_700" type="color">#512da8</item>
        <item name="indigo_700" type="color">#303f9f</item>
        <item name="blue_700" type="color">#455ede</item>
        <item name="light_blue_700" type="color">#0288d1</item>
        <item name="cyan_700" type="color">#0097a7</item>
        <item name="teal_700" type="color">#00796b</item>
        <item name="green_700" type="color">#0a7e07</item>
        <item name="light_green_700" type="color">#689f38</item>
        <item name="lime_700" type="color">#afb42b</item>
        <item name="yellow_700" type="color">#fbc02d</item>
        <item name="orange_700" type="color">#f57c00</item>
        <item name="deep_orange_700" type="color">#e64a19</item>
        <item name="brown_700" type="color">#5d4037</item>
        <item name="grey_700" type="color">#616161</item>
        <item name="blue_grey_700" type="color">#455a64</item>
    </array>
    <array name="mdcolor_800">
        <item name="red_800" type="color">#c41411</item>
        <item name="pink_800" type="color">#ad1457</item>
        <item name="purple_800" type="color">#6a1b9a</item>
        <item name="deep_purple_800" type="color">#4527a0</item>
        <item name="indigo_800" type="color">#283593</item>
        <item name="blue_800" type="color">#3b50ce</item>
        <item name="light_blue_800" type="color">#0277bd</item>
        <item name="cyan_800" type="color">#00838f</item>
        <item name="teal_800" type="color">#00695c</item>
        <item name="green_800" type="color">#056f00</item>
        <item name="light_green_800" type="color">#558b2f</item>
        <item name="lime_800" type="color">#9e9d24</item>
        <item name="yellow_800" type="color">#f9a825</item>
        <item name="orange_800" type="color">#ef6c00</item>
        <item name="deep_orange_800" type="color">#d84315</item>
        <item name="brown_800" type="color">#4e342e</item>
        <item name="grey_800" type="color">#424242</item>
        <item name="blue_grey_800" type="color">#37474f</item>
    </array>
    <array name="mdcolor_900">
        <item name="red_900" type="color">#b0120a</item>
        <item name="pink_900" type="color">#880e4f</item>
        <item name="purple_900" type="color">#4a148c</item>
        <item name="deep_purple_900" type="color">#311b92</item>
        <item name="indigo_900" type="color">#1a237e</item>
        <item name="blue_900" type="color">#2a36b1</item>
        <item name="light_blue_900" type="color">#01579b</item>
        <item name="cyan_900" type="color">#006064</item>
        <item name="teal_900" type="color">#004d40</item>
        <item name="green_900" type="color">#0d5302</item>
        <item name="light_green_900" type="color">#33691e</item>
        <item name="lime_900" type="color">#827717</item>
        <item name="yellow_900" type="color">#f57f17</item>
        <item name="orange_900" type="color">#e65100</item>
        <item name="deep_orange_900" type="color">#bf360c</item>
        <item name="brown_900" type="color">#3e2723</item>
        <item name="grey_900" type="color">#212121</item>
        <item name="blue_grey_900" type="color">#263238</item>
    </array>
    <array name="mdcolor_A100">
        <item name="red_A100" type="color">#ff7997</item>
        <item name="pink_A100" type="color">#ff80ab</item>
        <item name="purple_A100" type="color">#ea80fc</item>
        <item name="deep_purple_A100" type="color">#b388ff</item>
        <item name="indigo_A100" type="color">#8c9eff</item>
        <item name="blue_A100" type="color">#a6baff</item>
        <item name="light_blue_A100" type="color">#80d8ff</item>
        <item name="cyan_A100" type="color">#84ffff</item>
        <item name="teal_A100" type="color">#a7ffeb</item>
        <item name="green_A100" type="color">#a2f78d</item>
        <item name="light_green_A100" type="color">#ccff90</item>
        <item name="lime_A100" type="color">#f4ff81</item>
        <item name="yellow_A100" type="color">#ffff8d</item>
        <item name="orange_A100" type="color">#ffd180</item>
        <item name="deep_orange_A100" type="color">#ff9e80</item>
    </array>
    <array name="mdcolor_A200">
        <item name="red_A200" type="color">#ff5177</item>
        <item name="pink_A200" type="color">#ff4081</item>
        <item name="purple_A200" type="color">#e040fb</item>
        <item name="deep_purple_A200" type="color">#7c4dff</item>
        <item name="indigo_A200" type="color">#536dfe</item>
        <item name="blue_A200" type="color">#6889ff</item>
        <item name="light_blue_A200" type="color">#40c4ff</item>
        <item name="cyan_A200" type="color">#18ffff</item>
        <item name="teal_A200" type="color">#64ffda</item>
        <item name="green_A200" type="color">#5af158</item>
        <item name="light_green_A200" type="color">#b2ff59</item>
        <item name="lime_A200" type="color">#eeff41</item>
        <item name="yellow_A200" type="color">#ffff00</item>
        <item name="orange_A200" type="color">#ffab40</item>
        <item name="deep_orange_A200" type="color">#ff6e40</item>
    </array>
    <array name="mdcolor_A400">
        <item name="red_A400" type="color">#ff2d6f</item>
        <item name="pink_A400" type="color">#f50057</item>
        <item name="purple_A400" type="color">#d500f9</item>
        <item name="deep_purple_A400" type="color">#651fff</item>
        <item name="indigo_A400" type="color">#3d5afe</item>
        <item name="blue_A400" type="color">#4d73ff</item>
        <item name="light_blue_A400" type="color">#00b0ff</item>
        <item name="cyan_A400" type="color">#00e5ff</item>
        <item name="teal_A400" type="color">#1de9b6</item>
        <item name="green_A400" type="color">#14e715</item>
        <item name="light_green_A400" type="color">#76ff03</item>
        <item name="lime_A400" type="color">#c6ff00</item>
        <item name="yellow_A400" type="color">#ffea00</item>
        <item name="orange_A400" type="color">#ff9100</item>
        <item name="deep_orange_A400" type="color">#ff3d00</item>
    </array>
    <array name="mdcolor_A700">
        <item name="red_A700" type="color">#e00032</item>
        <item name="pink_A700" type="color">#c51162</item>
        <item name="purple_A700" type="color">#aa00ff</item>
        <item name="deep_purple_A700" type="color">#6200ea</item>
        <item name="indigo_A700" type="color">#304ffe</item>
        <item name="blue_A700" type="color">#4d69ff</item>
        <item name="light_blue_A700" type="color">#0091ea</item>
        <item name="cyan_A700" type="color">#00b8d4</item>
        <item name="teal_A700" type="color">#00bfa5</item>
        <item name="green_A700" type="color">#12c700</item>
        <item name="light_green_A700" type="color">#64dd17</item>
        <item name="lime_A700" type="color">#aeea00</item>
        <item name="yellow_A700" type="color">#ffd600</item>
        <item name="orange_A700" type="color">#ff6d00</item>
        <item name="deep_orange_A700" type="color">#dd2c00</item>
    </array>
    <array name="extra">
        <item name="grey_1000b" type="color">#000000</item>
        <item name="grey_1000w" type="color">#ffffff</item>
    </array>

</resources>
```

**Add the following method to pick a random color from a parent type**

```
private int getMatColor(String typeColor)
{
    int returnColor = Color.BLACK;
    int arrayId = getResources().getIdentifier("mdcolor_" + typeColor, "array", getApplicationContext().getPackageName());

    if (arrayId != 0)
    {
        TypedArray colors = getResources().obtainTypedArray(arrayId);
        int index = (int) (Math.random() * colors.length());
        returnColor = colors.getColor(index, Color.BLACK);
        colors.recycle();
    }
    return returnColor;
}
```

**Usage**

```
txt.setTextColor(getMatColor("500"));
```

Comment: By the way, I sorted array.xml by hand :) I asked a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32672040/puzzle-sort-text) on stackoverflow for sorting but couldn't find a useful answer..

Comment: you are missing amber.

Answer (score 11):

If you want something working with older SDK you can try this way :

```
TypedArray colors = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.loading_colors);
int index = (int) (Math.random() * colors .length());
int color = colors.getColor(index, Color.BLACK);
textView.setTextColor(color);
colors.recycle();
```

You need to declare your colors in a arrays.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <array name="loading_colors">
        <item name="red_50" type="color">#fde0dc</item>
        <item name="red_100" type="color">#f9bdbb</item>
        <item name="red_200" type="color">#f69988</item>
        <item name="red_300" type="color">#f36c60</item>
        <item name="red_400" type="color">#e84e40</item>
        <item name="red_500" type="color">#e51c23</item>
        <item name="red_600" type="color">#dd191d</item>
        <item name="red_700" type="color">#d01716</item>
        <item name="red_800" type="color">#c41411</item>
        <item name="red_900" type="color">#b0120a</item>
        <item name="red_A100" type="color">#ff7997</item>
        <item name="red_A200" type="color">#ff5177</item>
        <item name="red_A400" type="color">#ff2d6f</item>
        <item name="red_A700" type="color">#e00032</item>
        <item name="pink_50" type="color">#fce4ec</item>
        <item name="pink_100" type="color">#f8bbd0</item>
        <item name="pink_200" type="color">#f48fb1</item>
        <item name="pink_300" type="color">#f06292</item>
        <item name="pink_400" type="color">#ec407a</item>
        <item name="pink_500" type="color">#e91e63</item>
        <item name="pink_600" type="color">#d81b60</item>
        <item name="pink_700" type="color">#c2185b</item>
        <item name="pink_800" type="color">#ad1457</item>
        <item name="pink_900" type="color">#880e4f</item>
        <item name="pink_A100" type="color">#ff80ab</item>
        <item name="pink_A200" type="color">#ff4081</item>
        <item name="pink_A400" type="color">#f50057</item>
        <item name="pink_A700" type="color">#c51162</item>
        <item name="purple_50" type="color">#f3e5f5</item>
        <item name="purple_100" type="color">#e1bee7</item>
        <item name="purple_200" type="color">#ce93d8</item>
        <item name="purple_300" type="color">#ba68c8</item>
        <item name="purple_400" type="color">#ab47bc</item>
        <item name="purple_500" type="color">#9c27b0</item>
        <item name="purple_600" type="color">#8e24aa</item>
        <item name="purple_700" type="color">#7b1fa2</item>
        <item name="purple_800" type="color">#6a1b9a</item>
        <item name="purple_900" type="color">#4a148c</item>
        <item name="purple_A100" type="color">#ea80fc</item>
        <item name="purple_A200" type="color">#e040fb</item>
        <item name="purple_A400" type="color">#d500f9</item>
        <item name="purple_A700" type="color">#aa00ff</item>
        <item name="deep_purple_50" type="color">#ede7f6</item>
        <item name="deep_purple_100" type="color">#d1c4e9</item>
        <item name="deep_purple_200" type="color">#b39ddb</item>
        <item name="deep_purple_300" type="color">#9575cd</item>
        <item name="deep_purple_400" type="color">#7e57c2</item>
        <item name="deep_purple_500" type="color">#673ab7</item>
        <item name="deep_purple_600" type="color">#5e35b1</item>
        <item name="deep_purple_700" type="color">#512da8</item>
        <item name="deep_purple_800" type="color">#4527a0</item>
        <item name="deep_purple_900" type="color">#311b92</item>
        <item name="deep_purple_A100" type="color">#b388ff</item>
        <item name="deep_purple_A200" type="color">#7c4dff</item>
        <item name="deep_purple_A400" type="color">#651fff</item>
        <item name="deep_purple_A700" type="color">#6200ea</item>
        <item name="indigo_50" type="color">#e8eaf6</item>
        <item name="indigo_100" type="color">#c5cae9</item>
        <item name="indigo_200" type="color">#9fa8da</item>
        <item name="indigo_300" type="color">#7986cb</item>
        <item name="indigo_400" type="color">#5c6bc0</item>
        <item name="indigo_500" type="color">#3f51b5</item>
        <item name="indigo_600" type="color">#3949ab</item>
        <item name="indigo_700" type="color">#303f9f</item>
        <item name="indigo_800" type="color">#283593</item>
        <item name="indigo_900" type="color">#1a237e</item>
        <item name="indigo_A100" type="color">#8c9eff</item>
        <item name="indigo_A200" type="color">#536dfe</item>
        <item name="indigo_A400" type="color">#3d5afe</item>
        <item name="indigo_A700" type="color">#304ffe</item>
        <item name="blue_50" type="color">#e7e9fd</item>
        <item name="blue_100" type="color">#d0d9ff</item>
        <item name="blue_200" type="color">#afbfff</item>
        <item name="blue_300" type="color">#91a7ff</item>
        <item name="blue_400" type="color">#738ffe</item>
        <item name="blue_500" type="color">#5677fc</item>
        <item name="blue_600" type="color">#4e6cef</item>
        <item name="blue_700" type="color">#455ede</item>
        <item name="blue_800" type="color">#3b50ce</item>
        <item name="blue_900" type="color">#2a36b1</item>
        <item name="blue_A100" type="color">#a6baff</item>
        <item name="blue_A200" type="color">#6889ff</item>
        <item name="blue_A400" type="color">#4d73ff</item>
        <item name="blue_A700" type="color">#4d69ff</item>
        <item name="light_blue_50" type="color">#e1f5fe</item>
        <item name="light_blue_100" type="color">#b3e5fc</item>
        <item name="light_blue_200" type="color">#81d4fa</item>
        <item name="light_blue_300" type="color">#4fc3f7</item>
        <item name="light_blue_400" type="color">#29b6f6</item>
        <item name="light_blue_500" type="color">#03a9f4</item>
        <item name="light_blue_600" type="color">#039be5</item>
        <item name="light_blue_700" type="color">#0288d1</item>
        <item name="light_blue_800" type="color">#0277bd</item>
        <item name="light_blue_900" type="color">#01579b</item>
        <item name="light_blue_A100" type="color">#80d8ff</item>
        <item name="light_blue_A200" type="color">#40c4ff</item>
        <item name="light_blue_A400" type="color">#00b0ff</item>
        <item name="light_blue_A700" type="color">#0091ea</item>
        <item name="cyan_50" type="color">#e0f7fa</item>
        <item name="cyan_100" type="color">#b2ebf2</item>
        <item name="cyan_200" type="color">#80deea</item>
        <item name="cyan_300" type="color">#4dd0e1</item>
        <item name="cyan_400" type="color">#26c6da</item>
        <item name="cyan_500" type="color">#00bcd4</item>
        <item name="cyan_600" type="color">#00acc1</item>
        <item name="cyan_700" type="color">#0097a7</item>
        <item name="cyan_800" type="color">#00838f</item>
        <item name="cyan_900" type="color">#006064</item>
        <item name="cyan_A100" type="color">#84ffff</item>
        <item name="cyan_A200" type="color">#18ffff</item>
        <item name="cyan_A400" type="color">#00e5ff</item>
        <item name="cyan_A700" type="color">#00b8d4</item>
        <item name="teal_50" type="color">#e0f2f1</item>
        <item name="teal_100" type="color">#b2dfdb</item>
        <item name="teal_200" type="color">#80cbc4</item>
        <item name="teal_300" type="color">#4db6ac</item>
        <item name="teal_400" type="color">#26a69a</item>
        <item name="teal_500" type="color">#009688</item>
        <item name="teal_600" type="color">#00897b</item>
        <item name="teal_700" type="color">#00796b</item>
        <item name="teal_800" type="color">#00695c</item>
        <item name="teal_900" type="color">#004d40</item>
        <item name="teal_A100" type="color">#a7ffeb</item>
        <item name="teal_A200" type="color">#64ffda</item>
        <item name="teal_A400" type="color">#1de9b6</item>
        <item name="teal_A700" type="color">#00bfa5</item>
        <item name="green_50" type="color">#d0f8ce</item>
        <item name="green_100" type="color">#a3e9a4</item>
        <item name="green_200" type="color">#72d572</item>
        <item name="green_300" type="color">#42bd41</item>
        <item name="green_400" type="color">#2baf2b</item>
        <item name="green_500" type="color">#259b24</item>
        <item name="green_600" type="color">#0a8f08</item>
        <item name="green_700" type="color">#0a7e07</item>
        <item name="green_800" type="color">#056f00</item>
        <item name="green_900" type="color">#0d5302</item>
        <item name="green_A100" type="color">#a2f78d</item>
        <item name="green_A200" type="color">#5af158</item>
        <item name="green_A400" type="color">#14e715</item>
        <item name="green_A700" type="color">#12c700</item>
        <item name="light_green_50" type="color">#f1f8e9</item>
        <item name="light_green_100" type="color">#dcedc8</item>
        <item name="light_green_200" type="color">#c5e1a5</item>
        <item name="light_green_300" type="color">#aed581</item>
        <item name="light_green_400" type="color">#9ccc65</item>
        <item name="light_green_500" type="color">#8bc34a</item>
        <item name="light_green_600" type="color">#7cb342</item>
        <item name="light_green_700" type="color">#689f38</item>
        <item name="light_green_800" type="color">#558b2f</item>
        <item name="light_green_900" type="color">#33691e</item>
        <item name="light_green_A100" type="color">#ccff90</item>
        <item name="light_green_A200" type="color">#b2ff59</item>
        <item name="light_green_A400" type="color">#76ff03</item>
        <item name="light_green_A700" type="color">#64dd17</item>
        <item name="lime_50" type="color">#f9fbe7</item>
        <item name="lime_100" type="color">#f0f4c3</item>
        <item name="lime_200" type="color">#e6ee9c</item>
        <item name="lime_300" type="color">#dce775</item>
        <item name="lime_400" type="color">#d4e157</item>
        <item name="lime_500" type="color">#cddc39</item>
        <item name="lime_600" type="color">#c0ca33</item>
        <item name="lime_700" type="color">#afb42b</item>
        <item name="lime_800" type="color">#9e9d24</item>
        <item name="lime_900" type="color">#827717</item>
        <item name="lime_A100" type="color">#f4ff81</item>
        <item name="lime_A200" type="color">#eeff41</item>
        <item name="lime_A400" type="color">#c6ff00</item>
        <item name="lime_A700" type="color">#aeea00</item>
        <item name="yellow_50" type="color">#fffde7</item>
        <item name="yellow_100" type="color">#fff9c4</item>
        <item name="yellow_200" type="color">#fff59d</item>
        <item name="yellow_300" type="color">#fff176</item>
        <item name="yellow_400" type="color">#ffee58</item>
        <item name="yellow_500" type="color">#ffeb3b</item>
        <item name="yellow_600" type="color">#fdd835</item>
        <item name="yellow_700" type="color">#fbc02d</item>
        <item name="yellow_800" type="color">#f9a825</item>
        <item name="yellow_900" type="color">#f57f17</item>
        <item name="yellow_A100" type="color">#ffff8d</item>
        <item name="yellow_A200" type="color">#ffff00</item>
        <item name="yellow_A400" type="color">#ffea00</item>
        <item name="yellow_A700" type="color">#ffd600</item>
        <item name="amber_50" type="color">#fff8e1</item>
        <item name="amber_100" type="color">#ffecb3</item>
        <item name="amber_200" type="color">#ffe082</item>
        <item name="amber_300" type="color">#ffd54f</item>
        <item name="amber_400" type="color">#ffca28</item>
        <item name="amber_500" type="color">#ffc107</item>
        <item name="amber_600" type="color">#ffb300</item>
        <item name="amber_700" type="color">#ffa000</item>
        <item name="amber_800" type="color">#ff8f00</item>
        <item name="amber_900" type="color">#ff6f00</item>
        <item name="amber_A100" type="color">#ffe57f</item>
        <item name="amber_A200" type="color">#ffd740</item>
        <item name="amber_A400" type="color">#ffc400</item>
        <item name="amber_A700" type="color">#ffab00</item>
        <item name="orange_50" type="color">#fff3e0</item>
        <item name="orange_100" type="color">#ffe0b2</item>
        <item name="orange_200" type="color">#ffcc80</item>
        <item name="orange_300" type="color">#ffb74d</item>
        <item name="orange_400" type="color">#ffa726</item>
        <item name="orange_500" type="color">#ff9800</item>
        <item name="orange_600" type="color">#fb8c00</item>
        <item name="orange_700" type="color">#f57c00</item>
        <item name="orange_800" type="color">#ef6c00</item>
        <item name="orange_900" type="color">#e65100</item>
        <item name="orange_A100" type="color">#ffd180</item>
        <item name="orange_A200" type="color">#ffab40</item>
        <item name="orange_A400" type="color">#ff9100</item>
        <item name="orange_A700" type="color">#ff6d00</item>
        <item name="deep_orange_50" type="color">#fbe9e7</item>
        <item name="deep_orange_100" type="color">#ffccbc</item>
        <item name="deep_orange_200" type="color">#ffab91</item>
        <item name="deep_orange_300" type="color">#ff8a65</item>
        <item name="deep_orange_400" type="color">#ff7043</item>
        <item name="deep_orange_500" type="color">#ff5722</item>
        <item name="deep_orange_600" type="color">#f4511e</item>
        <item name="deep_orange_700" type="color">#e64a19</item>
        <item name="deep_orange_800" type="color">#d84315</item>
        <item name="deep_orange_900" type="color">#bf360c</item>
        <item name="deep_orange_A100" type="color">#ff9e80</item>
        <item name="deep_orange_A200" type="color">#ff6e40</item>
        <item name="deep_orange_A400" type="color">#ff3d00</item>
        <item name="deep_orange_A700" type="color">#dd2c00</item>
        <item name="brown_50" type="color">#efebe9</item>
        <item name="brown_100" type="color">#d7ccc8</item>
        <item name="brown_200" type="color">#bcaaa4</item>
        <item name="brown_300" type="color">#a1887f</item>
        <item name="brown_400" type="color">#8d6e63</item>
        <item name="brown_500" type="color">#795548</item>
        <item name="brown_600" type="color">#6d4c41</item>
        <item name="brown_700" type="color">#5d4037</item>
        <item name="brown_800" type="color">#4e342e</item>
        <item name="brown_900" type="color">#3e2723</item>
        <item name="grey_50" type="color">#fafafa</item>
        <item name="grey_100" type="color">#f5f5f5</item>
        <item name="grey_200" type="color">#eeeeee</item>
        <item name="grey_300" type="color">#e0e0e0</item>
        <item name="grey_400" type="color">#bdbdbd</item>
        <item name="grey_500" type="color">#9e9e9e</item>
        <item name="grey_600" type="color">#757575</item>
        <item name="grey_700" type="color">#616161</item>
        <item name="grey_800" type="color">#424242</item>
        <item name="grey_900" type="color">#212121</item>
        <item name="grey_1000b" type="color">#000000</item>
        <item name="grey_1000w" type="color">#ffffff</item>
        <item name="blue_grey_50" type="color">#eceff1</item>
        <item name="blue_grey_100" type="color">#cfd8dc</item>
        <item name="blue_grey_200" type="color">#b0bec5</item>
        <item name="blue_grey_300" type="color">#90a4ae</item>
        <item name="blue_grey_400" type="color">#78909c</item>
        <item name="blue_grey_500" type="color">#607d8b</item>
        <item name="blue_grey_600" type="color">#546e7a</item>
        <item name="blue_grey_700" type="color">#455a64</item>
        <item name="blue_grey_800" type="color">#37474f</item>
        <item name="blue_grey_900" type="color">#263238</item>
    </array>

</resources>
```

But be careful it's probably less efficient than reflection.

Comment: Yes, that's cool, but not exactly what a tried to get.. I tried to receive one color out of the (for example) 100-series. [See my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32674486/4406921)

Answer (score 5):

Using reflection you can retrieve all java.awt.Color constants, some 148 colors with names

```
for (Field field : Color.class.getDeclaredFields()) {
    int modifiers = field.getModifiers();
    if (Modifier.isPublic(modifiers) && Modifier.isStatic(modifiers)
            && Modifier.isFinal(modifiers) && field.getType() == Color.class) {
        String colorName = field.getName().toLowerCase(Locale.US);
        Color color = Color.valueOf(colorName);
        System.out.printf("- %s -> %s%n", colorName, color);
    }
}
```

This uses reflection, and assumes that the constant name is a human readable name.

```
[139] thistle -> 0xd8bfd8ff
[140] tomato -> 0xff6347ff
[141] turquoise -> 0x40e0d0ff
[142] violet -> 0xee82eeff
[143] wheat -> 0xf5deb3ff
[144] white -> 0xffffffff
[145] whitesmoke -> 0xf5f5f5ff
[146] yellow -> 0xffff00ff
[147] yellowgreen -> 0x9acd32ff
```

So add the colors in a list, and randomly pick one with `random.nextInt(colors.size())`.

Comment: Nice idea, but I don't want to create a list manually and pick then. If Google used a algorithm to create this table, I want to use that.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a class I wrote. You can create your own material color palette or get a random color.

**Example uses:**

```
// get a random color.
int randomColor = MaterialColorPalette.getRandomColor("100");

// create your own material color palette
MaterialColorPalette myCustomPalette = new MaterialColorPalette(Color.CYAN);
int my200Color = myCustomPalette.getColor("200");
```

**MaterialColorPalette.java**

```
import android.graphics.Color;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class MaterialColorPalette {

  public static final int RED_500 = 0xFFF44336;
  public static final int PINK_500 = 0xFFE91E63;
  public static final int PURPLE_500 = 0xFF9C27B0;
  public static final int DEEP_PURPLE_500 = 0xFF673AB7;
  public static final int INDIGO_500 = 0xFF3F51B5;
  public static final int BLUE_500 = 0xFF2196F3;
  public static final int LIGHT_BLUE_500 = 0xFF03A9F4;
  public static final int CYAN_500 = 0xFF00BCD4;
  public static final int TEAL_500 = 0xFF009688;
  public static final int GREEN_500 = 0xFF4CAF50;
  public static final int LIGHT_GREEN_500 = 0xFF8BC34A;
  public static final int LIME_500 = 0xFFCDDC39;
  public static final int YELLOW_500 = 0xFFFFEB3B;
  public static final int AMBER_500 = 0xFFFFC107;
  public static final int ORANGE_500 = 0xFFFF9800;
  public static final int DEEP_ORANGE_500 = 0xFFFF5722;
  public static final int BROWN_500 = 0xFF795548;
  public static final int GREY_500 = 0xFF9E9E9E;
  public static final int BLUE_GREY_500 = 0xFF607D8B;

  private static final List<MaterialColorPalette> MATERIAL_PALETTES;

  private static final Random RANDOM = new Random();

  static {
    MATERIAL_PALETTES = new ArrayList<>();
    MATERIAL_PALETTES.add(new MaterialColorPalette(RED_500));
    MATERIAL_PALETTES.add(new MaterialColorPalette(PINK_500));
    MATERIAL_PALETTES.add(new MaterialColorPalette(PURPLE_500));
    MATERIAL_PALETTES.add(new MaterialColorPalette(DEEP_PURPLE_500));
    MATERIAL_PALETTES.add(new MaterialColorPalette(INDIGO_500));
    MATERIAL_PALETTES.add(new MaterialColorPalette(BLUE_500));
    MATERIAL_PALETTES.add(new MaterialColorPalette(LIGHT_BLUE_500));
    MATERIAL_PALETTES.add(new MaterialColorPalette(CYAN_500));
    MATERIAL_PALETTES.add(new MaterialColorPalette(TEAL_500));
    MATERIAL_PALETTES.add(new MaterialColorPalette(GREEN_500));
    MATERIAL_PALETTES.add(new MaterialColorPalette(LIGHT_GREEN_500));
    MATERIAL_PALETTES.add(new MaterialColorPalette(LIME_500));
    MATERIAL_PALETTES.add(new MaterialColorPalette(YELLOW_500));
    MATERIAL_PALETTES.add(new MaterialColorPalette(AMBER_500));
    MATERIAL_PALETTES.add(new MaterialColorPalette(ORANGE_500));
    MATERIAL_PALETTES.add(new MaterialColorPalette(DEEP_ORANGE_500));
    MATERIAL_PALETTES.add(new MaterialColorPalette(BROWN_500));
    MATERIAL_PALETTES.add(new MaterialColorPalette(GREY_500));
    MATERIAL_PALETTES.add(new MaterialColorPalette(BLUE_GREY_500));
  }

  public static int getRandomColor(String key) {
    return MATERIAL_PALETTES.get(RANDOM.nextInt(MATERIAL_PALETTES.size())).getColor(key);
  }

  /**
   * Lighten or darken a color
   *
   * @param color
   *     color value
   * @param percent
   *     -1.0 to 1.0
   * @return new shaded color
   * @see #shadeColor(String, double)
   */
  public static int shadeColor(int color, double percent) {
    return shadeColor(String.format("#%06X", (0xFFFFFF & color)), percent); // ignores alpha channel
  }

  /**
   * Lighten or darken a color
   *
   * @param color
   *     7 character string representing the color.
   * @param percent
   *     -1.0 to 1.0
   * @return new shaded color
   * @see #shadeColor(int, double)
   */
  public static int shadeColor(String color, double percent) {
    // based off http://stackoverflow.com/a/13542669/1048340
    long f = Long.parseLong(color.substring(1), 16);
    double t = percent < 0 ? 0 : 255;
    double p = percent < 0 ? percent * -1 : percent;
    long R = f >> 16;
    long G = f >> 8 & 0x00FF;
    long B = f & 0x0000FF;
    int red = (int) (Math.round((t - R) * p) + R);
    int green = (int) (Math.round((t - G) * p) + G);
    int blue = (int) (Math.round((t - B) * p) + B);
    return Color.rgb(red, green, blue);
  }

  private final HashMap<String, Integer> palette = new HashMap<>();

  /**
   * @param primary
   *     the 500 color
   */
  public MaterialColorPalette(int primary) {
    palette.put("50", shadeColor(primary, 0.9));
    palette.put("100", shadeColor(primary, 0.7));
    palette.put("200", shadeColor(primary, 0.5));
    palette.put("300", shadeColor(primary, 0.333));
    palette.put("400", shadeColor(primary, 0.166));
    palette.put("500", primary);
    palette.put("600", shadeColor(primary, -0.125));
    palette.put("700", shadeColor(primary, -0.25));
    palette.put("800", shadeColor(primary, -0.375));
    palette.put("900", shadeColor(primary, -0.5));
    palette.put("A100", shadeColor(primary, 0.7));
    palette.put("A200", shadeColor(primary, 0.5));
    palette.put("A400", shadeColor(primary, 0.166));
    palette.put("A700", shadeColor(primary, -0.25));
  }

  public int getColor(String key) {
    return palette.get(key);
  }

  public void putColor(String key, int color) {
    palette.put(key, color);
  }

}
```

Just copy the class into your project and add the package declaration.

Answer (score 4):

As [Tibox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32656145/4406921) described:

**1. Add the Material Colors to `array.xml`:**

```
<array name="mdcolor_50">
    <item name="red_50" type="color">#fde0dc</item>
    <item name="pink_50" type="color">#fce4ec</item>
    <item name="purple_50" type="color">#f3e5f5</item>
    <item name="deep_purple_50" type="color">#ede7f6</item>
    <item name="indigo_50" type="color">#e8eaf6</item>
    <item name="blue_50" type="color">#e7e9fd</item>
    <item name="light_blue_50" type="color">#e1f5fe</item>
    <item name="cyan_50" type="color">#e0f7fa</item>
    <item name="teal_50" type="color">#e0f2f1</item>
    <item name="green_50" type="color">#d0f8ce</item>
    <item name="light_green_50" type="color">#f1f8e9</item>
    <item name="lime_50" type="color">#f9fbe7</item>
    <item name="yellow_50" type="color">#fffde7</item>
    <item name="amber_50" type="color">#fff8e1</item>
    <item name="orange_50" type="color">#fff3e0</item>
    <item name="deep_orange_50" type="color">#fbe9e7</item>
    <item name="brown_50" type="color">#efebe9</item>
    <item name="grey_50" type="color">#fafafa</item>
    <item name="blue_grey_50" type="color">#eceff1</item>
</array>

<array name="mdcolor_100">
    <item name="red_100" type="color">#f9bdbb</item>
    <item name="pink_100" type="color">#f8bbd0</item>
    <item name="purple_100" type="color">#e1bee7</item>
    <item name="deep_purple_100" type="color">#d1c4e9</item>
    <item name="indigo_100" type="color">#c5cae9</item>
    <item name="blue_100" type="color">#d0d9ff</item>
    <item name="light_blue_100" type="color">#b3e5fc</item>
    <item name="cyan_100" type="color">#b2ebf2</item>
    <item name="teal_100" type="color">#b2dfdb</item>
    <item name="green_100" type="color">#a3e9a4</item>
    <item name="light_green_100" type="color">#dcedc8</item>
    <item name="lime_100" type="color">#f0f4c3</item>
    <item name="yellow_100" type="color">#fff9c4</item>
    <item name="amber_100" type="color">#ffecb3</item>
    <item name="orange_100" type="color">#ffe0b2</item>
    <item name="deep_orange_100" type="color">#ffccbc</item>
    <item name="brown_100" type="color">#d7ccc8</item>
    <item name="grey_100" type="color">#f5f5f5</item>
    <item name="blue_grey_100" type="color">#cfd8dc</item>
</array>

<array name="mdcolor_200">
    <item name="red_200" type="color">#f69988</item>
    <item name="pink_200" type="color">#f48fb1</item>
    <item name="purple_200" type="color">#ce93d8</item>
    <item name="deep_purple_200" type="color">#b39ddb</item>
    <item name="indigo_200" type="color">#9fa8da</item>
    <item name="blue_200" type="color">#afbfff</item>
    <item name="light_blue_200" type="color">#81d4fa</item>
    <item name="cyan_200" type="color">#80deea</item>
    <item name="teal_200" type="color">#80cbc4</item>
    <item name="green_200" type="color">#72d572</item>
    <item name="light_green_200" type="color">#c5e1a5</item>
    <item name="lime_200" type="color">#e6ee9c</item>
    <item name="yellow_200" type="color">#fff59d</item>
    <item name="orange_200" type="color">#ffcc80</item>
    <item name="deep_orange_200" type="color">#ffab91</item>
    <item name="brown_200" type="color">#bcaaa4</item>
    <item name="grey_200" type="color">#eeeeee</item>
    <item name="blue_grey_200" type="color">#b0bec5</item>
</array>

<array name="mdcolor_300">
    <item name="red_300" type="color">#f36c60</item>
    <item name="pink_300" type="color">#f06292</item>
    <item name="purple_300" type="color">#ba68c8</item>
    <item name="deep_purple_300" type="color">#9575cd</item>
    <item name="indigo_300" type="color">#7986cb</item>
    <item name="blue_300" type="color">#91a7ff</item>
    <item name="light_blue_300" type="color">#4fc3f7</item>
    <item name="cyan_300" type="color">#4dd0e1</item>
    <item name="teal_300" type="color">#4db6ac</item>
    <item name="green_300" type="color">#42bd41</item>
    <item name="light_green_300" type="color">#aed581</item>
    <item name="lime_300" type="color">#dce775</item>
    <item name="yellow_300" type="color">#fff176</item>
    <item name="orange_300" type="color">#ffb74d</item>
    <item name="deep_orange_300" type="color">#ff8a65</item>
    <item name="brown_300" type="color">#a1887f</item>
    <item name="grey_300" type="color">#e0e0e0</item>
    <item name="blue_grey_300" type="color">#90a4ae</item>
</array>

<array name="mdcolor_400">
    <item name="red_400" type="color">#e84e40</item>
    <item name="pink_400" type="color">#ec407a</item>
    <item name="purple_400" type="color">#ab47bc</item>
    <item name="deep_purple_400" type="color">#7e57c2</item>
    <item name="indigo_400" type="color">#5c6bc0</item>
    <item name="blue_400" type="color">#738ffe</item>
    <item name="light_blue_400" type="color">#29b6f6</item>
    <item name="cyan_400" type="color">#26c6da</item>
    <item name="teal_400" type="color">#26a69a</item>
    <item name="green_400" type="color">#2baf2b</item>
    <item name="light_green_400" type="color">#9ccc65</item>
    <item name="lime_400" type="color">#d4e157</item>
    <item name="yellow_400" type="color">#ffee58</item>
    <item name="orange_400" type="color">#ffa726</item>
    <item name="deep_orange_400" type="color">#ff7043</item>
    <item name="brown_400" type="color">#8d6e63</item>
    <item name="grey_400" type="color">#bdbdbd</item>
    <item name="blue_grey_400" type="color">#78909c</item>
</array>

<array name="mdcolor_500">
    <item name="red_500" type="color">#e51c23</item>
    <item name="pink_500" type="color">#e91e63</item>
    <item name="purple_500" type="color">#9c27b0</item>
    <item name="deep_purple_500" type="color">#673ab7</item>
    <item name="indigo_500" type="color">#3f51b5</item>
    <item name="blue_500" type="color">#5677fc</item>
    <item name="light_blue_500" type="color">#03a9f4</item>
    <item name="cyan_500" type="color">#00bcd4</item>
    <item name="teal_500" type="color">#009688</item>
    <item name="green_500" type="color">#259b24</item>
    <item name="light_green_500" type="color">#8bc34a</item>
    <item name="lime_500" type="color">#cddc39</item>
    <item name="yellow_500" type="color">#ffeb3b</item>
    <item name="orange_500" type="color">#ff9800</item>
    <item name="deep_orange_500" type="color">#ff5722</item>
    <item name="brown_500" type="color">#795548</item>
    <item name="grey_500" type="color">#9e9e9e</item>
    <item name="blue_grey_500" type="color">#607d8b</item>
</array>

<array name="mdcolor_600">
    <item name="red_600" type="color">#dd191d</item>
    <item name="pink_600" type="color">#d81b60</item>
    <item name="purple_600" type="color">#8e24aa</item>
    <item name="deep_purple_600" type="color">#5e35b1</item>
    <item name="indigo_600" type="color">#3949ab</item>
    <item name="blue_600" type="color">#4e6cef</item>
    <item name="light_blue_600" type="color">#039be5</item>
    <item name="cyan_600" type="color">#00acc1</item>
    <item name="teal_600" type="color">#00897b</item>
    <item name="green_600" type="color">#0a8f08</item>
    <item name="light_green_600" type="color">#7cb342</item>
    <item name="lime_600" type="color">#c0ca33</item>
    <item name="yellow_600" type="color">#fdd835</item>
    <item name="orange_600" type="color">#fb8c00</item>
    <item name="deep_orange_600" type="color">#f4511e</item>
    <item name="brown_600" type="color">#6d4c41</item>
    <item name="grey_600" type="color">#757575</item>
    <item name="blue_grey_600" type="color">#546e7a</item>
</array>

<array name="mdcolor_700">
    <item name="red_700" type="color">#d01716</item>
    <item name="pink_700" type="color">#c2185b</item>
    <item name="purple_700" type="color">#7b1fa2</item>
    <item name="deep_purple_700" type="color">#512da8</item>
    <item name="indigo_700" type="color">#303f9f</item>
    <item name="blue_700" type="color">#455ede</item>
    <item name="light_blue_700" type="color">#0288d1</item>
    <item name="cyan_700" type="color">#0097a7</item>
    <item name="teal_700" type="color">#00796b</item>
    <item name="green_700" type="color">#0a7e07</item>
    <item name="light_green_700" type="color">#689f38</item>
    <item name="lime_700" type="color">#afb42b</item>
    <item name="yellow_700" type="color">#fbc02d</item>
    <item name="orange_700" type="color">#f57c00</item>
    <item name="deep_orange_700" type="color">#e64a19</item>
    <item name="brown_700" type="color">#5d4037</item>
    <item name="grey_700" type="color">#616161</item>
    <item name="blue_grey_700" type="color">#455a64</item>
</array>

<array name="mdcolor_800">
    <item name="red_800" type="color">#c41411</item>
    <item name="pink_800" type="color">#ad1457</item>
    <item name="purple_800" type="color">#6a1b9a</item>
    <item name="deep_purple_800" type="color">#4527a0</item>
    <item name="indigo_800" type="color">#283593</item>
    <item name="blue_800" type="color">#3b50ce</item>
    <item name="light_blue_800" type="color">#0277bd</item>
    <item name="cyan_800" type="color">#00838f</item>
    <item name="teal_800" type="color">#00695c</item>
    <item name="green_800" type="color">#056f00</item>
    <item name="light_green_800" type="color">#558b2f</item>
    <item name="lime_800" type="color">#9e9d24</item>
    <item name="yellow_800" type="color">#f9a825</item>
    <item name="orange_800" type="color">#ef6c00</item>
    <item name="deep_orange_800" type="color">#d84315</item>
    <item name="brown_800" type="color">#4e342e</item>
    <item name="grey_800" type="color">#424242</item>
    <item name="blue_grey_800" type="color">#37474f</item>
</array>

<array name="mdcolor_900">
    <item name="red_900" type="color">#b0120a</item>
    <item name="pink_900" type="color">#880e4f</item>
    <item name="purple_900" type="color">#4a148c</item>
    <item name="deep_purple_900" type="color">#311b92</item>
    <item name="indigo_900" type="color">#1a237e</item>
    <item name="blue_900" type="color">#2a36b1</item>
    <item name="light_blue_900" type="color">#01579b</item>
    <item name="cyan_900" type="color">#006064</item>
    <item name="teal_900" type="color">#004d40</item>
    <item name="green_900" type="color">#0d5302</item>
    <item name="light_green_900" type="color">#33691e</item>
    <item name="lime_900" type="color">#827717</item>
    <item name="yellow_900" type="color">#f57f17</item>
    <item name="orange_900" type="color">#e65100</item>
    <item name="deep_orange_900" type="color">#bf360c</item>
    <item name="brown_900" type="color">#3e2723</item>
    <item name="grey_900" type="color">#212121</item>
    <item name="blue_grey_900" type="color">#263238</item>
</array>

<array name="mdcolor_A100">
    <item name="red_A100" type="color">#ff7997</item>
    <item name="pink_A100" type="color">#ff80ab</item>
    <item name="purple_A100" type="color">#ea80fc</item>
    <item name="deep_purple_A100" type="color">#b388ff</item>
    <item name="indigo_A100" type="color">#8c9eff</item>
    <item name="blue_A100" type="color">#a6baff</item>
    <item name="light_blue_A100" type="color">#80d8ff</item>
    <item name="cyan_A100" type="color">#84ffff</item>
    <item name="teal_A100" type="color">#a7ffeb</item>
    <item name="green_A100" type="color">#a2f78d</item>
    <item name="light_green_A100" type="color">#ccff90</item>
    <item name="lime_A100" type="color">#f4ff81</item>
    <item name="yellow_A100" type="color">#ffff8d</item>
    <item name="orange_A100" type="color">#ffd180</item>
    <item name="deep_orange_A100" type="color">#ff9e80</item>
</array>

<array name="mdcolor_A200">
    <item name="red_A200" type="color">#ff5177</item>
    <item name="pink_A200" type="color">#ff4081</item>
    <item name="purple_A200" type="color">#e040fb</item>
    <item name="deep_purple_A200" type="color">#7c4dff</item>
    <item name="indigo_A200" type="color">#536dfe</item>
    <item name="blue_A200" type="color">#6889ff</item>
    <item name="light_blue_A200" type="color">#40c4ff</item>
    <item name="cyan_A200" type="color">#18ffff</item>
    <item name="teal_A200" type="color">#64ffda</item>
    <item name="green_A200" type="color">#5af158</item>
    <item name="light_green_A200" type="color">#b2ff59</item>
    <item name="lime_A200" type="color">#eeff41</item>
    <item name="yellow_A200" type="color">#ffff00</item>
    <item name="orange_A200" type="color">#ffab40</item>
    <item name="deep_orange_A200" type="color">#ff6e40</item>
</array>

<array name="mdcolor_A400">
    <item name="red_A400" type="color">#ff2d6f</item>
    <item name="pink_A400" type="color">#f50057</item>
    <item name="purple_A400" type="color">#d500f9</item>
    <item name="deep_purple_A400" type="color">#651fff</item>
    <item name="indigo_A400" type="color">#3d5afe</item>
    <item name="blue_A400" type="color">#4d73ff</item>
    <item name="light_blue_A400" type="color">#00b0ff</item>
    <item name="cyan_A400" type="color">#00e5ff</item>
    <item name="teal_A400" type="color">#1de9b6</item>
    <item name="green_A400" type="color">#14e715</item>
    <item name="light_green_A400" type="color">#76ff03</item>
    <item name="lime_A400" type="color">#c6ff00</item>
    <item name="yellow_A400" type="color">#ffea00</item>
    <item name="orange_A400" type="color">#ff9100</item>
    <item name="deep_orange_A400" type="color">#ff3d00</item>
</array>

<array name="mdcolor_A700">
    <item name="red_A700" type="color">#e00032</item>
    <item name="pink_A700" type="color">#c51162</item>
    <item name="purple_A700" type="color">#aa00ff</item>
    <item name="deep_purple_A700" type="color">#6200ea</item>
    <item name="indigo_A700" type="color">#304ffe</item>
    <item name="blue_A700" type="color">#4d69ff</item>
    <item name="light_blue_A700" type="color">#0091ea</item>
    <item name="cyan_A700" type="color">#00b8d4</item>
    <item name="teal_A700" type="color">#00bfa5</item>
    <item name="green_A700" type="color">#12c700</item>
    <item name="light_green_A700" type="color">#64dd17</item>
    <item name="lime_A700" type="color">#aeea00</item>
    <item name="yellow_A700" type="color">#ffd600</item>
    <item name="orange_A700" type="color">#ff6d00</item>
    <item name="deep_orange_A700" type="color">#dd2c00</item>
</array>

<array name="extra">
    <item name="grey_1000b" type="color">#000000</item>
    <item name="grey_1000w" type="color">#ffffff</item>
</array>
```

**2. Add `getMDcolor()` to your class:**

```
private int getMDcolor(String mdcolor) {
    int returnColor = 0;
    String[] mdcolors = new String[]{
            "mdcolor_50",
            "mdcolor_100",
            "mdcolor_200",
            "mdcolor_300",
            "mdcolor_400",
            "mdcolor_500",
            "mdcolor_600",
            "mdcolor_700",
            "mdcolor_800",
            "mdcolor_900",
            "mdcolor_A100",
            "mdcolor_A200",
            "mdcolor_A400",
            "mdcolor_A700",
            "extras"};
    if (Arrays.asList(mdcolors).contains(mdcolor)) {
        TypedArray colors = null;
        switch (mdcolor) {
            case "mdcolor_50":
                colors = mContext.getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.mdcolor_50);
                break;

            case "mdcolors_100":
                colors = mContext.getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.mdcolor_100);
                break;

            case "mdcolor_200":
                colors = mContext.getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.mdcolor_200);
                break;

            case "mdcolor_300":
                colors = mContext.getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.mdcolor_300);
                break;

            case "mdcolor_400":
                colors = mContext.getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.mdcolor_400);
                break;

            case "mdcolor_500":
                colors = mContext.getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.mdcolor_500);
                break;

            case "mdcolor_600":
                colors = mContext.getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.mdcolor_600);
                break;

            case "mdcolor_700":
                colors = mContext.getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.mdcolor_700);
                break;

            case "mdcolor_800":
                colors = mContext.getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.mdcolor_800);
                break;

            case "mdcolor_900":
                colors = mContext.getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.mdcolor_900);
                break;

            case "mdcolor_A100":
                colors = mContext.getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.mdcolor_A100);
                break;

            case "mdcolor_A200":
                colors = mContext.getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.mdcolor_A200);
                break;

            case "mdcolor_A400":
                colors = mContext.getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.mdcolor_A400);
                break;

            case "mdcolor_A700":
                colors = mContext.getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.mdcolor_A700);
                break;

            case "extra":
                colors = mContext.getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.extra);
                break;
        }
        if (colors != null) {
            int index = (int) (Math.random() * colors.length());
            returnColor = colors.getColor(index, Color.BLACK);
        }
        assert colors != null;
        colors.recycle();
    }
    return returnColor;
```

**3. Usage:**

- Get a color by: `getMDcolor("<md color id>")`
- Available colors:
  `mdcolor_50`
  `mdcolor_100`
  `mdcolor_200`
  `mdcolor_300`
  `mdcolor_400`
  `mdcolor_500`
  `mdcolor_600`
  `mdcolor_700`
  `mdcolor_800`
  `mdcolor_900`
  `mdcolor_A100`
  `mdcolor_A200`
  `mdcolor_A400`
  `mdcolor_A700`
  `extras`