# Puzzle - Sort text?

Tags: java, xml, sorting

It's kind of hard to find a suitable title for this question. Edits are welcome! :)

---

That is my source `xml` code:

```
<resources>
    <array name="md_colors">
        <item name="[color1]_50" type="color">[color hex]</item>
        <item name="[color1]_100" type="color">[color hex]</item>
        <item name="[color1]_200" type="color">[color hex]</item>
        <item name="[color1]_300" type="color">[color hex]</item>
        ...
        <item name="[color1]_900" type="color">[color hex]</item>

        <item name="[color1]_A100" type="color">[color hex]</item>
        <item name="[color1]_A200" type="color">[color hex]</item>
        <item name="[color1]_A400" type="color">[color hex]</item>
        <item name="[color1]_A700" type="color">[color hex]</item>


        <item name="[color2]_50" type="color">[color hex]</item>
        <item name="[color2]_100" type="color">[color hex]</item>
        <item name="[color2]_200" type="color">[color hex]</item>
        <item name="[color2]_300" type="color">[color hex]</item>
        ...
        <item name="[color2]_900" type="color">[color hex]</item>

        <item name="[color2]_A100" type="color">[color hex]</item>
        <item name="[color2]_A200" type="color">[color hex]</item>
        <item name="[color2]_A400" type="color">[color hex]</item>
        <item name="[color2]_A700" type="color">[color hex]</item>


        <item name="[color3]_50" type="color">[color hex]</item>
        ...
        <item name="[color20]_A700" type="color">[color hex]</item>
    </array>
<resources>
```

And this how it has to be sorted:

```
<resources>
    <array name="mdcolors_50">
        <item name="[color1]_50" type="color">[color hex]</item>
        <item name="[color2]_50" type="color">[color hex]</item>
        ...
        <item name="[color20]_50" type="color">[color hex]</item>
    </array>

    <array name="mdcolors_100">
        <item name="[color1]_100" type="color">[color hex]</item>
        <item name="[color2]_100" type="color">[color hex]</item>
        ...
        <item name="[color20]_100" type="color">[color hex]</item>
    </array>

    <array name="mdcolors_200">
        <item name="[color1]_200" type="color">[color hex]</item>
        <item name="[color2]_200" type="color">[color hex]</item>
        ...
        <item name="[color20]_200" type="color">[color hex]</item>
    </array>
    ...

    <array name="mdcolors_A100">
        <item name="[color1]_A100" type="color">[color hex]</item>
        <item name="[color2]_A100" type="color">[color hex]</item>
        ...
    </array>

    <array name="mdcolors_A200">
        <item name="[color1]_A200" type="color">[color hex]</item>
        <item name="[color2]_A200" type="color">[color hex]</item>
        ...
        <item name="[color20]_A200" type="color">[color hex]</item>
    </array>

    <array name="mdcolors_A400">
        <item name="[color1]_A400" type="color">[color hex]</item>
        <item name="[color2]_A400" type="color">[color hex]</item>
        ...
        <item name="[color20]_A400" type="color">[color hex]</item>
    </array>

    <array name="mdcolors_A700">
        <item name="[color1]_A700" type="color">[color hex]</item>
        <item name="[color2]_A700" type="color">[color hex]</item>
        ...
        <item name="[color20]_A700" type="color">[color hex]</item>
    </array>
<resources>
```

Now is my question how to sort the source file to receive the above sorting?

**Important:**

- Numeric order isn't `50`, `100`, `150`, `200`..
  It's `50`, `100`, `200`, .. `900`, `A100`, `A200`, `A400`, `A700`
- Every number needs to be placed in a new `<array name="mdcolor_[color???]" />`
- I only can program in `java`. I also **understand** `html/js/php`, but could use it for a tool.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs.

Comment: @SandeepChatterjee my thought was to do it by hand xD I know it possible to write a tiny program for this but I have no idea, that's why I'm asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Linux tools to sort your array file, but you will have to edit it in sections afterwards.

```
cut -d'"' -f2  array.xml  | rev  | cut -d'_' -f1 | rev | sort | uniq |  xargs -I{} grep _{}\" array.xml
```

The output will be :

```
    <item name="red_100" type="color">#f9bdbb</item>
    <item name="pink_100" type="color">#f8bbd0</item>
    <item name="purple_100" type="color">#e1bee7</item>
    <item name="deep_purple_100" type="color">#d1c4e9</item>
    <item name="indigo_100" type="color">#c5cae9</item>
    <item name="blue_100" type="color">#d0d9ff</item>
    <item name="light_blue_100" type="color">#b3e5fc</item>
    <item name="cyan_100" type="color">#b2ebf2</item>
    <item name="teal_100" type="color">#b2dfdb</item>
    <item name="green_100" type="color">#a3e9a4</item>
    <item name="light_green_100" type="color">#dcedc8</item>
    <item name="lime_100" type="color">#f0f4c3</item>
    <item name="yellow_100" type="color">#fff9c4</item>
    <item name="amber_100" type="color">#ffecb3</item>
    <item name="orange_100" type="color">#ffe0b2</item>
    <item name="deep_orange_100" type="color">#ffccbc</item>
    <item name="brown_100" type="color">#d7ccc8</item>
    <item name="grey_100" type="color">#f5f5f5</item>
    <item name="blue_grey_100" type="color">#cfd8dc</item>
    <item name="grey_1000b" type="color">#000000</item>
    <item name="grey_1000w" type="color">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="red_200" type="color">#f69988</item>
    <item name="pink_200" type="color">#f48fb1</item>
    <item name="purple_200" type="color">#ce93d8</item>
    <item name="deep_purple_200" type="color">#b39ddb</item>
    <item name="indigo_200" type="color">#9fa8da</item>
    <item name="blue_200" type="color">#afbfff</item>
    <item name="light_blue_200" type="color">#81d4fa</item>
    <item name="cyan_200" type="color">#80deea</item>
    <item name="teal_200" type="color">#80cbc4</item>
    <item name="green_200" type="color">#72d572</item>
    <item name="light_green_200" type="color">#c5e1a5</item>
    <item name="lime_200" type="color">#e6ee9c</item>
    <item name="yellow_200" type="color">#fff59d</item>
    <item name="amber_200" type="color">#ffe082</item>
    <item name="orange_200" type="color">#ffcc80</item>
    <item name="deep_orange_200" type="color">#ffab91</item>
    <item name="brown_200" type="color">#bcaaa4</item>
    <item name="grey_200" type="color">#eeeeee</item>
    <item name="blue_grey_200" type="color">#b0bec5</item>
    <item name="red_300" type="color">#f36c60</item>
    <item name="pink_300" type="color">#f06292</item>
    <item name="purple_300" type="color">#ba68c8</item>
    <item name="deep_purple_300" type="color">#9575cd</item>
    <item name="indigo_300" type="color">#7986cb</item>
    <item name="blue_300" type="color">#91a7ff</item>
    <item name="light_blue_300" type="color">#4fc3f7</item>
    <item name="cyan_300" type="color">#4dd0e1</item>
    <item name="teal_300" type="color">#4db6ac</item>
    <item name="green_300" type="color">#42bd41</item>
    <item name="light_green_300" type="color">#aed581</item>
    <item name="lime_300" type="color">#dce775</item>
    <item name="yellow_300" type="color">#fff176</item>
    <item name="amber_300" type="color">#ffd54f</item>
    <item name="orange_300" type="color">#ffb74d</item>
    <item name="deep_orange_300" type="color">#ff8a65</item>
    <item name="brown_300" type="color">#a1887f</item>
    <item name="grey_300" type="color">#e0e0e0</item>
    <item name="blue_grey_300" type="color">#90a4ae</item>
    <item name="red_400" type="color">#e84e40</item>
    <item name="pink_400" type="color">#ec407a</item>
    <item name="purple_400" type="color">#ab47bc</item>
    <item name="deep_purple_400" type="color">#7e57c2</item>
    <item name="indigo_400" type="color">#5c6bc0</item>
    <item name="blue_400" type="color">#738ffe</item>
    <item name="light_blue_400" type="color">#29b6f6</item>
    <item name="cyan_400" type="color">#26c6da</item>
    <item name="teal_400" type="color">#26a69a</item>
    <item name="green_400" type="color">#2baf2b</item>
    <item name="light_green_400" type="color">#9ccc65</item>
    <item name="lime_400" type="color">#d4e157</item>
    <item name="yellow_400" type="color">#ffee58</item>
    <item name="amber_400" type="color">#ffca28</item>
    <item name="orange_400" type="color">#ffa726</item>
    <item name="deep_orange_400" type="color">#ff7043</item>
    <item name="brown_400" type="color">#8d6e63</item>
    <item name="grey_400" type="color">#bdbdbd</item>
    <item name="blue_grey_400" type="color">#78909c</item>
    <item name="red_50" type="color">#fde0dc</item>
    <item name="pink_50" type="color">#fce4ec</item>
    <item name="purple_50" type="color">#f3e5f5</item>
    <item name="deep_purple_50" type="color">#ede7f6</item>
    <item name="indigo_50" type="color">#e8eaf6</item>
    <item name="blue_50" type="color">#e7e9fd</item>
    <item name="light_blue_50" type="color">#e1f5fe</item>
    <item name="cyan_50" type="color">#e0f7fa</item>
    <item name="teal_50" type="color">#e0f2f1</item>
    <item name="green_50" type="color">#d0f8ce</item>
    <item name="light_green_50" type="color">#f1f8e9</item>
    <item name="lime_50" type="color">#f9fbe7</item>
    <item name="yellow_50" type="color">#fffde7</item>
    <item name="amber_50" type="color">#fff8e1</item>
    <item name="orange_50" type="color">#fff3e0</item>
    <item name="deep_orange_50" type="color">#fbe9e7</item>
    <item name="brown_50" type="color">#efebe9</item>
    <item name="grey_50" type="color">#fafafa</item>
    <item name="blue_grey_50" type="color">#eceff1</item>
    <item name="red_500" type="color">#e51c23</item>
    <item name="pink_500" type="color">#e91e63</item>
    <item name="purple_500" type="color">#9c27b0</item>
    <item name="deep_purple_500" type="color">#673ab7</item>
    <item name="indigo_500" type="color">#3f51b5</item>
    <item name="blue_500" type="color">#5677fc</item>
    <item name="light_blue_500" type="color">#03a9f4</item>
    <item name="cyan_500" type="color">#00bcd4</item>
    <item name="teal_500" type="color">#009688</item>
    <item name="green_500" type="color">#259b24</item>
    <item name="light_green_500" type="color">#8bc34a</item>
    <item name="lime_500" type="color">#cddc39</item>
    <item name="yellow_500" type="color">#ffeb3b</item>
    <item name="amber_500" type="color">#ffc107</item>
    <item name="orange_500" type="color">#ff9800</item>
    <item name="deep_orange_500" type="color">#ff5722</item>
    <item name="brown_500" type="color">#795548</item>
    <item name="grey_500" type="color">#9e9e9e</item>
    <item name="blue_grey_500" type="color">#607d8b</item>
    <item name="red_600" type="color">#dd191d</item>
    <item name="pink_600" type="color">#d81b60</item>
    <item name="purple_600" type="color">#8e24aa</item>
    <item name="deep_purple_600" type="color">#5e35b1</item>
    <item name="indigo_600" type="color">#3949ab</item>
    <item name="blue_600" type="color">#4e6cef</item>
    <item name="light_blue_600" type="color">#039be5</item>
    <item name="cyan_600" type="color">#00acc1</item>
    <item name="teal_600" type="color">#00897b</item>
    <item name="green_600" type="color">#0a8f08</item>
    <item name="light_green_600" type="color">#7cb342</item>
    <item name="lime_600" type="color">#c0ca33</item>
    <item name="yellow_600" type="color">#fdd835</item>
    <item name="amber_600" type="color">#ffb300</item>
    <item name="orange_600" type="color">#fb8c00</item>
    <item name="deep_orange_600" type="color">#f4511e</item>
    <item name="brown_600" type="color">#6d4c41</item>
    <item name="grey_600" type="color">#757575</item>
    <item name="blue_grey_600" type="color">#546e7a</item>
    <item name="red_700" type="color">#d01716</item>
    <item name="pink_700" type="color">#c2185b</item>
    <item name="purple_700" type="color">#7b1fa2</item>
    <item name="deep_purple_700" type="color">#512da8</item>
    <item name="indigo_700" type="color">#303f9f</item>
    <item name="blue_700" type="color">#455ede</item>
    <item name="light_blue_700" type="color">#0288d1</item>
    <item name="cyan_700" type="color">#0097a7</item>
    <item name="teal_700" type="color">#00796b</item>
    <item name="green_700" type="color">#0a7e07</item>
    <item name="light_green_700" type="color">#689f38</item>
    <item name="lime_700" type="color">#afb42b</item>
    <item name="yellow_700" type="color">#fbc02d</item>
    <item name="amber_700" type="color">#ffa000</item>
    <item name="orange_700" type="color">#f57c00</item>
    <item name="deep_orange_700" type="color">#e64a19</item>
    <item name="brown_700" type="color">#5d4037</item>
    <item name="grey_700" type="color">#616161</item>
    <item name="blue_grey_700" type="color">#455a64</item>
    <item name="red_800" type="color">#c41411</item>
    <item name="pink_800" type="color">#ad1457</item>
    <item name="purple_800" type="color">#6a1b9a</item>
    <item name="deep_purple_800" type="color">#4527a0</item>
    <item name="indigo_800" type="color">#283593</item>
    <item name="blue_800" type="color">#3b50ce</item>
    <item name="light_blue_800" type="color">#0277bd</item>
    <item name="cyan_800" type="color">#00838f</item>
    <item name="teal_800" type="color">#00695c</item>
    <item name="green_800" type="color">#056f00</item>
    <item name="light_green_800" type="color">#558b2f</item>
    <item name="lime_800" type="color">#9e9d24</item>
    <item name="yellow_800" type="color">#f9a825</item>
    <item name="amber_800" type="color">#ff8f00</item>
    <item name="orange_800" type="color">#ef6c00</item>
    <item name="deep_orange_800" type="color">#d84315</item>
    <item name="brown_800" type="color">#4e342e</item>
    <item name="grey_800" type="color">#424242</item>
    <item name="blue_grey_800" type="color">#37474f</item>
    <item name="red_900" type="color">#b0120a</item>
    <item name="pink_900" type="color">#880e4f</item>
    <item name="purple_900" type="color">#4a148c</item>
    <item name="deep_purple_900" type="color">#311b92</item>
    <item name="indigo_900" type="color">#1a237e</item>
    <item name="blue_900" type="color">#2a36b1</item>
    <item name="light_blue_900" type="color">#01579b</item>
    <item name="cyan_900" type="color">#006064</item>
    <item name="teal_900" type="color">#004d40</item>
    <item name="green_900" type="color">#0d5302</item>
    <item name="light_green_900" type="color">#33691e</item>
    <item name="lime_900" type="color">#827717</item>
    <item name="yellow_900" type="color">#f57f17</item>
    <item name="amber_900" type="color">#ff6f00</item>
    <item name="orange_900" type="color">#e65100</item>
    <item name="deep_orange_900" type="color">#bf360c</item>
    <item name="brown_900" type="color">#3e2723</item>
    <item name="grey_900" type="color">#212121</item>
    <item name="blue_grey_900" type="color">#263238</item>
    <item name="red_A100" type="color">#ff7997</item>
    <item name="pink_A100" type="color">#ff80ab</item>
    <item name="purple_A100" type="color">#ea80fc</item>
    <item name="deep_purple_A100" type="color">#b388ff</item>
    <item name="indigo_A100" type="color">#8c9eff</item>
    <item name="blue_A100" type="color">#a6baff</item>
    <item name="light_blue_A100" type="color">#80d8ff</item>
    <item name="cyan_A100" type="color">#84ffff</item>
    <item name="teal_A100" type="color">#a7ffeb</item>
    <item name="green_A100" type="color">#a2f78d</item>
    <item name="light_green_A100" type="color">#ccff90</item>
    <item name="lime_A100" type="color">#f4ff81</item>
    <item name="yellow_A100" type="color">#ffff8d</item>
    <item name="amber_A100" type="color">#ffe57f</item>
    <item name="orange_A100" type="color">#ffd180</item>
    <item name="deep_orange_A100" type="color">#ff9e80</item>
    <item name="red_A200" type="color">#ff5177</item>
    <item name="pink_A200" type="color">#ff4081</item>
    <item name="purple_A200" type="color">#e040fb</item>
    <item name="deep_purple_A200" type="color">#7c4dff</item>
    <item name="indigo_A200" type="color">#536dfe</item>
    <item name="blue_A200" type="color">#6889ff</item>
    <item name="light_blue_A200" type="color">#40c4ff</item>
    <item name="cyan_A200" type="color">#18ffff</item>
    <item name="teal_A200" type="color">#64ffda</item>
    <item name="green_A200" type="color">#5af158</item>
    <item name="light_green_A200" type="color">#b2ff59</item>
    <item name="lime_A200" type="color">#eeff41</item>
    <item name="yellow_A200" type="color">#ffff00</item>
    <item name="amber_A200" type="color">#ffd740</item>
    <item name="orange_A200" type="color">#ffab40</item>
    <item name="deep_orange_A200" type="color">#ff6e40</item>
    <item name="red_A400" type="color">#ff2d6f</item>
    <item name="pink_A400" type="color">#f50057</item>
    <item name="purple_A400" type="color">#d500f9</item>
    <item name="deep_purple_A400" type="color">#651fff</item>
    <item name="indigo_A400" type="color">#3d5afe</item>
    <item name="blue_A400" type="color">#4d73ff</item>
    <item name="light_blue_A400" type="color">#00b0ff</item>
    <item name="cyan_A400" type="color">#00e5ff</item>
    <item name="teal_A400" type="color">#1de9b6</item>
    <item name="green_A400" type="color">#14e715</item>
    <item name="light_green_A400" type="color">#76ff03</item>
    <item name="lime_A400" type="color">#c6ff00</item>
    <item name="yellow_A400" type="color">#ffea00</item>
    <item name="amber_A400" type="color">#ffc400</item>
    <item name="orange_A400" type="color">#ff9100</item>
    <item name="deep_orange_A400" type="color">#ff3d00</item>
    <item name="red_A700" type="color">#e00032</item>
    <item name="pink_A700" type="color">#c51162</item>
    <item name="purple_A700" type="color">#aa00ff</item>
    <item name="deep_purple_A700" type="color">#6200ea</item>
    <item name="indigo_A700" type="color">#304ffe</item>
    <item name="blue_A700" type="color">#4d69ff</item>
    <item name="light_blue_A700" type="color">#0091ea</item>
    <item name="cyan_A700" type="color">#00b8d4</item>
    <item name="teal_A700" type="color">#00bfa5</item>
    <item name="green_A700" type="color">#12c700</item>
    <item name="light_green_A700" type="color">#64dd17</item>
    <item name="lime_A700" type="color">#aeea00</item>
    <item name="yellow_A700" type="color">#ffd600</item>
    <item name="amber_A700" type="color">#ffab00</item>
    <item name="orange_A700" type="color">#ff6d00</item>
    <item name="deep_orange_A700" type="color">#dd2c00</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want  go ahead and have a go using Java, if you only need the data in the new XML format ie. no need to have the data hanging around as Java objects for any reason, then I would probably:-

1. Parse the input XML (use a DOM parser if the input file is always going to be less than a couple of hundred lines, or a SAX parser otherwise - for performance)
2. As you parse the XML - use a Regex to inspect the _XXX sub-string and group each in a sorted collection
3. Iterate the collection and use the output to create the output file

Proof of concept:-

```
    ArrayList<String> group_100 = new ArrayList<>();
    group_100.add("[color1]_100");
    group_100.add("[color2]_100");
    Collections.sort(group_100);

    ArrayList<String> group_A100 = new ArrayList<>();
    group_A100.add("[color1]_A100");
    group_A100.add("[color2]_A100");
    Collections.sort(group_A100);

    TreeMap<String, ArrayList<String>> colorMap = new TreeMap<>();
    colorMap.put("mdcolors_A100", group_A100);
    colorMap.put("mdcolors_100", group_100);

    // Do some preliminary File stuff

    // Write opening <resources> element

    for(Map.Entry<String,ArrayList<String>> entry : colorMap.entrySet()) {
      String arrayName = entry.getKey();

      // Write opening "<array name=" + arrayName + "> element to file 

      ArrayList<String> nameList = entry.getValue();            
      for(String itemName : nameList)
          System.out.println(arrayName + " => " + itemName);
        // Write <item element using itemName

      // Write closing </array> element to file  
    }
```

Based on your example files, the natural sort order of Strings holds good for the ArrayList and TreeMap but if your data is just a sample then you need to check if the natural sort order of Strings works. If not you need to look into possibly creating some value objects for the `<array>` and `<item>` elements and use Comparable or Comparator(s) to implement any custom sorting required.

Answer (score 0):

XSLT is much easier for this kind of thing than Java. In XSLT 2.0 it's essentially:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="item" 
                    group-by="substring-after(@name, '_')">
  <xsl:sort select="replace(current-grouping-key(), '[0-9]', '')"/>
  <xsl:sort select="number(replace(current-grouping-key(), '[A-Z]', '')"/>
  <array name="mdcolors_{current-grouping-key()}"> 
    <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
  </array>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

Comment: Yeah, but... it's XSLT :(

Comment: There will always be people who prefer writing 100 lines of Java to 10 lines of XSLT, but I still like to show them that there are better ways of doing things.