# Where does material design get the 50 - 900 color schemes?

Tags: material-design

In this material design color example by Google http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html, where did they come up with the number scheme that goes from 50 to 900 in the swatches?

Comment: It looks to me as if the numbers represent a combination of saturation and value numbers. There's RGB color notation that we all know and then there's [HSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV). The material color palette numbers seem to be using a combination of the S and V numbers just simplified for the common folk

Comment: It was discussed before here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32942503/material-design-color-palette