# Calculating Material Colors

Tags: android, colors, material-design

I'm working on an Android app that has a built in UI customizer. The UI customizer allows the user to change different colors throughout the app, such as the toolbar / actionbar color.

With Google Material Design specifications, if you have a color on [this pallete](https://material.io/guidelines/style/color.html#color-color-palette) as your toolbar / actionbar color, then the color two rows down from it should be the status bar color (for devices that support it).

For example, if you select color `#3F51B5` under the Indigo category, then color `#303F9F` should be the status bar color.

So the color picker I used takes a default value in the form of the colors above (`#303F9F`), however, the color picker returns a value in integer form.

For color `#3F51B5`, it's equivalent integer value is `-12627531` and
color `#303F9F`'s equivalent integer value is `-13615201`.

Essentially, I want my app to let the user choose the primary color, and have it's darker complement color automatically generated. I tried subtracting `987670` from the first color to get the second color, but it only works for the colors I specified, not any color.

How do I go about auto generating a color that is two shades darker? I'm not sure if this needs to be accounted for, but maybe the method could also detect if it's a color from the color palette link above or just a random color, and if it's from the color palette then I could hard code in all the values (not really desired solution) and random color could just use some pseudo-code to produce a darker shade.

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Material design color palette](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32942503/material-design-color-palette)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following method to get a darker primary color:

```
/**
 * Darkens a color by a given factor.
 *
 * @param color
 *     the color to darken
 * @param factor
 *     The factor to darken the color.
 * @return darker version of specified color.
 */
@ColorInt public static int darker(@ColorInt int color, @FloatRange(from = 0.0, to = 1.0) float factor) {
  return Color.argb(Color.alpha(color), 
      Math.max((int) (Color.red(color) * factor), 0),
      Math.max((int) (Color.green(color) * factor), 0),
      Math.max((int) (Color.blue(color) * factor), 0)
  );
}
```

Example:

```
int primaryDark = darker(primaryColor, 0.85f);
```