# How to get Material color swatches with Jetpack Compose Color?

Tags: android, material-design, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

Is there a way to get Material Color swatches with Jetpack Compose Colors?

[image]

Created Material 500 colors manually using this [website](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/color/), and this [material color picker site](https://materialui.co/colors/).

```
val Red500 = Color(0xfff44336)
val Pink500 = Color(0xffe91e63)
val Purple500 = Color(0xff9c27b0)
val DeepPurple500 = Color(0xff673ab7)
val Indigo500 = Color(0xff3f51b5)
val Blue500 = Color(0xff2196f3)
val LightBlue500 = Color(0xff03a9f4)
val Cyan500 = Color(0xff00bcd4)
val Teal500 = Color(0xff009688)
val Green500 = Color(0xff4caf50)
val LightGreen500 = Color(0xff8bc34a)
val Lime500 = Color(0xffcddc39)
val Yellow500 = Color(0xffffeb3b)
val Amber500 = Color(0xffffc107)
val Orange500 = Color(0xffff9800)
val DeepOrange500 = Color(0xffff5722)
val Brown500 = Color(0xff795548)
val Grey500 = Color(0xff9e9e9e)
```

And based on this this [article for Flutter](https://medium.com/@nickysong/creating-a-custom-color-swatch-in-flutter-554bcdcb27f3) i converted the function from Dart to Kotlin

```
fun createMaterialSwatch(color: Color): Map<Int, Color> {

    val colorSwatch = linkedMapOf<Int, Color>()

    val variants = mutableListOf(.05)
    for (i in 1 until 10) {
        variants.add(0.1 * i)
    }

    val red: Int = color.red.fractionToRGBRange()
    val green: Int = color.green.fractionToRGBRange()
    val blue: Int = color.blue.fractionToRGBRange()

    for (variant in variants) {
        val ds: Double = 0.5 - variant
        val newRed: Int = red + ((if (ds < 0) red else 255 - red) * ds).roundToInt()
        val newGreen: Int = green + ((if (ds < 0) green else 255 - green) * ds).roundToInt()
        val newBlue: Int = blue + ((if (ds < 0) blue else 255 - blue) * ds).roundToInt()

        colorSwatch[(variant * 1000).roundToInt()] = Color(newRed, newGreen, newBlue)
    }

    return colorSwatch
}


fun Float.fractionToRGBRange() = (this * 255.0f).toInt()
```

But it doesn't return the correct colors, is there a buil-in function to get swatches like in Flutter or can anyone point me what's wrong with the function above?

What i get is on the left, what it should be is on the right

[image]
[image]

Also is there a way to create accent colors A100, A200, A400, A700?

Comment: Have you tried this site? You can download your theme for Compose, including accents etc: https://material-foundation.github.io/material-theme-builder/#/custom

Comment: @CodePoet It's very cool to create Material Design 3 colors as in that site but what i need is Material Design 2 material color swatches which contain 10 shades based of Color500 of that swatch.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no Compose counterpart available i had to do this by hand as

```
  val red by lazy {
    linkedMapOf(
        50 to Color(0xffFFEBEE),
        100 to Color(0xffFFCDD2),
        200 to Color(0xffEF9A9A),
        300 to Color(0xffE57373),
        400 to Color(0xffEF5350),
        500 to Color(0xffF44336),
        600 to Color(0xffE53935),
        700 to Color(0xffD32F2F),
        800 to Color(0xffC62828),
        900 to Color(0xffB71C1C)
    )
}
```

for each material color and

```
val primaryHeaderColors by lazy {
    listOf(
        Color(0xffF44336),
        Color(0xffE91E63),
        Color(0xff9C27B0),
        Color(0xff673AB7),
        Color(0xff3F51B5),
        Color(0xff2196F3),
        Color(0xff03A9F4),
        Color(0xff00BCD4),
        Color(0xff00ACC1),
        Color(0xff4CAF50),
        Color(0xff8BC34A),
        Color(0xffCDDC39),
        Color(0xffFFEB3B),
        Color(0xffFFC107),
        Color(0xffFF9800),
        Color(0xffFF5722),
        Color(0xff795548),
        Color(0xff9E9E9E),
        Color(0xff607D8B)
    )
}
```

and made it into a [library](https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Compose-Extended-Colors) for anyone interested.