# Generate color array based on given reference color

Tags: vbscript, colors, asp-classic

I have an array that needs to be fed with hex (or RGB) color codes. Could someone help with a code that would take a reference color (like green) and generate shades of that reference color.

I have found some color manipulation code in JavaScript but coudn´t find in VBScript.

Edit.
To clarify, I don´t want code for feeding array or convert hex to rgb or anything like that. I just don´t know the math behind the colors, so I´m unable to take a color and generate derivated colors from it. Code or just logic help is welcome.

Comment: Help: certainly. Write it for you: certainly not.

Comment: Help or Code would be welcome, although I have helped people with codes before when it comes to something that is very specific or has been or goes beyond simple teaching. Thanks for the obvious answer.

Comment: I have found this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5560248/programmatically-lighten-or-darken-a-hex-color-or-rgb-and-blend-colors)
It´s in JS but It´s kind of complex to translate to VBscript, I´m searching for simpler workarounds in JS and going to try to translate to VBscript.

Answer (score 2):

RGB color descriptions consist of 3 values for the 3 primary colors red, green, and blue. Each value is usually represented as one byte, so its value can range from 0 to 255 (decimal) or 00 to FF (hexadecimal) respectively. Lower values represent darker, higher values brighter colors.

A value `RGB(255, 255, 0)` represents the same color as the hexadecimal value `#FFFF00`: a bright yellow. `RGB(0, 0, 0)` (`#000000`) is black, `RGB(255, 255, 255)` (`#FFFFFF`) is white.

See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_model) for more information about the RGB color model.

In VBScript you'll normally use the [`RGB`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/676k6dt6) function when working with colors. If you need a hexadecimal representation you can convert decimal values to hex with the [`Hex`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8t2d9cx5) function.

To get a feel for how the primary colors play together try playing around with a color picker. There are various available online (for instance [here](http://www.colorpicker.com/) and [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_colorpicker.asp)).

Comment: Yes, I have tried something with that already and works fine if I have only three colors(red, green, blue), the problem comes when I have colors like Brown or Purple, I failed to generate shades of them because I don´t know when to increase/decrease each channel to achieve the desired derivated color.

Comment: I found this jsbin [link](http://jsbin.com/oqaza4/2/edit?html,js,output) I think I can work something out of that. The logic is pretty simple actually. Thanks for the help, I´ll post the vbscript code here in case someone needs something similar.