# Is there a formula for computing the corresponding muted/faded ("highlight") color for a given hex-valued color?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, colors, chart.js

I found [this code](http://codepedia.info/editor-example/create-pie-chart-using-html5-canvas-in-jquery-example/) for use in Chart.js:

```
var data = [{
    value: 300,
    color: "#F7464A",
    highlight: "#FF5A5E",
    label: "Strawberry"
}, {
    value: 50,
    color: "#46BFBD",
    highlight: "#5AD3D1",
    label: "Lettuce"
}, {
    value: 100,
    color: "#FDB45C",
    highlight: "#FFC870",
    label: "Melon"
}];
```

The "highlight" color seems basically like a version of the original color with a generous shovelful of glacial silt added. Is there a formula I can use to create similar corresponding highlights to any color I might use (hex value)? Either in javascript, or even in C#, where I could determine the highlight colors beforehand and then add them manually? Something like:

```
function string getHighlightColorForBaseColor(string hexColor)
{
    // Perform some color-theory wizardry and pass back the highlight color
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5560248/1070452  maybe?

Comment: That data structure appears to be for an [older version](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/v1.1.1/docs/05-Pie-Doughnut-Chart.md). But to your question: the values in your post are hardcoded, you don't know if someone used an algorithm to calculate it (that you could duplicate), or if they just typed it in manually to what looks good to them. The doc I linked says, "If you don't specify a color and highliht, one will be chosen from the global default array", so even the default isn't calculated, it's hard coded.

Comment: @Quantic: I just installed Chart.JS, and it works with it, so if the data structure is for an old version, it is still compatible. If there's a preferred way, I'm all eyes.

Comment: My point is that there might not be an algorithm that turns `#F7464A` into `#FF5A5E` (strawberry highlight), `#46BFBD` into `#5AD3D1` (lettuce highlight), and etc.. There is no answer to "determine the highlight colors beforehand and then add them manually?" because there is no standard for what constitutes a "highlight color" relative to another color, and chart.js doesn't even have its *own* standard that you could duplicate. So just copy someone else's "highlight" code such as in Plutonix's link.

Comment: I downloaded version 2.0.2, and have it in my Scripts folder, but I ended up using a CDN: <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
I will try it, changing that from "1.0.2" to "2.0.2"

Comment: I tried to convert those values to different color models and only dependency I discovered is that in HSV model Hue is almost the same, 'highlighted' Saturation is lower (but in strawberry it is 30% lower and in lettuce only 10% lower) and 'highlighted' Value is higher (varies even worse than saturation). I checked other models also, but I found no rules. Therefore I think there is no easy algorithm or those values was picked manually.