# Creating a shade for each row of my script

Tags: javascript, svg, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I wanted to create a shade/course by my script based on each rows data.

I found a useful script on Stackoverflow to create a shade/course.

here is my full code:

```
const svg = document.getElementById('root')
let dom = []

const data = []
data.push([1000,2500,5000,10000,150,350,0]) // row 1
data.push([2,0,0,1,8,6,5]) // row 2
data.push([9,10,5,2,0,3,8]) // row 3
data.push([1,2,3,3,2,1,0]) // row 4
data.push([0,1,3,3,7,0,0]) // row 5
data.push([0,1,0,1,0,1,0]) // row 6
data.push([1,10,20,30,10,20,4]) // row 7
data.push([1,5,10,25,20,0,1]) // row 8
data.push([15,8,51,1,2,5,9]) // row 9
data.push([2,8,2,5,7,5,1]) // row 10

const seedColor = '#00cc00'
const rows = data.length
const cols = 7
const margin = 2
const height = 10
const width = 30
const svgHeight = (rows * height) + (rows * margin)

// @see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5560248/programmatically-lighten-or-darken-a-hex-color-or-rgb-and-blend-colors
_shadeColor2 = (color, percent) => {
  let f = parseInt(`${color}`.slice(1),16),
      t   = percent < 0 ? 0 : 255,
      p   = percent < 0 ? percent * -1 : percent,
      R   = f>>16,
      G   = f>>8&0x00FF,
      B   = f&0x0000FF;
  return "#" + (0x1000000+(Math.round((t-R)*p)+R)*0x10000+(Math.round((t-G)*p)+G)*0x100+(Math.round((t-B)*p)+B)).toString(16).slice(1);
}

for(let r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
    const max = Math.max(...data[r])
  const faktor = 1 / max

  for(let c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
    let shadeBy = data[r][c] * faktor

    let colorRx = /(#(?:[0-9a-f]{2}){2,4}|#[0-9a-f]{3}|(?:rgba?|hsla?)\((?:\d+%?(?:deg|rad|grad|turn)?(?:,|\s)+){2,3}[\s/]*[\d.]+%?\))/i
    color = _shadeColor2(seedColor, shadeBy)

        dom.push('<rect x="'+((width*c)+margin*c)+'" y="'+((height*r)+margin*r)+'" width="30" height="10" fill="'+color+'" ></rect>')
  } 
}

svg.style.height = svgHeight
svg.innerHTML = dom.join('')
```

and a running example is here: https://jsfiddle.net/0zLotkhu/33/

My goal was to create a shade for each row based on the data of each column. I didn't find the mistake why my shade isn't a real fade.

Comment: Why do you think the result is not what you wanted? For each row, the highest value is mapped to #ffffff, 0 is mapped to #00cc00, with every other value in between. Describe which colors you wanted to achieve.

Comment: And what do you mean by "a real fade"?

Comment: @ccprog sorry for bad question. You can't see a good difference between 1000-2500 and 350-150 in first row. For me it's hard to see a difference between these values.

Comment: This is not the place to talk about color perception. To get help on this site, you cannot just say "I want more contrast". You must describe the desired result in terms of a programming problem.

Comment: Sorry for my very bad english but I can't find the right words for my problem.  My problem is more the thing, that I want to create something like the Github-Contribution-Calendar and I don't know how to get something more like that.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the different shades of green to be farther apart? I can't say I understand the formula you are using to arrive at your percentages - but it looks to me like the rectangles are being colored exactly as desired, but the percentages are too closer together. Look at this example where I've added your percentages (I limited the decimals to just 2) - and you'll see what I mean.

```js
const svg = document.getElementById('root')
let dom = []

const data = []
data.push([1000,2500,5000,10000,150,350,0]) // row 1
data.push([2,0,0,1,8,6,5]) // row 2
data.push([9,10,5,2,0,3,8]) // row 3
data.push([1,2,3,3,2,1,0]) // row 4
data.push([0,1,3,3,7,0,0]) // row 5
data.push([0,1,0,1,0,1,0]) // row 6
data.push([1,10,20,30,10,20,4]) // row 7
data.push([1,5,10,25,20,0,1]) // row 8
data.push([15,8,51,1,2,5,9]) // row 9
data.push([2,8,2,5,7,5,1]) // row 10

const seedColor = '#00cc00'
const rows = data.length
const cols = 7
const margin = 2
const height = 10
const width = 30
const svgHeight = (rows * height) + (rows * margin)

// @see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5560248/programmatically-lighten-or-darken-a-hex-color-or-rgb-and-blend-colors
_shadeColor2 = (color, percent) => {
percent = percent.toFixed(2)
console.log('shading '+color+ ' percent '+percent)
 var f=parseInt(color.slice(1),16),t=percent<0?0:255,p=percent<0?percent*-1:percent,R=f>>16,G=f>>8&0x00FF,B=f&0x0000FF;
    return "#"+(0x1000000+(Math.round((t-R)*p)+R)*0x10000+(Math.round((t-G)*p)+G)*0x100+(Math.round((t-B)*p)+B)).toString(16).slice(1);
}

for(let r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
 const max = Math.max(...data[r])
  const faktor = 1 / max

  for(let c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
    let shadeBy = data[r][c] * faktor
    
    let colorRx = /(#(?:[0-9a-f]{2}){2,4}|#[0-9a-f]{3}|(?:rgba?|hsla?)\((?:\d+%?(?:deg|rad|grad|turn)?(?:,|\s)+){2,3}[\s/]*[\d.]+%?\))/i
    color = _shadeColor2(seedColor, shadeBy)

  dom.push('<rect x="'+((width*c)+margin*c)+'" y="'+((height*r)+margin*r)+'" width="30" height="10" fill="'+color+'" ></rect><text x="'+((width*c)+margin*c)+'" y="'+((height*r)+7+margin*r)+'" fill="#000000" font-family="arial" font-size="8" >'+shadeBy.toFixed(2)+'</text>')
  } 
}

svg.style.height = svgHeight
svg.innerHTML = dom.join('')
```

```html
<svg id="root"></svg>
```