# How to use `currentColor` in linear-gradient

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients

I want to use `currentColor` to show progress bar progression from the left.

[image: Example Progress Bar]

In the example below I am using the `background` of the progress bar instead of the actual color of the progress bar.

https://jsfiddle.net/nick1111/tc4r0net/13/

```css
progress[value] {
  /* Reset the default appearance */
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 250px;
  height: 20px;
}

progress::-webkit-progress-value {
  background: linear-gradient(to left, currentColor, rgba(255, 255, 255, .1));
}
```

```html
<div style="color:green;">
  <div>
    <progress value="80" max="100">70 %</progress>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I use currentColor instead of rgba(255,255,255,.1) ?

Thanks

Comment: You can't. `currentcolor` means just that...without any amendment/ opacity etc,

Comment: What do you mean how do you use it? You define color for progress and just replace `rgba(255,255,255,.1)` with `currentColor`

Comment: @Huangism if i replace the rgba with currentColor then it wont show the color progression from left to right. What i want to show is progress bar starting with same light color and slowly progressing to bright color.

Comment: Please check updated question. Progress bar starting with little bit of its color

Comment: You cannot do this by using CSS alone, if you use LESS or SASS, it can be achieved with currentColor (I think). If you are just using css, then you need to define at least one of the colors, either the start or the end and define the other as currentColor

Comment: I am using scss.

Comment: I never used SCSS but it appears the variable currentColor does not work with lighten. https://jsfiddle.net/tc4r0net/34/ if you change currentColor, to an actual color, it works

Comment: yes but color is an input so cant use actual color.

Comment: Then you will need to change the color based on the input, get the color, calculate the lightened/darkened color, then update the styling, assuming you are using js for the input. If you are using js, lighten/darken a color is not that simple, but https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5560248/programmatically-lighten-or-darken-a-hex-color-or-rgb-and-blend-colors

Comment: Look into SCSS mixins

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this. The idea is to use two gradient to simulate this behavior:

```css
progress[value] {
  /* Reset the default appearance */
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 250px;
  height: 20px;
}

progress::-webkit-progress-value {
  background: 
  linear-gradient(to left, transparent, rgba(128,128,128,0.9)), 
  linear-gradient(currentcolor, currentcolor);
}
```

```html
<div style="color:blue;">
  <div>
    <progress value="80" max="100">70 %</progress>
  </div>
</div>
<div style="color:green;">
  <div>
    <progress value="80" max="100">70 %</progress>
  </div>
</div>
<div style="color:white;">
  <div>
    <progress value="80" max="100">70 %</progress>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @jose1221 i updated my answer, you can have a look ;)