# highcharts: column chart color change based on value

Tags: highcharts, colors

I am creating a column type chart using highcharts.
My data has two dimensions, the second dimension shows the severity of the first dimension and range from 0 to 100.

```
data:{(234,45),(55645,7),(964,97),...}
```

i need my column height to show the first dimension of data, and dinamically change the color of each column based on the severity(second dimension).something like heatmap color but the color change based on another sets of data.

[image: something like this]

Any suggestions how i can do this?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll show an approach I think you can adapt. Lets create a series and set a default color for it (which I assume to be the color for zero severity):

```
series: [{
    color: '#ffff00', // yellow
    data: [42.4, 33.2, 34.5, 39.7, 52.6, 75.5, 57.4, 60.4, 47.6, 39.1, 46.8, 51.1]
}]
```

To color depending on severity, we need some values and a function to calculate the new color. I'm going to assume you'll have an array of the severity values outside the chart, which correspond to the series point indexes. For example:

```
severity = [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110];
min = Math.min(...severity);
max = Math.max(...severity);
maxColor = new Highcharts.Color('#ff0000'); // red

calculateColor = function(inputColor, min, max, value) {
    color = new Highcharts.Color(inputColor);
    interval = max - min;
    adjustedValue = value - min;
    alpha = adjustedValue / interval;
    return color.tweenTo(maxColor, alpha);
}
```

Using the `calculateColor` function with an input color, the min and max of the severity along with the specific severity value should now return a severity-adjusted color.

To demonstrate, we update the series colors using this function:

```
for(i = 0; i < this.series[0].data.length; i++) {
    this.series[0].data[i].update({
        color: calculateColor(this.series[0].color, min, max, severity[i])
    }, false);
};

this.redraw();
```

See [this complete JSFiddle demonstration](https://jsfiddle.net/5dz9r6k7/31/) of it in action.

Comment: Beat me to it, here is a very similar solution using the color function from [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13542669/8376046): https://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/qpgtrc97/

Comment: @ewolden Good with some alternative approaches, although that `blendColors` was hard to read :)

Answer (score 3):

In a simple way, you can use **colorAxis** from 'heatmap.js' module:

```
var columnProto = Highcharts.seriesTypes.column.prototype;

columnProto.axisTypes = ['xAxis', 'yAxis', 'colorAxis'];
columnProto.optionalAxis = 'colorAxis';
columnProto.colorKey = 'y';

Highcharts.wrap(columnProto, 'translate', function(proceed) {
    proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));

    Highcharts.seriesTypes.heatmap.prototype.translateColors.call(this);
});

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    series: [{
        data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
        type: 'column'
    }],
    colorAxis: {
        minColor: '#c6e48b',
        maxColor: '#196127',
        min: 1,
        max: 6,
        gridLineWidth: 0
    }
});
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/szv2g3u7/

Comment: Neat. Guessing OP might want severity as something other than `y`. Like that `colorKey` can address extra data: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/szv2g3u7/6/).

Comment: this is great tanks :)