# highcharts.js - Dynamic Label Color

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts, colors, label

Is it possible to change the label color when gauge color changes?

Here is my js fiddle - the requirement is to color the number the same way as the gauge:
http://jsfiddle.net/e76o9otk/735/

```
dataLabels: {
            format: '<div style="margin-top: -15.5px; text-align:center"><span style="font-size:10px;color:' +
                Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0] + '">{y}</span><br/>' +
                   '</div>'
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`formatter`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.dataLabels.formatter) callback function to include logic in the label text like this:

```
dataLabels: {
  formatter: function() {
    let color = ''
    if (this.y > 50) {
      color = '#55BF3B' //green
    } else if (this.y > 10) {
      color = '#DDDF0D' //yellow
    } else {
      color = '#DF5353' //red
    }
    return '<div style="margin-top: -15.5px; text-align:center"><span style="font-size:10px;color:' + color + '">' + this.y + '</span><br/>' + '</div>'
    },
  }
```

**Working JSFiddle example:** http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/x6j1ywdb/

---

If you want the dataLabel to be a gradient, you can implement (or borrow) a gradient function, such as this one: [Programmatically Lighten or Darken a hex color (or rgb, and blend colors)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5560248/programmatically-lighten-or-darken-a-hex-color-or-rgb-and-blend-colors)

**Working JSFiddle example:** (with gradient dataLabels): http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/x6j1ywdb/12/

Comment: Thanks ewolden! This is great approach, but I was thinking to match the label color completely - because between for values 10 and 50 the gauge color will be gradient between red and yellow - just put the value 25 in your example and you will see what I mean. - I guess I have to implement the logic for gradient color, right?

Comment: Glad to help. I see your point, I updated the answer with a gradient example now. The gradient function is from a very well written answer that I linked.