# CRA - Principal color stored in database

Tags: sass, create-react-app

It's possible to load a principal color (scss) from a database for create-react-app?

I've gone crazy looking for information. Would any of these work for me? https://github.com/MicheleBertoli/css-in-js#css-in-js

It is not clear to me if it is even possible in an SPA that the user can store their favorite template color (hexadecimal) in the database. Later, to load with call to database.

Now I have a "variables.scss" file that I import into the app:

```js
$colorBase: #277963CC;
$colorNote: #e6db7dcc;
$colorSuperLight: lighten ($colorBase, 50%);
$colorLight: lighten ($colorBase, 20%);
$colorHover: darken ($colorBase, 15%);
$colorDark: darken ($colorBase, 25%);
$colorMenuBg: adjust-hue ($colorBase, -15deg);
$colorLogoBrightness: lighten ($colorBase, 30%);
```

My intention is `$colorBase` to come from the database. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After much research, I have learned that I could not find a clear answer, because it is not good practice to do this type of operations on the client with a SPA. It would cause performance to drop. But for what I need, I would not mind because it would not lower the performance much. And you can always add a friendly little loading at the beginning of the web.

I have solved it by generating the different color tones in the JSX with a function I found ([David Sherret](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13532993/11831939)) and replacing CSS3 global variables instead of less.js

```js
function shadeColor(color, percent) {
    var R = parseInt(color.substring(1,3),16);
    var G = parseInt(color.substring(3,5),16);
    var B = parseInt(color.substring(5,7),16);
    R = parseInt(R * (100 + percent) / 100);
    G = parseInt(G * (100 + percent) / 100);
    B = parseInt(B * (100 + percent) / 100);
    R = (R<255)?R:255;  
    G = (G<255)?G:255;  
    B = (B<255)?B:255;  
    var RR = ((R.toString(16).length==1)?"0"+R.toString(16):R.toString(16));
    var GG = ((G.toString(16).length==1)?"0"+G.toString(16):G.toString(16));
    var BB = ((B.toString(16).length==1)?"0"+B.toString(16):B.toString(16));
    return "#"+RR+GG+BB;
}
```

I assign a fixed global variables in css

```css
:root {
    --color-super-light: #69c5adcc;
    --color-light: #3ea187cc;
    --color-hover: #1a614ecc;
    --color-dark: #0e4436cc;
    --color-menu-bg: #21613ecc;
    --color-logo-brillo: #00ffbbcc;
}
```

I assign them to the different elements of the SPA

```css
input {
    background-color: var(--color-dark) !important;
    color: var(--color-super-light) !important;
    border-color: var(--color-base) !important;
}
```

Finally, in the first load, I replace the variables with the color from the database and applying the function `shadeColor()`

```js
// dataFromDDBB is a data return from database (firebase)
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--color-base',
    dataFromDDBB.color+'CC'); // '#000000CC' - CC is hexadecimal opacity
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--color-super-light',
    shadeColor(dataFromDDBB.color,50)+'CC');
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--color-light',
    shadeColor(dataFromDDBB.color,20)+'CC');
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--color-logo-brillo',
    shadeColor(dataFromDDBB.color,30)+'CC');
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--color-hover',
    shadeColor(dataFromDDBB.color,-15)+'CC');
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--color-dark',
    shadeColor(dataFromDDBB.color,-80)+'CC');
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--color-menu-bg',
    shadeColor(dataFromDDBB.color,-25)+'CC');
```