# using a block of javascript in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to include a javascript function in my typescript code.
specificly this function:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13542669

The code:

```
const pSBC=(p,c0,c1,l)=>{
    let r,g,b,P,f,t,h,i=parseInt,m=Math.round,a=typeof(c1)=="string";
    if(typeof(p)!="number"||p<-1||p>1||typeof(c0)!="string"||(c0[0]!='r'&&c0[0]!='#')||(c1&&!a))return null;
    if(!this.pSBCr)this.pSBCr=(d)=>{
        let n=d.length,x={};
        if(n>9){
            [r,g,b,a]=d=d.split(","),n=d.length;
            if(n<3||n>4)return null;
            x.r=i(r[3]=="a"?r.slice(5):r.slice(4)),x.g=i(g),x.b=i(b),x.a=a?parseFloat(a):-1
        }else{
            if(n==8||n==6||n<4)return null;
            if(n<6)d="#"+d[1]+d[1]+d[2]+d[2]+d[3]+d[3]+(n>4?d[4]+d[4]:"");
            d=i(d.slice(1),16);
            if(n==9||n==5)x.r=d>>24&255,x.g=d>>16&255,x.b=d>>8&255,x.a=m((d&255)/0.255)/1000;
            else x.r=d>>16,x.g=d>>8&255,x.b=d&255,x.a=-1
        }return x};
    h=c0.length>9,h=a?c1.length>9?true:c1=="c"?!h:false:h,f=this.pSBCr(c0),P=p<0,t=c1&&c1!="c"?this.pSBCr(c1):P?{r:0,g:0,b:0,a:-1}:{r:255,g:255,b:255,a:-1},p=P?p*-1:p,P=1-p;
    if(!f||!t)return null;
    if(l)r=m(P*f.r+p*t.r),g=m(P*f.g+p*t.g),b=m(P*f.b+p*t.b);
    else r=m((P*f.r**2+p*t.r**2)**0.5),g=m((P*f.g**2+p*t.g**2)**0.5),b=m((P*f.b**2+p*t.b**2)**0.5);
    a=f.a,t=t.a,f=a>=0||t>=0,a=f?a<0?t:t<0?a:a*P+t*p:0;
    if(h)return"rgb"+(f?"a(":"(")+r+","+g+","+b+(f?","+m(a*1000)/1000:"")+")";
    else return"#"+(4294967296+r*16777216+g*65536+b*256+(f?m(a*255):0)).toString(16).slice(1,f?undefined:-2)
}
```

Now when i copy paste it in my typescript (angular) app, i get lots of errors like

```
Parameter 'p' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Parameter 'c0' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Parameter 'c1' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Parameter 'l' implicitly has an 'any' type.
The containing arrow function captures the global value of 'this'.
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'typeof globalThis' has no index signature.
The containing arrow function captures the global value of 'this'.
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'typeof globalThis' has no index signature.
Parameter 'd' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Property 'r' does not exist on type '{}'.
Property 'g' does not exist on type '{}'.
Property 'b' does not exist on type '{}'.
Property 'a' does not exist on type '{}'.
Argument of type 'boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
Property 'r' does not exist on type '{}'.
Property 'g' does not exist on type '{}'.
Property 'b' does not exist on type '{}'.
Property 'a' does not exist on type '{}'.
Property 'r' does not exist on type '{}'.
Property 'g' does not exist on type '{}'.
Property 'b' does not exist on type '{}'.
Property 'a' does not exist on type '{}'.
The containing arrow function captures the global value of 'this'.
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'typeof globalThis' has no index signature.
The containing arrow function captures the global value of 'this'.
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'typeof globalThis' has no index signature.
Operator '>=' cannot be applied to types 'boolean' and 'number'.
Operator '<' cannot be applied to types 'boolean' and 'number'.
The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.
The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.
The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.
```

I know some say any valid JavaScript is also valid typescript, but that's just not true..

Now without rewriting the method, is there a way to use it without having typescript do all the checks?

Comment: It *is* true that valid JavaScript is valid TypeScript, in fact, if you just ignore the errors and run the program, it should work. Anyway you cannot expect that a linter set to "validate" the stricter TypeScript syntax does not complain if you use JavaScript syntax. If those error are really bothering you, you can instruct the linter to ignore the JavaScript code block.

Comment: "I get lots of errors" where?

Comment: You will have to add types to the code yourself, keep in mind that the code in the answer uses some hacky code like global `this` references. You will have to manually fix each error to make typescript happy.

Comment: Also, this links might help you: https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/ignoring-code and https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/rules#disabling-rules

Comment: Your editor/linter might object, but the typescript compiler (tsc) will still output js. If you want to remove the warnings/errors, you can put ` // @ts-nocheck` at the beginning of the file

Comment: @secan It's TypeScript throwing errors, not ESLint.

Comment: I think adding types to this method will help because the way it's written it is quite hard to understand

Comment: Just place this bit of code into its own js file and import it instead of copy pasting into an existing ts file..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1:

Put that code in a .js file and export the function
Typescript will ignore .js files

Option 2:

put

```
// @ts-nocheck
```

At the beginning of the .ts file where that function is in.
It will ignore type checking in the whole .ts file.

In case there is an error while calling the function, put

```
//@ts-ignore
```

above that function call

This will ignore errors where arguments are not typed for that function call

Comment: i used an external js file with a plain export and that worked like a charm :) thanks