# Programmatically Lighten or Darken a hex color in lua - nvim highlight colors

Tags: colors, lua, hex, highlight, neovim

The goal is to programmatically change a hex colors brightness in lua.

This post contains several nice examples for js: [Programmatically Lighten or Darken a hex color (or rgb, and blend colors)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5560248/programmatically-lighten-or-darken-a-hex-color-or-rgb-and-blend-colors)

I tried my luck to convert one of these functions, but I'm still pretty new to lua programming. It just needs to work with hex values, rgb or other variants are not needed. Therefore, I  thought the "simpler" answers could serve as inspiration, but I still had no luck with it.

Eventually it shall be used to manipulate highlight colors in nvim. I'm  getting the colorcodes with a function I wrote:

```lua
local function get_color(synID, what)
    local command = 'echo synIDattr(hlID("' .. synID .. '"),' .. '"' .. what .. '"' .. ')'
    return vim.api.nvim_command_output(command)
end
```

Comment: The first code on the linked page runs in Lua 5.3. Replace parseint with tonumber, and optionally use `string.format("%#x", num)` to convert back into a hex string representation.

Comment: Tried again without no look. Would it be possible / appropriate for you to provide a working example as an answer?

Comment: Sure, but don't copy paste the answer. Try to understand it and figure out why your attempt failed :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't resort to bit ops in Lua 5.2 and lower, especially as Lua 5.1 lacks them (LuaJIT however does provide them); use multiplication, floor division & mod instead, and take care to clamp your values:

```
local function clamp(component)
  return math.min(math.max(component, 0), 255)
end
function LightenDarkenColor(col, amt)
  local num = tonumber(col, 16)
  local r = math.floor(num / 0x10000) + amt
  local g = (math.floor(num / 0x100) % 0x100) + amt
  local b = (num % 0x100) + amt
  return string.format("%#x", clamp(r) * 0x10000 + clamp(g) * 0x100 + clamp(b))
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Especially with the introduction of bit operators in 5.3, the Javascript references work with minimal changes:

```lua
function LightenDarkenColor(col, amt)
    col = tonumber(col, 16)
    return string.format("%#x", ((col & 0x0000FF) + amt) | ((((col >> 8) & 0x00FF) + amt) << 8) | (((col >> 16) + amt) << 16))
end

print(LightenDarkenColor("3F6D2A", 40))
```

`parseInt` became `tonumber` and `toString(16)` `string.format("%#x", ...)`

Note that this function does not perform any error handling on overflows.

The second function on the linked page can be ported the same way. `var` would be a `local` in Lua.

For Lua 5.2 and below, you need to use the [bit functions](http://lua-users.org/wiki/BitwiseOperators). I ported the second function instead, since it would get very unreadable very quickly:

```lua
function LightenDarkenColor(col, amt)
  local num = tonumber(col, 16)
  local r = bit.rshift(num, 16) + amt
  local b = bit.band(bit.rshift(num, 8), 0x00FF) + amt
  local g = bit.band(num, 0x0000FF) + amt
  local newColor = bit.bor(g, bit.bor(bit.lshift(b, 8), bit.lshift(r, 16)))
  return string.format("%#x", newColor)
end
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. Something like that was one of the attempts prior to opening this question. Tried again to work with it when reading the comment that the first code can work. Also, copy pasting this snippet results in an error. I thought the syntax must be different or is it due to the lua version ?

`E5112: Error while creating lua chunk: <Path> ')' expected near '&'`

Comment: That means you do not have bit operators, e.g. an older Lua version. I updated my answer

Comment: Shouldn't the order of the local vars in your second snippet be RGB?

Comment: I ported the example, it probably depends on the context whether the data is given in RGB or BGR. I agree, for 5.2 your implementation seems more suited.