# How can make logo color as lighter background color randomly

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass, background-color

[image]

I tried with opacity but it is not working
background-color: currentColor;
filter: opacity(0.5);

Iam making color randomly

```
card.querySelector('.logo').style.backgroundColor = "hsl(" + hue + ", " + saturation + "%, " + lightness + "%)";

card.querySelector('.logo').style.color = ('#' + ("00000" + Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.pow(16, 6)).toString(16)).slice(-6));
```

same like above picture i need to show colors

color is thick pink background color is light pink I have to show randomly

Comment: Would you be interested in a `css` solution for this?

Comment: Does any of the methods mentioned here works for you [Programmatically Lighten or Darken a hex color (or rgb, and blend colors)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5560248/programmatically-lighten-or-darken-a-hex-color-or-rgb-and-blend-colors)

Comment: iam trying with css like
backgroundColor: currentColor;

Comment: Have you used your browser devtools inspect facility to see what style attribute you are actually creating? There are brackets in that second setting which I don't understand (and suspect you should see errors on the console).

Comment: inside brackets --- randomly generate colours in javascript