# How to darken a given color (int)

Tags: android, android-color

I have a function that takes a given color and I would like it to darken the color (reduce its brightness by 20% or so). I can't figure out how to do this given just a color (int). What is the proper approach?

```
public static int returnDarkerColor(int color){
    int darkerColor = .... 
    return darkerColor;
}
```

Answer (score 73, accepted):

A more Android way of doing it:

```
    public static int manipulateColor(int color, float factor) {
        int a = Color.alpha(color);
        int r = Math.round(Color.red(color) * factor);
        int g = Math.round(Color.green(color) * factor);
        int b = Math.round(Color.blue(color) * factor);
        return Color.argb(a,
                Math.min(r,255),
                Math.min(g,255),
                Math.min(b,255));
    }
```

You will want to use a factor less than `1.0f` to darken. try `0.8f`.

Comment: Worked pretty well!

Answer (score 61):

There's even a simpler solution that has not been mentioned before, Android has a class called `ColorUtils` which can you help you with that
here's a Kotlin snippet of an extension function

```
inline val @receiver:ColorInt Int.darken
    @ColorInt
    get() = ColorUtils.blendARGB(this, Color.BLACK, 0.2f)
```

the method  `ColorUtils.blendARGB` takes your color as the first parameter and the second color you want to blend, `black` in this case and finally, the last parameter is the ratio between your color and the black color you're blending.

Answer (score 26):

A simpler solution using HSV like RogueBaneling suggested:

**Kotlin**

```
@ColorInt fun darkenColor(@ColorInt color: Int): Int {
    return Color.HSVToColor(FloatArray(3).apply {
        Color.colorToHSV(color, this)
        this[2] *= 0.8f
    })
}
```

**Java**

```
@ColorInt int darkenColor(@ColorInt int color) {
    float[] hsv = new float[3];
    Color.colorToHSV(color, hsv);
    hsv[2] *= 0.8f;
    return Color.HSVToColor(hsv);
}
```

No complex bitwise operations or `Math` necessary. Move `0.8f` to an argument if needed.

Comment: what should be to lighten a color?

Comment: Change the `0.8f` parameter to a value larger that 1.

Answer (score 12):

best way use the **ColorUtils.blendARGB**

***Darker:***

```
val newColor = ColorUtils.blendARGB(this, Color.BLACK, 0.5f)
```

***Lighter:***

```
val newColor = ColorUtils.blendARGB(this, Color.WHITE, 0.5f)
```

Answer (score 10):

If you want more simple and not accurately, below might help you.

```
public static int returnDarkerColor(int color){
    float ratio = 1.0f - 0.2f;
    int a = (color >> 24) & 0xFF;
    int r = (int) (((color >> 16) & 0xFF) * ratio);
    int g = (int) (((color >> 8) & 0xFF) * ratio);
    int b = (int) ((color & 0xFF) * ratio);

    return (a << 24) | (r << 16) | (g << 8) | b;
}
```

Comment: **1.** You're right. I just want show value 0.2f.
**2, 3.** It's my mistake. I just typed. Thank you for fixing.

Comment: This works properly and is much more efficient than the accepted answer

Comment: Works great. Used to set my title bar to a darkened shade of the action bar

Answer (score 5):

Convert the color to a [HSV array](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#RGBToHSV(int,%20int,%20int,%20float[])), then reduce the brightness by 20%, then convert HSV array back to RGB with `HSVToColor`. Note: The value you are looking to change in the array will be the `V`-value. (i.e., `hsv[2]`)

Answer (score 3):

Based on @Rasoul Miri answer you can create extensions to your main color class in a more *kotlinic* way. For example, if using the color class from the package `androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color` in Android you can add some extensions to it in this way:

```
fun Color.lighter(factor: Float = 1f) =
  Color(ColorUtils.blendARGB(this.toArgb(), Color.White.toArgb(), factor))

fun Color.darker(factor: Float = 1f) =
  Color(ColorUtils.blendARGB(this.toArgb(), Color.Black.toArgb(), factor))
```

This is a very handful function that can be used by simply doing

```
val myNewLighterColor = MaterialTheme.colors.primary.lighter(0.5f)
val myNextDarkerColor = MaterialTheme.colors.primary.darker(0.5f)
```

Answer (score 0):

This way you can select percentage of color and thus fetch a shade darker or a shade lighter

```
int  color = ((ColorDrawable)c2.getBackground()).getColor();
int  colorLighter = color - color * 40/100;
int  colorDarker = color + color * 40/100;
```

colorlighter gives us a lighter shade of color from button's background
colordarker gives us a darker shade of color from button's background

Comment: I think you should set limit value to prevent overflowing color max value(0xFFFFFF)