# How do I set specific tones (progresively darker, that is) for an array of values in java?

Tags: java, arrays, colors

I've got an array of numbers corresponding to different values which I add manually, but can't seem to figure out the way to assign different shades of colors to the numbers.
This is as far as I've gotten:

```
private void givecolor() {
    int[] colorarray = new int[6];
    int assignedvalue = 40;
    for (int index = 0; i < colorarray.length; i++){
        colorarray[i] = assignedvalue;
        assignedvalue--;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < colorarray.length; i++){
        colorarray = Color.getGreen;
    }
}
```

Comment: A similar question has been asked here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33072365/how-to-darken-a-given-color-int
Go chek it out!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this code compiles for you. Anyhow you need to set the color to a specific index on the colorarray.

```
colorarray[i] = Color.green;
```

Also, the second for loop will assign all the values for that array to be green.