# Make geom_text colour darker than geom_point colour

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am labeling a scatter plot with values.  To make it readable, I want the text colour to be darker than the points (a green point would have a darker green label):

```
p1 <- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, col = Species))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_text(aes(label = Sepal.Length), size = 2, position = position_dodge(width = 0.2))
```

I can use scale_colour_discrete to create the effect I want, but it applies to both points and text.

```
p1 + scale_colour_discrete(l = 50)
```

Can I apply it to the text only?

Comment: a simple hack would be to change `geom_point(alpha=0.5)`, which would make the points appear "lighter", but it's not the same as changing luminance, i think

Comment: That's a good quick fix - thank you.  I had to add `geom_point(alpha=0.5, shape = 16)` to prevent a dark border on the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
# specify your colour
COL <- c("red", "blue", "green")
p1 <- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, col = Species))+
      geom_point()
p1 <- p1 + scale_colour_manual(values = COL)
```

Now darken your colour using `col2rgb` and `rgb` ([source](https://gist.github.com/Jfortin1/72ef064469d1703c6b30)) or another [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787124/programmatically-darken-a-hex-colour)

```
COL2 <- col2rgb(COL)
COL2 <- COL2/2  # you can use of course other values than 2. Higher values the darker the output.
COL2 <- rgb(t(COL2), maxColorValue=255)
```

Plot the labels.

```
p1  + geom_text(aes(label = Sepal.Length), col=factor(iris$Species, labels=COL2), size = 2, position = position_dodge(width = 0.2))
```

For better overview I recommend to use `geom_text_repel`. Of note, you have to use `as.character`.

```
require(ggrepel)
p1 +   geom_text_repel(aes(label = Sepal.Length), size = 2, col= as.character(factor(iris$Species, labels=COL2)))
```

[image]

If you don't want to specify a colour in the beginning you can also extract the original ggplot colors using:

```
g <- ggplot_build(p1)
COL <- unlist(unique(g$data[[1]]["colour"]))
```

Then you use the code above for the darker text colour or combine everything in a darker function:

```
p1 <- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, col = Species))+
      geom_point()
# function 
darken <- function(Plot, factor=1.4){
  g <- ggplot_build(Plot)
  color <- unlist((g$data[[1]]["colour"]))
  col <- col2rgb(color)
  col <- col/factor
  col <- rgb(t(col), maxColorValue=255)
  col
}

# basic text
p1  + geom_text(aes(label = Sepal.Length), col=darken(p1, 2), size = 2, position = position_dodge(width = 0.2))
# repel text
p1  + geom_text_repel(aes(label = Sepal.Length), col= darken(p1, 2), size = 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Define colors for points:

```
n <- length(levels(iris$Species))
cols_points <- hcl(h = seq(15, 375, length = n + 1), l = 65, c = 100)[1:n]
```

Plot points as you did initially but set colors manually:

```
p1 <- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, colour = Species)) + geom_point() + scale_colour_manual(values = cols_points)
```

Define text colors by taking the same colors as you used for the plots but changing the hue (l, can be adjusted to how dark you want it):

```
cols_text <- hcl(h = seq(15, 375, length = n + 1), l = 30, c = 100)[1:n]

iris_cols <- ifelse(iris$Species == "setosa", cols_text[1], 
                ifelse(iris$Species == "versicolor", cols_text[2], cols_text[3]))
```

Plot with text annotation (I added a small y-offset, so that text and points don't overlap):

```
p1 + annotate("text", x = iris$Sepal.Length, y = iris$Sepal.Width + 0.05, label = iris$Sepal.Length, color = iris_cols, size = 2)
```