# Change color hex to darker

Tags: javascript, colors, hex

I know there is an answer to this ([Programmatically darken a Hex colour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787124/programmatically-darken-a-hex-colour)), I already tried to follow that explanation.

So, I'm saving into a variable the value of a hex:

`let y =  chart.color(x);`

If I'm printing it, it looks like this `#1f77b4`. So I delete the first character:

`y = y.substr(1);`

Now it looks like this: `1f77b4` so I'm adding `0x` at the begining:

`y = "0x" + y;` => now it is `0x1f77b4`. Great!

And now I'm trying to make the color darker by using the method explained on that question:

`y = (y & 0xfefefe) >> 1;`

After this computation, `y` is `998234`, converting it into hex makes it `7f3f07`. I tried both these values but they are not darker blue.

The origin color was blue, I used this method to get a darker blue but I've got a brownish yellow instead.

Is something wrong in my solving?

Comment: how did you get `3992936` ?

Comment: So it seems I didn't get 3992936. It looks like your conversion to hex is going wrong - did you use `y.toString(16)`?

Comment: `var y = "#1f77b4".substr(1); y = parseInt(y, 16); y = (y & 0xFEFEFE) >> 1; console.log(y.toString(16));` outputs "f3b5a", which is the correct value. [I still can't figure out how I pasted in that other number, it's not in anything else I'm doing at the moment.]

Comment: I understand your approach. But now there is a 5-digit result, how do I represent it as a color? :D if I add a 0 at the end it will be a pale orange, not the dark blue I want.

Comment: I think you might be adding the "0" to the wrong end: you need to have "#0f3b5a" rather than "#f3b5a0".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your (unshown) function used to convert to a hex string is not working correctly. Fortunately, JavaScript's [`toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString) function for numbers has an optional parameter which will do the conversion for you.

Also, as you're using the result in HTML/JavaScript, you may need prepend zeros to a width of 6, so...

```
function halveBrightness(hexColor) {
    if (hexColor.charAt(0) == "#") {
        hexColor = hexColor.substr(1);
    }
    var color = parseInt(hexColor, 16);
    /* using the method of https://stackoverflow.com/a/1787193/1115360 */
    color = (color & 0xFEFEFE) >> 1;

    return padLeft("0", 6, color.toString(16));

}

function padLeft(padChar, finalLength, str) {
    padChar = padChar.charAt(0);
    var nPads = finalLength - str.length;
    var padding = "";
    for(var i=1; i<=nPads; i++) {
        padding += padChar;
    }

    return padding + str;
}

/* using the value from the question */
var y = "#1f77b4";
console.log(halveBrightness(y));

/* check it works when bytes are/will become zero */
console.log(halveBrightness("0001FF"));
```

Outputs:

> 0f3b5a
>   00007f

You may need to put a "#" or "0x" at the beginning of the result, depending on what you're using it for.